# Object Dump JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a 3rd party add-on/application or some way to perform object map dumping in script debugger for a JavaScript object?

Here is the situation...  I have a method being called twice, and during each time something is different.  I'm not sure what is different, but something is.  So, if I could dump all the properties of window (or at least window.document) into a text editor, I could compare the state between the two calls with a simple file diff.  Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) + `console.log(myObjectInstance)`

Comment: ...and then look into the *Firebug console* and not the standard *Javascript console*. :-)

Comment: @SteveRobbins, a browser which doesn't have a console in which you could output values from your javascript is unlikely nowadays. Are you referring to some specific browser?

Comment: IE has a console, but logging an object returns `[object Object]`.  Not very useful

Comment: @SteveRobbins, who uses IE to develop web applications nowadays? Personally the only use I have found so far for Internet Explorer is to download a real web browser once I reinstall my Windows operating system. By the way that's the only time I launch this peace of software.

Comment: Any developer who supports major browsers. If the problem only exists in IE it can only be tested in IE, so you have to use the browser.

Comment: @SteveRobbins, good luck with IE :-) And my condolences if you have to support it. Hopefully you will find some great plugins out there for this major browser to debug your code.

Comment: And if you are using node.js and a terminal.. There is no firebug??

Comment: See Tim's answer below.

Answer (score 162):

```
console.log("my object: %o", myObj)
```

Otherwise you'll end up with a string representation sometimes displaying:

```
[object Object]
```

or some such.

Comment: How on earth is this not the selected answer?  Lucky me that this was answered on my birthday 4 years ago, when I wasn't using js.

Comment: In Meteor (server-side) it prints `my object: %o`. Not very helpful :)

Comment: In Node.js this just prints a literal `"%o"` in output.  Merely separating the string from the object, however, does dump a human-readable object as desired.

Comment: Funny how this has evolved. Now `console.log("my", myObj)` just pretends the `%o` was there, in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE11, Edge.

Answer (score 49):

```
function mydump(arr,level) {
    var dumped_text = "";
    if(!level) level = 0;

    var level_padding = "";
    for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

    if(typeof(arr) == 'object') {  
        for(var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];

            if(typeof(value) == 'object') { 
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                dumped_text += mydump(value,level+1);
            } else {
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
            }
        }
    } else { 
        dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
    }
    return dumped_text;
}
```

Comment: Update your code with changing the function name, as in recursion call, it is called "dump" while defining time its "mydump"

Comment: Copy and paste of: http://binnyva.blogspot.com/2005/10/dump-function-javascript-equivalent-of.html

Comment: this kills Chrome and Firefox with "too much recursion" when used to examine a jquery object

Comment: @slashdottir it is easy to fix, by checking `if (level > 10) return level_padding + '<< too deep >>';`

Comment: The "too much recursion" happens due to circular reference (when child parameter of one object references its parent object). Can be solved by remembering all parents of current value and if current value matches one of parent's, stop digging further.

Answer (score 43):

If you're on Chrome, Firefox or IE10 + why not extend the console and use

```
(function() {
    console.dump = function(object) {
        if (window.JSON && window.JSON.stringify)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
        else
            console.log(object);
    };
})();
```

for a concise, cross-browser solution.

Comment: I like this one. Especially for browser that do not support object dumping.

Comment: And maybe replace that "else console.log(object);" with a call to a custom traversal function as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3011557/2236012 above?... ;)

Comment: @C.B. "too much recursion" and a frozen browser is what this gets me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures. It will not work for all objects.

Answer (score 32):

Just use:

```
console.dir(object);
```

you will get a nice clickable object representation. Works in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Chrome and Firefox give [object Object]

Comment: You can test it in the Console (Hit F12) with `console.dir({bar:"foo"});` 
Does your object overwrites the toString method?

Comment: seems to be working in the console at least.  probably userr by me. thank you

Comment: such a sweet feature

Comment: You sir are a hero 


Answer (score 19):

for better readability you can convert the object to a json string as below:

```
console.log(obj, JSON.stringify(obj));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 13):

For Chrome/Chromium

```
console.log(myObj)
```

or it's equivalent

```
console.debug(myObj)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `console.log(object)` will throw your object to the Javascript console, but that's not always what you want. Using `JSON.stringify(object)` will return most stuff to be stored in a variable, for example to send it to a textarea input and submit the content back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, click the 3 dots and click More tools and click developer. On the console, type console.dir(yourObject).[Click this link to view an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9XZd.png)