# How can I display a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, serialization, javascript-objects

How do I display the content of a JavaScript object in a string format like when we `alert` a variable?

The same formatted way I want to display an object.

Comment: Would you please reword your question? What do you mean by "formatted way"? As in, with rich formatting, like bold/italic/etc?

Comment: is there a way to display the runtime value of a variable by printing the value of the variable using some console commands?

Comment: @BlackPanther Just do `console.log("", yourObject1, yourObject2, yourObject3, etc...);`. A shorter version is to just do `console.log(yourObject1, yourObject2, etc...);`.

Comment: Like this `console.log('a string', aNumber, anObject)`

Comment: Some tips:

You can use colors to have a better view of:
console.log('%c Sample Text', 'color:green;');

Or add some VAR in the text using:
console.log(\`Sample ${variable}\`, 'color:green;');

Comment: My problem was corrupted object which is ngModel of a select box and the [value] was used for option, instead of [ngValue]. When ngValue is used, the console.log is fine.

Comment: hey, i know this is very necromantic, but can you change the selected answer, ive added a lot of extra ways, not just one to display the object, and it will give me a chance to gain fame :D

Comment: This helped me a lot - https://code-maven.com/logging-javascript-objects

Comment: This may help [How can I serialize an input File object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24139216/9935654)

Answer (score 1346, accepted):

If you want to print the object for debugging purposes, use the code:

```
var obj = {
  prop1: 'prop1Value',
  prop2: 'prop2Value',
  child: {
    childProp1: 'childProp1Value',
  },
}
console.log(obj)
```

will display:

[image: screenshot console chrome]

**Note:** you must *only* log the object. For example, this won't work:

```
console.log('My object : ' + obj)
```

**Note '**: You can also use a comma in the `log` method, then the first line of the output will be the string and after that, the object will be rendered:

```
console.log('My object: ', obj);
```

Comment: That function also works on Google Chrome when using the JavaScript Console (Shift+Control+J or Shift+Control+I, depending on the Chrome version). Also note that `console.log(obj1, obj2)` works very nicely, too, so you don't have to call `console.log()` for every object when logging multiple variables. Also, always remember to remove all such calls in production, as it will break browsers that do not implement it (such as Internet Explorer).

Comment: Yes it prints [object Object] but it has a little expando-toggly button beside it that lets you inspect the contents of the object.

Comment: @hughes it actually can do both. i have an object i created with:

var obj = { "foo" : false };

and another object that is being passed into a callback from a server, the one passed through the callback prints with the little arrow so you can open it up, the statically created one just prints [object Object] with no arrow.

I'm trying to figure this out too, any other thoughts?

Comment: Yes it print object but in Chrome console you could extend the arrow and take a look at the data, here's an image of how it look: http://i.imgur.com/goRDM.png

Comment: @Felix: Great point about breaking browsers such as IE.  You can also use `if(console && console.log) { console.log(obj1, obj2); }` without worrying about breaking browsers that don't support console.log.

Comment: if you don't have the expand-button maybe you tried to be a smartass like me and called `toString()` on the object hoping for enlightenment. However this kinda forces the [object Object] output. Keep that in mind to save some of your life time :)

Comment: Just to note: This is not the answer if you are trying to develop an HTA on Microsoft Windows. This is because HTA's run in elevated privileges and don't get a console or other UI components.

Comment: IE does support `console.log` if you have the console open. However, it doesn't give you a nice clickable object you can expand.

Comment: You need to have the IE Developer tools debugger running which creates the console.log thingy for you.

Comment: If the, obvious, `console.log` is not working in your environment. (E.g. eclipse and xCode have not such a smooth console as FF or Chrome) consider Flavius answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/957652/1063730 Works nice in more rough coding-eco-systems :)

Comment: @chocojosh, `console && console.log && console.log(obj1, obj2);` as an expression can also do :)

Comment: `console.log("id:"+obj);` won't output correctly as it outputs a string as you see it there, you need to specify it like this: `console.log("id:"); console.log(obj);`

Comment: `console.log('%c red text, %c green bg', 'color: red', 'background: green' );`  `%c` can be used to style console.log's with colors.  it's helpful if you have too many and need to find one easy and modules that console log often

Comment: You can also see properties of an object by loop. Like

for(var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    console.log(key + " - " + value);
}

Comment: -1 Not cross-platform (see any mobile browser, where to get a console you have to have a *remote machine* available for debugging)

Comment: For the benefit of future rookies, @AnriëtteMyburgh's answer `console.log("id:"); console.log(obj);` works in most modern browsers. So let's use that until we get good enough to need something different.

Comment: **Important** console.log prints actually a reference to the object so if the object fields change after the logging so does the output see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state)

Comment: this is just NOT the right answer, console.dir(value) is, even if in most cases console.log(value) will result in the same thing (IF the value is an object)

Comment: didnt see this mentioned but couldnt you just console.log("id:", obj); in every browser and node this results and printing the string and object without creating the '[object Object]'

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` or `console.dir(obj)`

Comment: when I do console.log(myObject) I get [object Object] so how can your answer be the right one?  If I can't just do a console.log on my object as you did and see the graph...? And if i try JSON.stringify, I get TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: @AnriëtteMyburgh you can also say console.log("id:", obj)

Comment: Safari has a bunch of console commands that let you work with [object Object].  For instance try the "keys" or "values" commands.  Yep, way better if this was just a drop down but you can't have everything.  https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html

Comment: WRONG. Like others have said, console.log actually prints a reference to the object at last executable state. It WILL CHANGE! This can cost you a lot of wasted time as you search for bugs that don't exist. Better to use JSON.stringify.

Comment: Unfortunately, all I see is the text "<unavailable>" (using modern Firefox).  Works fine on old Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Does not work with Android WebView. It does have a console output which can be seen on a debugger, but it does not support string substitutions like %o at this time. Android WebView is how you embed a browser in an app.

Comment: What if `console` is not available? Like in Nashorn I am using in Keycloak?

Comment: Adding to @Steven2163712 's comment: this logs to the console a live reference to the object. If you want the contents of the object at the time of logging, some other solution is required.

Answer (score 2441):

Use native `JSON.stringify` method.
Works with nested objects and all major browsers [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=json) this method.

```
str = JSON.stringify(obj);
str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4); // (Optional) beautiful indented output.
console.log(str); // Logs output to dev tools console.
alert(str); // Displays output using window.alert()
```

Link to [Mozilla API Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and other examples.

```
obj = JSON.parse(str); // Reverses above operation (Just in case if needed.)
```

---

Use a custom [JSON.stringify replacer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/218857) if you
encounter this Javascript error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(obj) will not show all properties for array objects. eg `array = ["a","b"]; array["c"] = "c"`. When we do `JSON.stringify(array)` output is **"[ "a", "b" ]"** and when we do console.log(array) output is **["a", "b", c: "c"]**

Comment: I use JSON.stringify with [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) to output for debugging. [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/absynce/ACGRx/)

Comment: JSON.stringify can only show a small subset of javascript values, and will throw an exception for the rest - console.log does not have this problem.

Comment: If you are a newbie like me, don't forget ```console.log``` i.e. ```console.log(JSON.stringify(obj,null, 4));```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" when ob=window.

Comment: Great for doing it without requiring a browser plugin. It is working for me, at least in simple and most common cases!

Comment: @Stefano If you wanna see the output without console, you can combine both options. JSON will put data into a string, then alert() it: `alert(JSON.stringify(object))`

Comment: I had cases where it did not work : it showed `{}` for a non-empty object. So be sure to check with `console.log(obj)` before thinking your object is empty when `strigify()` returns `{}`.

Comment: stringify won't work if it's a DOM object.  Solution is to simply split into 2 separate commands believe it or not:  console.log("id:"); console.log(obj);

Comment: > In Node.js, you can use [util.inspect(object)](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options). It automatically replaces circular links with "[Circular]". -----
 credit: [Erel Segal-Halevi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354289/8015265) in that JSON.stringify replacer link

Comment: Notice that this, for example, is a valid javascript object: `{name: "John"}` but not valid JSON, so this method won't work in some cases.

Comment: I was having to log my object to Google Analytics so I used `JSON.stringify(obj).toString()`

Comment: For anyone else trying to actually raw print a prettified object on the page itself, all you need to do is wrap the object in a <pre> HTML tag. For benefiting from the improved indenting of this stringified JSON, wrap that string instead.

Comment: This answer works most of the time, but I had a circular reference error, this other answer helped me with that: [How can I print a circular structure in a JSON-like format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354289/3154857)

Answer (score 421):

```
var output = '';
for (var property in object) {
  output += property + ': ' + object[property]+'; ';
}
alert(output);
```

Comment: This is what exactly i want. I am using google maps v3 and the directionrenderer returns an object. That has four items and in that one objects name keeps changing so we need to find that. For that this method really helped. Besides this way we can get all the names of the properties and objects. Or is there any other way to find the names of the objects and properties?

Comment: You probably want to mask out the built in cruft with hasOwnProperty most of the time.

Comment: A little late finding this, but as it got requested on my birthday last year (29th aug), here is a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrMarlow/fq53o6o9/

Comment: This is an old and pretty terrible answer. It doesn't recurse at all, doesn't indent, uses `var` and `alert` etc.

Answer (score 147):

`console.dir(object)`:

> Displays an interactive listing of the properties of a specified JavaScript object. This listing lets you use disclosure triangles to examine the contents of child objects.

Note that the `console.dir()` feature is non-standard.  See [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)

Comment: Yes this is a good solution, however it only works as exptected if you want to log only the object (e.g. console.dir(obj)). In case you want to concatenate a sting to the output, it'll give you [object Object].

Comment: A massive advantage of `console.dir` is that you can still expand and read the values in your console after the variable has been garbage collected. This is described in another [SO article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776467/why-cant-i-expand-this-event-object-in-the-chrome-console)

Comment: And one more advantage of `console.dir` is that when you save console to file, all properties are in file as expected. That doesn't happen when using console.log only.

Answer (score 108):

### Try this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

This will print the stringify version of object. So instead of `[object]` as an output you will get the content of object.

Comment: `typeerror: Converting circular structure to JSON`?

Comment: @KaidenPrince see this answer for your error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json  It is likely a DOM element in your object.  If that's the case, you're best attempting to just log to the console in chrome or firefox and inspect there.  Otherwise you'd have to strip out all circular elements before the JSON.stringify is called in order for it to work.

Comment: Solution is to simply split into 2 separate commands believe it or not: console.log("id:"); console.log(obj);

Comment: JSON.stringify does not understand Map

Comment: Is this somehow different from the top answer given 5 years earlier? If so, please explain and I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: Mine is one liner and very simple @DanDascalescu :)

Answer (score 68):

Well, Firefox (thanks to @Bojangles for detailed information) has [`Object.toSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) method which prints objects as JSON and `function(){}`.

That's enough for most debugging purposes, I guess.

Comment: Your link to `Object.toSource()` now redirects to `Object.prototype.toString()` - mdn doesn't have anything on toSource as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 51):

If you want to use alert, to print your object, you can do this:

`alert("myObject is " + myObject.toSource());`

It should print each property and its corresponding value in string format.

Comment: toSource() doesn't work in non-gecko browsers (e.g. Chrome, Safari)

Answer (score 47):

If you would like to see data in tabular format you can use:

```
console.table(obj);
```

Table can be sorted if you click on the table column.

You can also select what columns to show:

```
console.table(obj, ['firstName', 'lastName']);
```

You can find more information about console.table [here](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/11/13/advanced-javascript-debugging-with-consoletable)

Answer (score 40):

**Function:**

```
var print = function(o){
    var str='';

    for(var p in o){
        if(typeof o[p] == 'string'){
            str+= p + ': ' + o[p]+'; </br>';
        }else{
            str+= p + ': { </br>' + print(o[p]) + '}';
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'Wilson Page',
    contact: {
        email: 'wilson@hotmail.com',
        tel: '123456789'
    }  
}

$('body').append( print(myObject) );
```

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/6eqMn/

Comment: Print method call the browser to print the page to pdf :p

Comment: @jsh you should turn the if-else around and check for object instead of only string. updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6eqMn/594/

Comment: @wilsonpage This is failing if I add integer value to tel property :(

Answer (score 39):

In NodeJS you can print an object by using [`util.inspect(obj)`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options). Be sure to state the depth or you'll only have a shallow print of the object.

Answer (score 34):

Simply use

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Example

```
var args_string = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(args_string);
```

Or

```
alert(args_string);
```

Also, note in javascript functions are considered as objects.

As an extra note :

Actually you can assign new property like this and access it console.log or display it in alert

```
foo.moo = "stackoverflow";
console.log(foo.moo);
alert(foo.moo);
```

Comment: The question itself states: "Like when we 'alert' a variable", so that's not really an answer. And also your other option "JSON.stringify(obj)" has already been mentioned in "Nov 27 2010", you're only cluttering this question with duplicates and non-answers. Your point about assigning new properties is also senseless in this context.

Comment: Is this materially different from the top answer given 5 years earlier? If so, please explain and I'll undo my downvote.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a way to do it:

```
console.log("%o", obj);
```

Comment: In the context of Chrome-dev-tool, google did mentioned this in this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write). referring to the section "String substitution and formatting"

Comment: I saw it in [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console).

Comment: I routinely use the following as a debug statement.

console.log("id-str %o",{obj1:obj1,obj2:obj2,...});

The debug window identifies each object and I can drill down on those that are interesting.

Answer (score 24):

NB:
In these examples, yourObj defines the object you want to examine.

## First off my least favorite yet most utilized way of displaying an object:

**This is the defacto way of showing the contents of an object**

```
console.log(yourObj)
```

will produce something like :
[image]

## I think the best solution is to look through the Objects Keys, and then through the Objects Values if you really want to see what the object holds...

```
console.log(Object.keys(yourObj));
console.log(Object.values(yourObj));
```

It will output something like : 
[image]
(pictured above: the keys/values stored in the object)

## There is also this new option if you're using ECMAScript 2016 or newer:

```
Object.keys(yourObj).forEach(e => console.log(`key=${e}  value=${yourObj[e]}`));
```

This will produce neat output : 
[image]
The solution mentioned in a previous answer: `console.log(yourObj)` displays too many parameters and **is not the most user friendly way to display the data you want**. That is why I recommend logging keys and then values separately.

## Next up :

```
console.table(yourObj)
```

Someone in an earlier comment suggested this one, however it never worked for me. If it does work for someone else on a different browser or something, then kudos! Ill still put the code here for reference!
Will output something like this to the console : 
[image]

Comment: Would you expand the example to include Object and obj.

Comment: not sure I understand the comment, but I added differing names for objects that should have a name. object was not explicit enough.

Comment: `console.table(yourObj)`  worked for me on Google Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit). Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 23):

To print the full object with *Node.js* with colors as a bonus:

```
console.dir(object, {depth: null, colors: true})
```

Colors are of course optional, 'depth: null' will print the full object.

The options don't seem to be supported in browsers.

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir

https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options

Answer (score 19):

Use this:

```
console.log('print object: ' + JSON.stringify(session));
```

Answer (score 19):

As it was said before best and most simply way i found was

```
var getPrintObject=function(object)
{
    return JSON.stringify(object);
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest and fastest solution, however it doesn't work on big objects such as `navigator`.

Answer (score 15):

*(This has been added to my library at [GitHub](https://github.com/PimpTrizkit/PJs/wiki/11.-Object-to-String-(pOTS.js)))*

Reinventing the wheel here! None of these solutions worked for my situation. So, I quickly doctored up [wilsonpage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516629/wilsonpage)'s answer. This one is not for printing to screen (via console, or textfield or whatever). It does work fine in those situations and works just fine as the OP requested, for `alert`. Many answers here do not address using `alert` as the OP requested. Anyhow, It is, however, formatted for data transport. This version seems to return a very similar result as `toSource()`. I've not tested against `JSON.stringify`, but I assume this is about the same thing. This version is more like a poly-fil so that you can use it in any environment. The result of this function is a valid Javascript object declaration.

I wouldn't doubt if something like this was already on SO somewhere, but it was just shorter to make it than to spend a while searching past answers. And since this question was my top hit on google when I started searching about this; I figured putting it here might help others.

Anyhow, the result from this function will be a string representation of your object, even if your object has embedded objects and arrays, and even if those objects or arrays have even further embedded objects and arrays. (I heard you like to drink? So, I pimped your car with a cooler. And then, I pimped your cooler with a cooler. So, your cooler can drink, while your being cool.)

Arrays are stored with `[]` instead of `{}` and thus dont have key/value pairs, just values. Like regular arrays. Therefore, they get created like arrays do.

Also, all string (including key names) are quoted, this is not necessary unless those strings have special characters (like a space or a slash). But, I didn't feel like detecting this just to remove some quotes that would otherwise still work fine.

This resulting string can then be used with `eval` or just dumping it into a var thru string manipulation. Thus, re-creating your object again, from text.

```
function ObjToSource(o){
    if (!o) return 'null';
    var k="",na=typeof(o.length)=="undefined"?1:0,str="";
    for(var p in o){
        if (na) k = "'"+p+ "':";
        if (typeof o[p] == "string") str += k + "'" + o[p]+"',";
        else if (typeof o[p] == "object") str += k + ObjToSource(o[p])+",";
        else str += k + o[p] + ",";
    }
    if (na) return "{"+str.slice(0,-1)+"}";
    else return "["+str.slice(0,-1)+"]";
}
```

Let me know if I messed it all up, works fine in my testing. Also, the only way I could think of to detect type `array` was to check for the presence of `length`. Because Javascript really stores arrays as objects, I cant actually check for type `array` (there is no such type!). If anyone else knows a better way, I would love to hear it. Because, if your object also has a property named `length` then this function will mistakenly treat it as an array.

EDIT: Added check for null valued objects. Thanks Brock Adams

EDIT: Below is the fixed function to be able to print infinitely recursive objects. This does not print the same as `toSource` from FF because `toSource` will print the infinite recursion one time, where as, this function will kill it immediately. This function runs slower than the one above, so I'm adding it here instead of editing the above function, as its only needed if you plan to pass objects that link back to themselves, somewhere.

```
const ObjToSource=(o)=> {
    if (!o) return null;
    let str="",na=0,k,p;
    if (typeof(o) == "object") {
        if (!ObjToSource.check) ObjToSource.check = new Array();
        for (k=ObjToSource.check.length;na<k;na++) if (ObjToSource.check[na]==o) return '{}';
        ObjToSource.check.push(o);
    }
    k="",na=typeof(o.length)=="undefined"?1:0;
    for(p in o){
        if (na) k = "'"+p+"':";
        if (typeof o[p] == "string") str += k+"'"+o[p]+"',";
        else if (typeof o[p] == "object") str += k+ObjToSource(o[p])+",";
        else str += k+o[p]+",";
    }
    if (typeof(o) == "object") ObjToSource.check.pop();
    if (na) return "{"+str.slice(0,-1)+"}";
    else return "["+str.slice(0,-1)+"]";
}
```

Test:

```
var test1 = new Object();
test1.foo = 1;
test1.bar = 2;

var testobject = new Object();
testobject.run = 1;
testobject.fast = null;
testobject.loop = testobject;
testobject.dup = test1;

console.log(ObjToSource(testobject));
console.log(testobject.toSource());
```

Result:

```
{'run':1,'fast':null,'loop':{},'dup':{'foo':1,'bar':2}}
({run:1, fast:null, loop:{run:1, fast:null, loop:{}, dup:{foo:1, bar:2}}, dup:{foo:1, bar:2}})
```

NOTE: Trying to print `document.body` is a terrible example. For one, FF just prints an empty object string when using `toSource`. And when using the  function above, FF crashes on `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`. And Chrome will crash on `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Clearly, `document.body` was not meant to be converted to string. Because its either too large, or against security policy to access certain properties. Unless,  I messed something up here, do tell!

Comment: Crash prone.  Try `ObjToSource(document.body)`, for example.

Comment: ok, I found the issue. I was not checking for null valued objects. That is fixed now. But, you still cant do `ObjToSource(document.body)` because of infinite recursion. Even `document.body.toSource()` in FireFox returns an empty object.

Comment: @BrockAdams - There now its fixed for infinite recursion, however `document.body` is still not printable. See NOTE.

Comment: `document.body` was just a shortcut to pointing out some big problems. You've now fixed the worst of those and I already upvoted.  (Although, I do believe that a different approach could handle `document.body`.  Most of the answers here would not do well against it either.)

Comment: Well, if you (or anyone else) got any ideas of how to get past the fact that such a large object will fill up the stack during recursion or bypass security restrictions. I would love to hear it. Thanks for the vote!

Comment: You said, "fixed the worse of those". Care to enlighten me as to what other problems there are? I would like to make it right, even for the small problems.

Comment: Replace "fixed the worse of those", with "All the problems that I identified at a glance".  I did not analyze or test the code in depth as it's not quite what I'm looking for.  I didn't say "fixed all problems" because I suspect that such code *should* be able to handle `document.body`, as Firebug does.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Well, if you ever find a specific issue. Or come across a way to handle these last two points (stackoverflow, security restrictions), please let me know.

Comment: Sadly, this answer does not add any indentation. The output is all one single line.

Comment: @posfan12 -  Yes, as mentioned in the description, it was mainly made for data transport. For example, you can push it thru `eval` to get your object back. But it does still work with `alert`.

Comment: @hmijailmournsresignees - If reinventing the wheel is never good, then we would never have rubber tires, and trains. I didn't do it for lazyness. It would have taken me less than a minute to google up `JSON.stringify` if I wanted to be lazy. On the contrary, I spend hard working time on this function. It even gets some traffic on github. JavaScript is finding it's place in more and more interesting environments, this function is a good polyfil for those situations. Plus it can be used as a working solution for the OP. This is also not the only reinvention of pagewil's answer on here.

Answer (score 14):

If you would like to print the object of its full length, can use

> console.log(require('util').inspect(obj, {showHidden: false, depth: null})

If you want to print the object by converting it to the string then

> console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

Comment: you would need to add the `JSON.stringify` when you try to concatenate with a string object. If you use `console.log(object)`, it should pretty print the contents of the object

Answer (score 11):

I needed a way to recursively print the object, which pagewil's answer provided (Thanks!). I updated it a little bit to include a way to print up to a certain level, and to add spacing so that it is properly indented based on the current level that we are in so that it is more readable.

```
// Recursive print of object
var print = function( o, maxLevel, level ) {
    if ( typeof level == "undefined" ) {
        level = 0;
    }
    if ( typeof level == "undefined" ) {
        maxLevel = 0;
    }

    var str = '';
    // Remove this if you don't want the pre tag, but make sure to remove
    // the close pre tag on the bottom as well
    if ( level == 0 ) {
        str = '<pre>';
    }

    var levelStr = '';
    for ( var x = 0; x < level; x++ ) {
        levelStr += '    ';
    }

    if ( maxLevel != 0 && level >= maxLevel ) {
        str += levelStr + '...</br>';
        return str;
    }

    for ( var p in o ) {
        if ( typeof o[p] == 'string' ) {
            str += levelStr +
                p + ': ' + o[p] + ' </br>';
        } else {
            str += levelStr +
                p + ': { </br>' + print( o[p], maxLevel, level + 1 ) + levelStr + '}</br>';
        }
    }

    // Remove this if you don't want the pre tag, but make sure to remove
    // the open pre tag on the top as well
    if ( level == 0 ) {
        str += '</pre>';
    }
    return str;
};
```

Usage:

```
var pagewilsObject = {
    name: 'Wilson Page',
    contact: {
        email: 'wilson@hotmail.com',
        tel: '123456789'
    }  
}

// Recursive of whole object
$('body').append( print(pagewilsObject) ); 

// Recursive of myObject up to 1 level, will only show name 
// and that there is a contact object
$('body').append( print(pagewilsObject, 1) );
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use ES6 template literal concept to display the content of a JavaScript object in a string format.

```
alert(`${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
```

```js
const obj  = {
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "habbits": "Nothing",
};
alert(`${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
```

Comment: This doesn't really any value beyond the `JSON.stringify` answer given in 2010. The syntax looks more cryptic than `alert(JSON.stringify(obj));`, and template literals are beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 6):

I always use `console.log("object will be: ", obj, obj1)`.
this way I don't need to do the workaround with stringify with JSON.
All the properties of the object will be expanded nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Another way of displaying objects within the console is with `JSON.stringify`. Checkout the below example:

```
var gandalf = {
  "real name": "Gandalf",
  "age (est)": 11000,
  "race": "Maia",
  "haveRetirementPlan": true,
  "aliases": [
    "Greyhame",
    "Stormcrow",
    "Mithrandir",
    "Gandalf the Grey",
    "Gandalf the White"
  ]
};
//to console log object, we cannot use console.log("Object gandalf: " + gandalf);
console.log("Object gandalf: ");
//this will show object gandalf ONLY in Google Chrome NOT in IE
console.log(gandalf);
//this will show object gandalf IN ALL BROWSERS!
console.log(JSON.stringify(gandalf));
//this will show object gandalf IN ALL BROWSERS! with beautiful indent
console.log(JSON.stringify(gandalf, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 5):

**Javascript Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function print_r(theObj){ 
       if(theObj.constructor == Array || theObj.constructor == Object){ 
          document.write("<ul>") 
          for(var p in theObj){ 
             if(theObj[p].constructor == Array || theObj[p].constructor == Object){ 
                document.write("<li>["+p+"] => "+typeof(theObj)+"</li>"); 
                document.write("<ul>") 
                print_r(theObj[p]); 
                document.write("</ul>") 
             } else { 
                document.write("<li>["+p+"] => "+theObj[p]+"</li>"); 
             } 
          } 
          document.write("</ul>") 
       } 
    } 
</script>
```

**Printing Object**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
print_r(JAVACRIPT_ARRAY_OR_OBJECT);
</script>
```

via [print_r in Javascript](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/print_r-in-javascript/)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug in the js.do example I'm using, but this only seems to output the first full "branch" of the tree. ie it follows the first reference of the first reference... ad infinitum

Answer (score 5):

```
var list = function(object) {
   for(var key in object) {
     console.log(key);
   }
}
```

where `object` is your object

or you can use this in chrome dev tools, "console" tab:

`console.log(object);`

Comment: I think your answer is incomplete. (not me that cause downvote)
This, yet, only print the key..

Comment: thanks for your answer, it has inspired me to do this: `console.log(Object.keys(object));` while I know that only prints the properties keys, it is enough to me for my purposes ;)

Answer (score 5):

Assume object `obj = {0:'John', 1:'Foo', 2:'Bar'}`

Print object's content

```
for (var i in obj){
    console.log(obj[i], i);
}
```

Console output (Chrome DevTools) :

```
John 0
Foo 1
Bar 2
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using `console.table` for getting clear object format, so imagine you have this object:

```
const obj = {name: 'Alireza', family: 'Dezfoolian', gender: 'male', netWorth: "$0"};
```

And you will you see a neat and readable table like this below:
[image: console.table]

Answer (score 4):

## Circular references solution

To make **string** without redundant information from object which contains duplicate references (references to same object in many places) including circular references, use `JSON.stringify` with **replacer** (presented in snippet) as follows

```
let s = JSON.stringify(obj, refReplacer(), 4);
```

```js
function refReplacer() {
  let m = new Map(), v= new Map(), init = null;

  return function(field, value) {
    let p= m.get(this) + (Array.isArray(this) ? `[${field}]` : '.' + field); 
    let isComplex= value===Object(value)
    
    if (isComplex) m.set(value, p);  
    
    let pp = v.get(value)||'';
    let path = p.replace(/undefined\.\.?/,'');
    let val = pp ? `#REF:${pp[0]=='[' ? '$':'$.'}${pp}` : value;
    
    !init ? (init=value) : (val===init ? val="#REF:$" : 0);
    if(!pp && isComplex) v.set(value, path);
   
    return val;
  }
}




// ---------------
// TEST
// ---------------

// gen obj with duplicate references
let a = { a1: 1, a2: 2 };
let b = { b1: 3, b2: "4" };
let obj = { o1: { o2:  a  }, b, a }; // duplicate reference
a.a3 = [1,2,b];                      // circular reference
b.b3 = a;                            // circular reference


let s = JSON.stringify(obj, refReplacer(), 4);

console.log(s);
alert(s);
```

This solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61693085/860099)  (more info there) create [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) like path for each object value and if same object occurs twice (or more) it uses reference with this path to reference that object e.g. `#REF:$.bar.arr[3].foo` (where `$` means main object) instead 'render' whole object (which is less redundant)

**BONUS**: inversion

```js
function parseRefJSON(json) {
  let objToPath = new Map();
  let pathToObj = new Map();
  let o = JSON.parse(json);
  
  let traverse = (parent, field) => {
    let obj = parent;
    let path = '#REF:$';

    if (field !== undefined) {
      obj = parent[field];
      path = objToPath.get(parent) + (Array.isArray(parent) ? `[${field}]` : `${field?'.'+field:''}`);
    }

    objToPath.set(obj, path);
    pathToObj.set(path, obj);
    
    let ref = pathToObj.get(obj);
    if (ref) parent[field] = ref;

    for (let f in obj) if (obj === Object(obj)) traverse(obj, f);
  }
  
  traverse(o);
  return o;
}



// ------------
// TEST
// ------------

let s = `{
    "o1": {
        "o2": {
            "a1": 1,
            "a2": 2,
            "a3": [
                1,
                2,
                {
                    "b1": 3,
                    "b2": "4",
                    "b3": "#REF:$.o1.o2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "b": "#REF:$.o1.o2.a3[2]",
    "a": "#REF:$.o1.o2"
}`;

console.log('Open Chrome console to see nested fields');
let obj = parseRefJSON(s);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

A little helper function I always use in my projects for simple, speedy debugging via the console. 
 Inspiration taken from Laravel.

```
/**
 * @param variable mixed  The var to log to the console
 * @param varName string  Optional, will appear as a label before the var
 */
function dd(variable, varName) {
    var varNameOutput;

    varName = varName || '';
    varNameOutput = varName ? varName + ':' : '';

    console.warn(varNameOutput, variable, ' (' + (typeof variable) + ')');
}
```

**Usage**

`dd(123.55);` outputs:
[image]

```
var obj = {field1: 'xyz', field2: 2016};
dd(obj, 'My Cool Obj');
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The console.log() does a great job of debugging objects, but if you are looking to print the object to the page content, here's the simplest way that I've come up with to mimic the functionality of PHP's print_r(). A lot these other answers want to reinvent the wheel, but between JavaScript's JSON.stringify() and HTML's <pre> tag, you get exactly what you are looking for.

```js
var obj = { name: 'The Name', contact: { email: 'thename@gmail.com', tel: '123456789' }};
$('body').append('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)+'</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

i used pagewil's print method, and it worked very nicely.

here is my slightly extended version with (sloppy) indents and distinct prop/ob delimiters:

```
var print = function(obj, delp, delo, ind){
    delp = delp!=null ? delp : "\t"; // property delimeter
    delo = delo!=null ? delo : "\n"; // object delimeter
    ind = ind!=null ? ind : " "; // indent; ind+ind geometric addition not great for deep objects
    var str='';

    for(var prop in obj){
        if(typeof obj[prop] == 'string' || typeof obj[prop] == 'number'){
          var q = typeof obj[prop] == 'string' ? "" : ""; // make this "'" to quote strings
          str += ind + prop + ': ' + q + obj[prop] + q + '; ' + delp;
        }else{
          str += ind + prop + ': {'+ delp + print(obj[prop],delp,delo,ind+ind) + ind + '}' + delo;
        }
    }
    return str;
};
```

Comment: It is very sloppy.

Answer (score 2):

Another modification of pagewils code... his doesn't print out anything other than strings and leaves the number and boolean fields blank and I fixed the typo on the second typeof just inside the function as created by megaboss.

```
var print = function( o, maxLevel, level )
{
    if ( typeof level == "undefined" )
    {
        level = 0;
    }
    if ( typeof maxlevel == "undefined" )
    {
        maxLevel = 0;
    }

    var str = '';
    // Remove this if you don't want the pre tag, but make sure to remove
    // the close pre tag on the bottom as well
    if ( level == 0 )
    {
        str = '<pre>';   // can also be <pre>
    }

    var levelStr = '<br>';
    for ( var x = 0; x < level; x++ )
    {
        levelStr += '    ';   // all those spaces only work with <pre>
    }

    if ( maxLevel != 0 && level >= maxLevel )
    {
        str += levelStr + '...<br>';
        return str;
    }

    for ( var p in o )
    {
        switch(typeof o[p])
        {
          case 'string':
          case 'number':    // .tostring() gets automatically applied
          case 'boolean':   // ditto
            str += levelStr + p + ': ' + o[p] + ' <br>';
            break;

          case 'object':    // this is where we become recursive
          default:
            str += levelStr + p + ': [ <br>' + print( o[p], maxLevel, level + 1 ) + levelStr + ']</br>';
            break;
        }
    }

    // Remove this if you don't want the pre tag, but make sure to remove
    // the open pre tag on the top as well
    if ( level == 0 )
    {
        str += '</pre>';   // also can be </pre>
    }
    return str;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's function.

```
function printObj(obj) {
console.log((function traverse(tab, obj) {
    let str = "";
    if(typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj + ',';
    }
    if(Array.isArray(obj)) {            
        return '[' + obj.map(o=>JSON.stringify(o)).join(',') + ']' + ',';
    }
    str = str + '{\n';
    for(var p in obj) {
        str = str + tab + ' ' + p + ' : ' + traverse(tab+' ', obj[p]) +'\n';
    }
    str = str.slice(0,-2) + str.slice(-1);                
    str = str + tab + '},';
    return str;
}('',obj).slice(0,-1)))};
```

It can show object using tab indent with readability.

Comment: Sure shot to crash your browser :P

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something that can return a prettified string of any javascript object, check out https://github.com/fresheneesz/beautinator . An example:

```
var result = beautinator({ "font-size": "26px","font-family": "'Open Sans', sans-serif",color: "white", overflow: "hidden",padding: "4px 4px 4px 8px",Text: { display: "block", width: "100%","text-align": "center", "padding-left": "2px","word-break": "break-word"}})
console.log(result)
```

Results in:

```
{ "font-size": "26px",
  "font-family": "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
  color: "white", overflow: "hidden",
  padding: "4px 4px 4px 8px",
  Text: { display: "block", width: "100%",
          "text-align": "center", "padding-left": "2px",
          "word-break": "break-word"
  }
}
```

It even works if there are functions in your object.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to show the contents of the object is using console.log as shown below

```
console.log("Object contents are ", obj);
```

Please note that I am not using '+' to concatenate the object. If I use '+' than I will only get the string representation if object, something like [Object object].

Answer (score 1):

In ES2015, using the [shorthand property declaration syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) for object literals, you can log objects while also concisely preserving your variable names:

```
console.log("bwib:", bwib, "bwab:", bwab, "bwob": bwob) // old way A
console.log({bwib: bwib, bwab: bwab, bwob: bwob})       // old way B

console.log({bwib, bwab, bwob})                         // ES2015+ way
```

[image: Demonstration in Firefox Console]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
var object = this.window;
console.log(object,'this is window object');
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will not work in a browser and you might only need this in case you want to get valid JS representation for your object and not a JSON. It just runs node inline evaluation

```
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync

const objectToSource = (obj) =>
  execSync('node -e \'console.log(JSON.parse(`' + JSON.stringify(obj) + '`))\'', { encoding: 'utf8' })

console.log(objectToSource({ a: 1 }))
```

Comment: try providing an explanation of what your code does and why you do it this way for a better understanding

Comment: It will not work in a browser and you might only need this in case you want to get valid JS representation for your object and not a JSON. It just runs node inline evaluation

Answer (score 0):

### The simplest answer

I am astounded this doesn't have a simpler answer, just a bunch of people repeating the exact same 2 things and others with unreadable code...

Here you go. If you just need the object as a string (no nested levels):

```
function prettyStringifyObject(obj: Record < any, any > ) {
  let result = ''
  for (const key in obj) {
    result = `${result}${result !== '' ? ', ' : ''}${key}: ${Array.isArray(obj[key]) ? `[${obj[key]}]` : obj[key]}`
  }
  return `{${result}}`
}
```

---

### Tests

Test with

```
const someTestObject = {
  data: [1, 2, 3, "4"],
  aString: "awdasdyhblhyb",
  aBoolean: true,
  aNumber: 50,
  aNull: null
  aNestedObject: {
    someOtherData: [],
    isNested: true
  }
}

console.log(prettyStringifyObject(someTestObject))
```

Result:

```
"{data: [1,2,3,4], aString: awdasdyhblhyb, aBoolean: true, aNumber: 50, aNull: null, aNestedObject: [object Object]}"
```

You can check the JSFiddle I made [here](https://jsfiddle.net/boscodomingo/o2dsbt0h/)

Answer (score -2):

You may use my function .
Call this function with an array or string or an object it alerts the contents.

**Function**

```
function print_r(printthis, returnoutput) {
    var output = '';

    if($.isArray(printthis) || typeof(printthis) == 'object') {
        for(var i in printthis) {
            output += i + ' : ' + print_r(printthis[i], true) + '\n';
        }
    }else {
        output += printthis;
    }
    if(returnoutput && returnoutput == true) {
        return output;
    }else {
        alert(output);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
print_r(data);
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems that a simple `for...in` can't solve the problem especially when we want to tackle apart from custom, host , native or CSSOM objects. Besides, we are talking about debugging here and who knows when and where we'll need it!

My small library can handle objects like this one:

```
    obj2
     |__ foo = 'bar'
     |__ loop2 = obj2
     |            :
     |__ another = obj1
                    |__ a1 = 1
                    |__ b1 = 'baz'
                    |__ loop1 = obj1
                    |            :
                    |__ c1 = true
                    |__ d1 = ''
                    |__ e1 = [1,2,3]
```

and present them colorful and with identation like:

1. 0, foo, 'bar'
2. 0, loop2, 'contains a circular reference to object at index 0'
3. 0, another, 'object'
4. 1, a1, 1
5. 1, b1, 'baz'
6. 1, loop1, 'contains a circular reference to object at index 2'
7. 1, c1, 'true'
8. 1, d1, ''
9. 1, e1, [1,2,3]

but see there:

1. https://github.com/centurianii/jsdebug
2. http://jsfiddle.net/centurianii/92Cmk/36/

With some precautions even `document.body` is parsed!

Comment: This seems to output HTML code, not JavaScript code.