# How do you sort an array on multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have a multidimensional array. The primary array is an array of

```
[publicationID][publication_name][ownderID][owner_name]
```

What I am trying to do is sort the array by `owner_name` and then by `publication_name`.  I know in JavaScript you have `Array.sort()`, into which you can put a custom function, in my case i have:

```
function mysortfunction(a, b) {
    var x = a[3].toLowerCase();
    var y = b[3].toLowerCase();

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

This is fine for just sorting on the one column, namely owner_name, but how do I modify it to sort on `owner_name`, then `publication_name`?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

If owner names differ, sort by them. Otherwise, use publication name for tiebreaker.

```
function mysortfunction(a, b) {

  var o1 = a[3].toLowerCase();
  var o2 = b[3].toLowerCase();

  var p1 = a[1].toLowerCase();
  var p2 = b[1].toLowerCase();

  if (o1 < o2) return -1;
  if (o1 > o2) return 1;
  if (p1 < p2) return -1;
  if (p1 > p2) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @dcp I don't see how it could also sort the second attribute. Unless you loop it as many as the number of selected columns.. Am I right? e.g. `[[A, 10], [J, 15], [A, 5], [J, 5]] => [[A, 10], [A, 5], [J, 15], [J, 5]]`

Comment: @user26409021  -  No, that's not right.  It would end up being [[A, 5], [A, 10], [J, 5], [J, 15]].  It sorts by the first attribute first, and if those are the same, then it sorts by the second attribute.  So in your example, A would come before J.  In the case where A is the same for two elements, then it would use the second attribute. So For [A,10], [A,5], 5 comes before 10 so it would end up with [A,5],[A,10] for the ordering.  The thing you may be missing is that mysortfunction is called multiple times when you use Array.sort until the sorting is completed.

Comment: @user26409021 - A loop is not needed in the mysortfunction function, because Array.sort will call the function as needed until the Array is properly sorted.  The only thing mysortfunction is responsible for is determining whether arguments a and b are equal, whether a is less than b, or whether a is greater than b. We don't need a loop to make that determination.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @dcp Is this expandable to 3+ columns?

Comment: @John Odom - Yes, you would just add the extra sort conditions as needed.  For example, if you wanted to sort by name, age, and salary (in that order), you would add the conditions (e.g. if statements) on name first, then on age, then on salary.  Order of conditions matters, because the order in which you place the conditions controls the order in which the sorting logic is applied.

Answer (score 66):

I think what you're looking for is thenBy.js: https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js

It allows you to use the standard Array.sort, but with `firstBy().thenBy().thenBy()` style.

[An example can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/n4ncq2nc/1/).

Comment: Be careful with performance on large datasets. Every time `thenBy` is called, all the array items are looped through again.

Comment: That is definitely not the case. When you call thenBy(), it constructs a new function that encapsules the previous one. At sorting time, javascript will not strictly "loop through" the items, but it _will_ call the function you pass it many times. The number of calls will not change by using thenBy. For some performance considerations, read: https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js#a-word-on-performance

Comment: I see, I was incorrect, thanks for thinking about performance. Perhaps add a note about the memory considerations of creating closures with new functions?

Comment: How to use this for multiple dynamic then? or in a for loop?

Comment: @Harry If you can't get it to work, please post an issue with the example that you cannot get to sort, so others can learn too. Happy to help you. https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js/issues

Answer (score 47):

A good way to sort on many fields that are strings is to use the `localeCompare` method and the boolean operator `||`.

Something like:

```
// Sorting record releases by name and then by title.
releases.sort((oldRelease, newRelease) => {
  const compareName = oldRelease.name.localeCompare(newRelease.name);
  const compareTitle = oldRelease.title.localeCompare(newRelease.title);

  return compareName || compareTitle;
})
```

If you wanted to sort on more fields, you could simply chain them off the return statement with more boolean operators.

Comment: as a matter of fact, you could tidy it up with a `.reduce()`

Comment: however, `.localCompare()` returns a -1, 0, 1 so I don't think your solution will work as the || is good for booleans

Comment: @ekkis, both 1 and -1 are "truthy", so this is a very elegant solution. I've just done this:

`sortItems = (a, b) => (a.distance - b.distance) || (a.name - b.name);`

and it works like a charm for my non-picky needs.

Comment: @bstst your way is better, because it doesn't evaluate `(a.name - b.name)` unless necessary.  Creating variables first does extra work even if it's not needed.

Comment: That's true, this does more work than necessary, but I would only change it in critical areas. For code that sorts a nominal amount of data, code clarity trumps the perf.

Answer (score 28):

Came across a need to do SQL-style mixed asc and desc object array sorts by keys.

kennebec's solution above helped me get to this:

```
Array.prototype.keySort = function(keys) {

keys = keys || {};

// via
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array
var obLen = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            size++;
    }
    return size;
};

// avoiding using Object.keys because I guess did it have IE8 issues?
// else var obIx = function(obj, ix){ return Object.keys(obj)[ix]; } or
// whatever
var obIx = function(obj, ix) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (size == ix)
                return key;
            size++;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

var keySort = function(a, b, d) {
    d = d !== null ? d : 1;
    // a = a.toLowerCase(); // this breaks numbers
    // b = b.toLowerCase();
    if (a == b)
        return 0;
    return a > b ? 1 * d : -1 * d;
};

var KL = obLen(keys);

if (!KL)
    return this.sort(keySort);

for ( var k in keys) {
    // asc unless desc or skip
    keys[k] = 
            keys[k] == 'desc' || keys[k] == -1  ? -1 
          : (keys[k] == 'skip' || keys[k] === 0 ? 0 
          : 1);
}

this.sort(function(a, b) {
    var sorted = 0, ix = 0;

    while (sorted === 0 && ix < KL) {
        var k = obIx(keys, ix);
        if (k) {
            var dir = keys[k];
            sorted = keySort(a[k], b[k], dir);
            ix++;
        }
    }
    return sorted;
});
return this;
};
```

sample usage:

```
var obja = [
  {USER:"bob",  SCORE:2000, TIME:32,    AGE:16, COUNTRY:"US"},
  {USER:"jane", SCORE:4000, TIME:35,    AGE:16, COUNTRY:"DE"},
  {USER:"tim",  SCORE:1000, TIME:30,    AGE:17, COUNTRY:"UK"},
  {USER:"mary", SCORE:1500, TIME:31,    AGE:19, COUNTRY:"PL"},
  {USER:"joe",  SCORE:2500, TIME:33,    AGE:18, COUNTRY:"US"},
  {USER:"sally",    SCORE:2000, TIME:30,    AGE:16, COUNTRY:"CA"},
  {USER:"yuri", SCORE:3000, TIME:34,    AGE:19, COUNTRY:"RU"},
  {USER:"anita",    SCORE:2500, TIME:32,    AGE:17, COUNTRY:"LV"},
  {USER:"mark", SCORE:2000, TIME:30,    AGE:18, COUNTRY:"DE"},
  {USER:"amy",  SCORE:1500, TIME:29,    AGE:19, COUNTRY:"UK"}
];

var sorto = {
  SCORE:"desc",TIME:"asc", AGE:"asc"
};

obja.keySort(sorto);
```

yields the following:

```
 0: {     USER: jane;     SCORE: 4000;    TIME: 35;       AGE: 16;    COUNTRY: DE;   }
 1: {     USER: yuri;     SCORE: 3000;    TIME: 34;       AGE: 19;    COUNTRY: RU;   }
 2: {     USER: anita;    SCORE: 2500;    TIME: 32;       AGE: 17;    COUNTRY: LV;   }
 3: {     USER: joe;      SCORE: 2500;    TIME: 33;       AGE: 18;    COUNTRY: US;   }
 4: {     USER: sally;    SCORE: 2000;    TIME: 30;       AGE: 16;    COUNTRY: CA;   }
 5: {     USER: mark;     SCORE: 2000;    TIME: 30;       AGE: 18;    COUNTRY: DE;   }
 6: {     USER: bob;      SCORE: 2000;    TIME: 32;       AGE: 16;    COUNTRY: US;   }
 7: {     USER: amy;      SCORE: 1500;    TIME: 29;       AGE: 19;    COUNTRY: UK;   }
 8: {     USER: mary;     SCORE: 1500;    TIME: 31;       AGE: 19;    COUNTRY: PL;   }
 9: {     USER: tim;      SCORE: 1000;    TIME: 30;       AGE: 17;    COUNTRY: UK;   }
 keySort: {  }
```

(using a print function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-print-a-javascript-object))

[here is a jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/uxibic/1/edit).

edit: [cleaned up and posted as mksort.js on github](https://github.com/bitless/mksort.js).

Answer (score 17):

This is handy for alpha sorts of all sizes.
Pass it the indexes you want to sort by, in order, as arguments.

```
Array.prototype.deepSortAlpha= function(){
    var itm, L=arguments.length, order=arguments;

    var alphaSort= function(a, b){
        a= a.toLowerCase();
        b= b.toLowerCase();
        if(a== b) return 0;
        return a> b? 1:-1;
    }
    if(!L) return this.sort(alphaSort);

    this.sort(function(a, b){
        var tem= 0,  indx=0;
        while(tem==0 && indx<L){
            itm=order[indx];
            tem= alphaSort(a[itm], b[itm]); 
            indx+=1;        
        }
        return tem;
    });
    return this;
}

var arr= [[ "Nilesh","Karmshil"], ["Pranjal","Deka"], ["Susants","Ghosh"],
["Shiv","Shankar"], ["Javid","Ghosh"], ["Shaher","Banu"], ["Javid","Rashid"]];

arr.deepSortAlpha(1,0);
```

Comment: May I know from where did you collect this data
[[ "Nilesh","Karmshil"], ["Pranjal","Deka"], ["Susants","Ghosh"],
["Shiv","Shankar"], ["Javid","Ghosh"], ["Shaher","Banu"], ["Javid","Rashid"]];

Answer (score 16):

I suggest to use a built in comparer and chain the wanted sort order with logical or `||`.

```
function customSort(a, b) {
    return a[3].localeCompare(b[3]) || a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
}
```

Working example:

```js
var array = [
    [0, 'Aluminium', 0, 'Francis'],
    [1, 'Argon', 1, 'Ada'],
    [2, 'Brom', 2, 'John'],
    [3, 'Cadmium', 3, 'Marie'],
    [4, 'Fluor', 3, 'Marie'],
    [5, 'Gold', 1, 'Ada'],
    [6, 'Kupfer', 4, 'Ines'],
    [7, 'Krypton', 4, 'Joe'],
    [8, 'Sauerstoff', 3, 'Marie'],
    [9, 'Zink', 5, 'Max']
];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[3].localeCompare(b[3]) || a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
});

document.write('<pre>');
array.forEach(function (a) {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(a) + '<br>');
});
```

Comment: This worked great for me! Simple to understand also. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You could concat the 2 variables together into a sortkey and use that for your comparison.

```
list.sort(function(a,b){
   var aCat = a.var1 + a.var2;
   var bCat = b.var1 + b.var2;
   return (aCat > bCat ? 1 : aCat < bCat ? -1 : 0);
});
```

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues maybe because it's too brittle. It would fail to sort in the expected fashion on certain input keys since it just munges the two parts together without a delimiter or other distinction. Consider if var1 and var2 for item X were "foo" and "baz", while var1 for item Y was "foobar". When sorted X should come first but in this case it would be second. This answer could be improved on but as stated it's just not safe.

Answer (score 6):

I found [multisotr](https://github.com/peterkhayes/multisort). This is simple, powerfull and small library for multiple sorting. I was need to sort an array of objects with dynamics sorting criteria:

```js
const criteria = ['name', 'speciality']
const data = [
  { name: 'Mike', speciality: 'JS', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Tom', speciality: 'Java', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Mike', speciality: 'PHP', age: 40 },
  { name: 'Abby', speciality: 'Design', age: 20 },
]

const sorted = multisort(data, criteria)

console.log(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/peterkhayes/multisort/master/multisort.js"></script>
```

This library more mutch powerful, that was my case. Try it.

Answer (score 4):

## Simply

```
t.sort( (a,b)=> a[3].localeCompare(b[3]) || a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) );
```

```js
let t = [
    //[publicationID, publication_name, ownderID, owner_name ]
    [1, 'ZBC', 3, 'John Smith'],
    [2, 'FBC', 5, 'Mike Tyson'],
    [3, 'ABC', 7, 'Donald Duck'],
    [4, 'DBC', 1, 'Michael Jackson'],
    [5, 'XYZ', 2, 'Michael Jackson'],
    [6, 'BBC', 4, 'Michael Jackson'],
  ]; 
  
  // owner_name subarrray index = 3
  // publication_name subarrray index = 1

t.sort( (a,b)=> a[3].localeCompare(b[3]) || a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) );

console.log(t.join('\n'));
```

I assume that your data in array `let t = [ [publicationID, publication_name, ownderID, owner_name ], ... ]` where index of owner_name = 3 and publication_name =1.

Comment: kudos, I have to scroll down a lot to find the simplest solution to a rather simple problem

Answer (score 4):

## String Appending Method

You can sort by multiple values simply by appending the values into a string and comparing the strings. It is helpful to add a split key character to prevent runoff from one key to the next.

## Example

```js
const arr = [ 
    { a: 1, b: 'a', c: 3 },
    { a: 2, b: 'a', c: 5 },
    { a: 1, b: 'b', c: 4 },
    { a: 2, b: 'a', c: 4 }
]


function sortBy (arr, keys, splitKeyChar='~') {
    return arr.sort((i1,i2) => {
        const sortStr1 = keys.reduce((str, key) => str + splitKeyChar+i1[key], '')
        const sortStr2 = keys.reduce((str, key) => str + splitKeyChar+i2[key], '')
        return sortStr1.localeCompare(sortStr2)
    })
}

console.log(sortBy(arr, ['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

## Recursion Method

You can also use Recursion to do this. It is a bit more complex than the String Appending Method but it allows you to do ASC and DESC on the key level. I'm commenting on each section as it is a bit more complex.

There are a few commented out tests to show and verify the sorting works with a mixture of order and default order.

## Example

```
const arr = [ 
    { a: 1, b: 'a', c: 3 },
    { a: 2, b: 'a', c: 5 },
    { a: 1, b: 'b', c: 4 },
    { a: 2, b: 'a', c: 4 }
]


function sortBy (arr, keys) {
    return arr.sort(function sort (i1,i2, sKeys=keys) {
        // Get order and key based on structure
        const compareKey = (sKeys[0].key) ? sKeys[0].key : sKeys[0];
        const order = sKeys[0].order || 'ASC'; // ASC || DESC
        // Calculate compare value and modify based on order
        let compareValue = i1[compareKey].toString().localeCompare(i2[compareKey].toString())
        compareValue = (order.toUpperCase() === 'DESC') ? compareValue * -1 : compareValue
        // See if the next key needs to be considered 
        const checkNextKey = compareValue === 0 && sKeys.length !== 1
        // Return compare value
        return (checkNextKey) ? sort(i1, i2, sKeys.slice(1)): compareValue;
    })
}

// console.log(sortBy(arr, ['a', 'b', 'c']))
console.log(sortBy(arr, [{key:'a',order:'desc'}, 'b', 'c']))
// console.log(sortBy(arr, ['a', 'b', {key:'c',order:'desc'}]))
// console.log(sortBy(arr, ['a', {key:'b',order:'desc'}, 'c']))
// console.log(sortBy(arr, [{key:'a',order:'asc'}, {key:'b',order:'desc'}, {key:'c',order:'desc'}]))
```

Comment: In my opinion, the correct option. I'll make an improvement, to make work with asc|desc options at the keys. Also one would want to have it as Array.prototype function.

Comment: The String Method is about simplicity and I can't think of a simple way of including asc and desc. So I added a recursion method that allows you to do this. It is a bit more complex but works.

Comment: Adding the function to the array prototype is a great idea but that is an implementation detail and reduces the focus of solving the problem when sharing with others.

Comment: My aproach so far is converting a locale compare for each of the strings on the properties to a 00000000 or 1111111111, join them in the same order, and locale compare again. At the locale compare ill invert the 000>111 based on the asc/desc and the compare result. in the end you'll have a 001101101001001 string to locale compare

Comment: That is a cool approach! The only thing I would say is there is some unnecessary computing as you need to compare all values regardless if you need to or not but in most cases it won’t matter. Awesome man!

Answer (score 2):

I was working with `ng-grid` and needed to to multiple column sorting on an array of records returned from an API, so I came up with this nifty, dynamic multi-sort function.

First of all, `ng-grid` fires an "event" for "ngGridSorted" and passes this structure back, describing the sort:

```
sortData = {
    columns:    DOM Element,
    directions: [], //Array of string values desc or asc. Each index relating to the same index of fields
    fields:     [], //Array of string values
};
```

So I built a function that will dynamically generate a sort function based on the `sortData` as shown above (**Don't be scared by the scroll bar! It's only about 50 lines long! Also, I'm sorry about the slop. It prevented a horizontal scrollbar!**):

```
function SortingFunction(sortData)
{
    this.sortData = sortData;

    this.sort = function(a, b)
    {
        var retval = 0;

        if(this.sortData.fields.length)
        {
            var i = 0;

            /*
                Determine if there is a column that both entities (a and b)
                have that are not exactly equal. The first one that we find
                will be the column we sort on. If a valid column is not
                located, then we will return 0 (equal).
            */
            while(  (   !a.hasOwnProperty(this.sortData.fields[i]) 
                    ||  !b.hasOwnProperty(this.sortData.fields[i]) 
                    ||  (a.hasOwnProperty(this.sortData.fields[i]) 
                        && b.hasOwnProperty(this.sortData.fields[i]) 
                        && a[this.sortData.fields[i]] === b[this.sortData.fields[i]])
                    ) && i < this.sortData.fields.length){
                i++;
            }

            if(i < this.sortData.fields.length)
            {
                /*
                    A valid column was located for both entities
                    in the SortData. Now perform the sort.
                */
                if(this.sortData.directions 
                && i < this.sortData.directions.length 
                && this.sortData.directions[i] === 'desc')
                {
                    if(a[this.sortData.fields[i]] > b[this.sortData.fields[i]])
                        retval = -1;
                    else if(a[this.sortData.fields[i]] < b[this.sortData.fields[i]])
                        retval = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(a[this.sortData.fields[i]] < b[this.sortData.fields[i]])
                        retval = -1;
                    else if(a[this.sortData.fields[i]] > b[this.sortData.fields[i]])
                        retval = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }.bind(this);
}
```

I then sort the results of my API (`results`) like so:

```
results.sort(new SortingFunction(sortData).sort);
```

I hope somebody else enjoys this solution as much as I do! Thanks!

Comment: what is the columns option on the sort data used for?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem while displaying memory pool blocks from the output of some virtual DOM h-functions composition. Basically I faced to the same problem as sorting multi-criteria data like scoring results from players around the world.

I have noticed that multi-criteria sorting is:

```
- sort by the first column
- if equal, sort by the second
- if equal, sort by the third
-  etc... nesting and nesting if-else
```

And if you don't care, you could fail quickly in a if-else nesting hell... like callback hell of promises...

What about if we write a "predicate" function to decide if which part of alternative using ? The predicate is simply :

```
// useful for chaining test
const decide = (test, other) => test === 0 ? other : test
```

Now after having written your classifying tests (byCountrySize, byAge, byGameType, byScore, byLevel...) whatever who need, you can weight your tests (1 = asc, -1 = desc, 0 = disable), put them in  an array, and apply a reducing 'decide' function like this:

```
const multisort = (s1, s2) => {
  const bcs = -1 * byCountrySize(s1, s2) // -1 = desc 
  const ba =  1 *byAge(s1, s2)
  const bgt = 0 * byGameType(s1, s2) // 0 = doesn't matter
  const bs = 1 * byScore(s1, s2)
  const bl = -1 * byLevel(s1, s2) // -1 = desc

  // ... other weights and criterias

  // array order matters !
  return [bcs, ba, bgt, bs, bl].reduce((acc, val) => decide(val, acc), 0)
}

// invoke [].sort with custom sort...
scores.sort(multisort)
```

And voila ! It's up to you to define your own criterias / weights / orders... but you get the idea. Hope this helps !

EDIT: 
 * ensure that there is a total sorting order on each column
 * be aware of not having dependencies between columns orders, and no circular dependencies

if, not, sorting can be unstable !

Answer (score 1):

```
function multiSort() {

    var args =$.makeArray( arguments ),
        sortOrder=1, prop='', aa='',  b='';

    return function (a, b) {

       for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++){

         if(args[i][0]==='-'){
            prop=args[i].substr(1)
            sortOrder=-1
         }
         else{sortOrder=1; prop=args[i]}

         aa = a[prop].toLowerCase()
         bb = b[prop].toLowerCase()

         if (aa < bb) return -1 * sortOrder;
         if (aa > bb) return 1 * sortOrder;

       }

       return 0
    }

}
empArray.sort(multiSort( 'lastname','firstname')) Reverse with '-lastname'
```

Answer (score 1):

My own library for working with ES6 iterables [(blinq)](https://github.com/biggyspender/blinq/) allows (among other things) easy multi-level sorting

```js
const blinq = window.blinq.blinq
// or import { blinq } from 'blinq'
// or const { blinq } = require('blinq')
const dates = [{
    day: 1, month: 10, year: 2000
  },
  {
    day: 1, month: 1, year: 2000
  },
  {
    day: 2, month: 1, year: 2000
  },
  {
    day: 1, month: 1, year: 1999
  },
  {
    day: 1, month: 1, year: 2000
  }
]
const sortedDates = blinq(dates)
  .orderBy(x => x.year)
  .thenBy(x => x.month)
  .thenBy(x => x.day);

console.log(sortedDates.toArray())
// or console.log([...sortedDates])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/blinq@2.0.2"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just published to npm a micro-library called [sort-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sort-helper) *([source on github](https://github.com/rdeneau/sort-helper))*. The idea is to import the helper `by` to create the comparison function for `sort` array method through the syntax `items.sort(by(column, ...otherColumns))`, with several way to express the columns to sort by:

- By *key*: `persons.sort(by('lastName', 'firstName'))`,
- By *selector*: `dates.sort(by(x => x.toISOString()))`,
- In *descending order*: `[3, 2, 4, 1].sort(by(desc(n => n)))` → `[3, 2, 1, 0]`,
- *Ignoring case*: `['B', 'D', 'c', 'a'].sort(by(ignoreCase(x => x))).join('')` → `'aBcD'`.

It's similar to the nice [thenBy](https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js) mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045190/8634147) but with the following differences that may be more to the taste of some:

- An approach more functional than object-oriented *(see `thenBy` fluent API)*,
- A syntax a bit terser and still as much readable, natural almost like SQL.
- Fully implemented in TypeScript, to benefit from type safety and type expressivity.

Answer (score 1):

Despite a lot of complicated answers here, I still like the basic way to do it

```js
var arr = [
    [3, 'pub2', 1, 'ownA'],
    [1, 'pub1', 2, 'ownA'],
    [2, 'pub1', 3, 'ownC']
];

// sorting priority is bottom to top, in this case owner name then publication name

// sort publication name
arr.sort((a,b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));
// sort owner name
arr.sort((a,b) => a[3].localeCompare(b[3]));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This depends on the implementation of `sort` being stable.  All modern engines are, but last I checked, the spec didn't insist on it.  So this could suddenly break one day when an engine changes `sort` algorithms.

Comment: Never mind.  It's [in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort) since ES2019: *"The sort must be stable (that is, elements that compare equal must remain in their original order)"*.  Carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Sourced from [GitHub](https://github.com/slawomirszwan/javascript-multi-column-sort)

```js
function sortMethodAsc(a, b) {
    return a == b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;
}

function sortMethodWithDirection(direction) { 
    if (direction === undefined || direction == "asc") {
        return sortMethodAsc;
    } else {
        return function(a, b) {
            return -sortMethodAsc(a, b);
        } 
    }
}

function sortMethodWithDirectionByColumn(columnName, direction){   
    const sortMethod = sortMethodWithDirection(direction)
    return function(a, b){
        return sortMethod(a[columnName], b[columnName]);
    } 
}

function sortMethodWithDirectionMultiColumn(sortArray) {
    //sample of sortArray
    // sortArray = [
    //     { column: "column5", direction: "asc" },
    //     { column: "column3", direction: "desc" }
    // ]
    const sortMethodsForColumn = (sortArray || []).map( item => sortMethodWithDirectionByColumn(item.column, item.direction) );
    return function(a,b) {
        let sorted = 0;
        let index = 0;
        while (sorted === 0 && index < sortMethodsForColumn.length) {
            sorted = sortMethodsForColumn[index++](a,b);
        }
        return sorted;
    }
} 

//=============================================
//=============================================
//=============================================
//test

var data = [
    {"CountryName":"Aruba","CountryCode":"ABW","GNI":280},{
        "CountryName":"Afghanistan","CountryCode":"ABW","GNI":280},{"CountryName":"Angola","CountryCode":"AGO","GNI":280},{"CountryName":"Albania","CountryCode":"ALB","GNI":4320},
        {"CountryName":"Arab World","CountryCode":"ARB","GNI":280},{"CountryName":"United Arab Emirates","CountryCode":"ARE","GNI":39130},
        {"CountryName":"Argentina","CountryCode":"ARG","GNI":13030},{"CountryName":"Armenia","CountryCode":"ARM","GNI":3990},{"CountryName":"American Samoa","CountryCode":"ASM","GNI":280},
        {"CountryName":"Antigua and Barbuda","CountryCode":"ATG","GNI":13810},{"CountryName":"Australia","CountryCode":"AUS","GNI":51360},
        {"CountryName":"Austria","CountryCode":"AUT","GNI":45440},{"CountryName":"Azerbaijan","CountryCode":"AZE","GNI":4080},{"CountryName":"Burundi","CountryCode":"BDI","GNI":280},
        {"CountryName":"Belgium","CountryCode":"BEL","GNI":41790},{"CountryName":"Benin","CountryCode":"BEN","GNI":800},{"CountryName":"Burkina Faso","CountryCode":"BFA","GNI":590},
        {"CountryName":"Bangladesh","CountryCode":"BGD","GNI":1470},{"CountryName":"Bulgaria","CountryCode":"BGR","GNI":7860},{"CountryName":"Bahrain","CountryCode":"BHR","GNI":21150},
        {"CountryName":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","CountryCode":"BIH","GNI":4910},{"CountryName":"Belarus","CountryCode":"BLR","GNI":5280},
        {"CountryName":"Belize","CountryCode":"BLZ","GNI":4390},{"CountryName":"Bolivia","CountryCode":"BOL","GNI":3130},{"CountryName":"Brazil","CountryCode":"BRA","GNI":8600},
        {"CountryName":"Barbados","CountryCode":"BRB","GNI":15270},{"CountryName":"Brunei Darussalam","CountryCode":"BRN","GNI":29600},
        {"CountryName":"Bhutan","CountryCode":"BTN","GNI":2660},{"CountryName":"Botswana","CountryCode":"BWA","GNI":6730},
        {"CountryName":"Central African Republic","CountryCode":"CAF","GNI":390},{"CountryName":"Canada","CountryCode":"CAN","GNI":42870},
        {"CountryName":"Central Europe and the Baltics","CountryCode":"CEB","GNI":13009},{"CountryName":"Switzerland","CountryCode":"CHE","GNI":80560},
        {"CountryName":"Chile","CountryCode":"CHL","GNI":13610},{"CountryName":"China","CountryCode":"CHN","GNI":8690},{"CountryName":"Cote d'Ivoire","CountryCode":"CIV","GNI":1580},
        {"CountryName":"Cameroon","CountryCode":"CMR","GNI":1370},{"CountryName":"Colombia","CountryCode":"COL","GNI":5890},{"CountryName":"Comoros","CountryCode":"COM","GNI":1280},
        {"CountryName":"Cabo Verde","CountryCode":"CPV","GNI":3030},{"CountryName":"Costa Rica","CountryCode":"CRI","GNI":11120},
        {"CountryName":"Caribbean small states","CountryCode":"CSS","GNI":8909},{"CountryName":"Cyprus","CountryCode":"CYP","GNI":23720},
        {"CountryName":"Czech Republic","CountryCode":"CZE","GNI":18160},{"CountryName":"Germany","CountryCode":"DEU","GNI":43490},
        {"CountryName":"Djibouti","CountryCode":"DJI","GNI":1880},{"CountryName":"Dominica","CountryCode":"DMA","GNI":6590},{"CountryName":"Denmark","CountryCode":"DNK","GNI":55220},
        {"CountryName":"Dominican Republic","CountryCode":"DOM","GNI":6630},{"CountryName":"Algeria","CountryCode":"DZA","GNI":3940},
        {"CountryName":"East Asia & Pacific (excluding high income)","CountryCode":"EAP","GNI":6987},{"CountryName":"Early-demographic dividend","CountryCode":"EAR","GNI":3352},
        {"CountryName":"East Asia & Pacific","CountryCode":"EAS","GNI":10171},{"CountryName":"Europe & Central Asia (excluding high income)","CountryCode":"ECA","GNI":7375},
        {"CountryName":"Europe & Central Asia","CountryCode":"ECS","GNI":22656},{"CountryName":"Ecuador","CountryCode":"ECU","GNI":5920},
        {"CountryName":"Euro area","CountryCode":"EMU","GNI":35645},{"CountryName":"Spain","CountryCode":"ESP","GNI":27180},{"CountryName":"Estonia","CountryCode":"EST","GNI":18190},
        {"CountryName":"Ethiopia","CountryCode":"ETH","GNI":740},{"CountryName":"European Union","CountryCode":"EUU","GNI":32784},
        {"CountryName":"Fragile and conflict affected situations","CountryCode":"FCS","GNI":1510},{"CountryName":"Finland","CountryCode":"FIN","GNI":44580},
        {"CountryName":"Fiji","CountryCode":"FJI","GNI":4970},{"CountryName":"France","CountryCode":"FRA","GNI":37970},{"CountryName":"Gabon","CountryCode":"GAB","GNI":6650},
        {"CountryName":"United Kingdom","CountryCode":"GBR","GNI":40530},{"CountryName":"Georgia","CountryCode":"GEO","GNI":3780},{"CountryName":"Ghana","CountryCode":"GHA","GNI":1880},
        {"CountryName":"Guinea","CountryCode":"GIN","GNI":790},{"CountryName":"Guinea-Bissau","CountryCode":"GNB","GNI":660},
        {"CountryName":"Equatorial Guinea","CountryCode":"GNQ","GNI":7050},{"CountryName":"Greece","CountryCode":"GRC","GNI":18090},
        {"CountryName":"Grenada","CountryCode":"GRD","GNI":9180},{"CountryName":"Guatemala","CountryCode":"GTM","GNI":4060},{"CountryName":"Guyana","CountryCode":"GUY","GNI":4500},
        {"CountryName":"High income","CountryCode":"HIC","GNI":40142},{"CountryName":"Honduras","CountryCode":"HND","GNI":2250},{"CountryName":"Heavily indebted poor countries (HIPC)","CountryCode":"HPC","GNI":904},{"CountryName":"Croatia","CountryCode":"HRV","GNI":12570},{"CountryName":"Haiti","CountryCode":"HTI","GNI":760},{"CountryName":"Hungary","CountryCode":"HUN","GNI":12870},{"CountryName":"IBRD only","CountryCode":"IBD","GNI":5745},{"CountryName":"IDA & IBRD total","CountryCode":"IBT","GNI":4620},{"CountryName":"IDA total","CountryCode":"IDA","GNI":1313},{"CountryName":"IDA blend","CountryCode":"IDB","GNI":1791},
        {"CountryName":"Indonesia","CountryCode":"IDN","GNI":3540},{"CountryName":"IDA only","CountryCode":"IDX","GNI":1074},{"CountryName":"India","CountryCode":"IND","GNI":1800},{"CountryName":"Ireland","CountryCode":"IRL","GNI":55290},{"CountryName":"Iraq","CountryCode":"IRQ","GNI":4630},{"CountryName":"Iceland","CountryCode":"ISL","GNI":60830},{"CountryName":"Israel","CountryCode":"ISR","GNI":37270},{"CountryName":"Italy","CountryCode":"ITA","GNI":31020},{"CountryName":"Jamaica","CountryCode":"JAM","GNI":4760},{"CountryName":"Jordan","CountryCode":"JOR","GNI":3980},{"CountryName":"Japan","CountryCode":"JPN","GNI":38550},{"CountryName":"Kazakhstan","CountryCode":"KAZ","GNI":7970},{"CountryName":"Kenya","CountryCode":"KEN","GNI":1460},{"CountryName":"Kyrgyz Republic","CountryCode":"KGZ","GNI":1130},
        {"CountryName":"Cambodia","CountryCode":"KHM","GNI":1230},{"CountryName":"Kiribati","CountryCode":"KIR","GNI":3010},{"CountryName":"St. Kitts and Nevis","CountryCode":"KNA","GNI":16240},{"CountryName":"Kuwait","CountryCode":"KWT","GNI":31430},{"CountryName":"Latin America & Caribbean (excluding high income)","CountryCode":"LAC","GNI":7470},{"CountryName":"Lao PDR","CountryCode":"LAO","GNI":2270},{"CountryName":"Lebanon","CountryCode":"LBN","GNI":8400},{"CountryName":"Liberia","CountryCode":"LBR","GNI":620},{"CountryName":"Libya","CountryCode":"LBY","GNI":5500},{"CountryName":"St. Lucia","CountryCode":"LCA","GNI":8830},{"CountryName":"Latin America & Caribbean","CountryCode":"LCN","GNI":8251},{"CountryName":"Least developed countries: UN classification","CountryCode":"LDC","GNI":1011},{"CountryName":"Low income","CountryCode":"LIC","GNI":774},{"CountryName":"Sri Lanka","CountryCode":"LKA","GNI":3850},{"CountryName":"Lower middle income","CountryCode":"LMC","GNI":2118},{"CountryName":"Low & middle income","CountryCode":"LMY","GNI":4455},{"CountryName":"Lesotho","CountryCode":"LSO","GNI":1210},{"CountryName":"Late-demographic dividend","CountryCode":"LTE","GNI":8518},{"CountryName":"Lithuania","CountryCode":"LTU","GNI":15200},{"CountryName":"Luxembourg","CountryCode":"LUX","GNI":70260},{"CountryName":"Latvia","CountryCode":"LVA","GNI":14740},{"CountryName":"Morocco","CountryCode":"MAR","GNI":2860},{"CountryName":"Moldova","CountryCode":"MDA","GNI":2200},{"CountryName":"Madagascar","CountryCode":"MDG","GNI":400},{"CountryName":"Maldives","CountryCode":"MDV","GNI":9760},
        {"CountryName":"Middle East & North Africa","CountryCode":"MEA","GNI":7236},{"CountryName":"Mexico","CountryCode":"MEX","GNI":8610},{"CountryName":"Marshall Islands","CountryCode":"MHL","GNI":4840},{"CountryName":"Middle income","CountryCode":"MIC","GNI":4942},{"CountryName":"Mali","CountryCode":"MLI","GNI":770},
        {"CountryName":"Malta","CountryCode":"MLT","GNI":24080},{"CountryName":"Myanmar","CountryCode":"MMR","GNI":1210},{"CountryName":"Middle East & North Africa (excluding high income)","CountryCode":"MNA","GNI":3832},{"CountryName":"Montenegro","CountryCode":"MNE","GNI":7400},{"CountryName":"Mongolia","CountryCode":"MNG","GNI":3270},{"CountryName":"Mozambique","CountryCode":"MOZ","GNI":420},{"CountryName":"Mauritania","CountryCode":"MRT","GNI":1100},{"CountryName":"Mauritius","CountryCode":"MUS","GNI":10130},{"CountryName":"Malawi","CountryCode":"MWI","GNI":320},{"CountryName":"Malaysia","CountryCode":"MYS","GNI":9650},{"CountryName":"North America","CountryCode":"NAC","GNI":56721},{"CountryName":"Namibia","CountryCode":"NAM","GNI":4570},{"CountryName":"Niger","CountryCode":"NER","GNI":360},{"CountryName":"Nigeria","CountryCode":"NGA","GNI":2100},
        {"CountryName":"Nicaragua","CountryCode":"NIC","GNI":2130},{"CountryName":"Netherlands","CountryCode":"NLD","GNI":46180},{"CountryName":"Norway","CountryCode":"NOR","GNI":75990},{"CountryName":"Nepal","CountryCode":"NPL","GNI":800},{"CountryName":"Nauru","CountryCode":"NRU","GNI":10220},{"CountryName":"New Zealand","CountryCode":"NZL","GNI":38970},{"CountryName":"OECD members","CountryCode":"OED","GNI":37273},{"CountryName":"Oman","CountryCode":"OMN","GNI":14440},{"CountryName":"Other small states","CountryCode":"OSS","GNI":12199},{"CountryName":"Pakistan","CountryCode":"PAK","GNI":1580},{"CountryName":"Panama","CountryCode":"PAN","GNI":13280},{"CountryName":"Peru","CountryCode":"PER","GNI":5960},{"CountryName":"Philippines","CountryCode":"PHL","GNI":3660},{"CountryName":"Palau","CountryCode":"PLW","GNI":12700},{"CountryName":"Papua New Guinea","CountryCode":"PNG","GNI":2340},{"CountryName":"Poland","CountryCode":"POL","GNI":12730},{"CountryName":"Pre-demographic dividend","CountryCode":"PRE","GNI":1379},{"CountryName":"Portugal","CountryCode":"PRT","GNI":19820},{"CountryName":"Paraguay","CountryCode":"PRY","GNI":5470},{"CountryName":"West Bank and Gaza","CountryCode":"PSE","GNI":3180},{"CountryName":"Pacific island small states","CountryCode":"PSS","GNI":3793},{"CountryName":"Post-demographic dividend","CountryCode":"PST","GNI":41609},{"CountryName":"Qatar","CountryCode":"QAT","GNI":60510},{"CountryName":"Romania","CountryCode":"ROU","GNI":10000},{"CountryName":"Russian Federation","CountryCode":"RUS","GNI":9230},{"CountryName":"Rwanda","CountryCode":"RWA","GNI":720},{"CountryName":"South Asia","CountryCode":"SAS","GNI":1729},{"CountryName":"Saudi Arabia","CountryCode":"SAU","GNI":20090},{"CountryName":"Sudan","CountryCode":"SDN","GNI":2380},{"CountryName":"Senegal","CountryCode":"SEN","GNI":1240},{"CountryName":"Singapore","CountryCode":"SGP","GNI":54530},{"CountryName":"Solomon Islands","CountryCode":"SLB","GNI":1920},{"CountryName":"Sierra Leone","CountryCode":"SLE","GNI":510},{"CountryName":"El Salvador","CountryCode":"SLV","GNI":3560},{"CountryName":"Serbia","CountryCode":"SRB","GNI":5180},{"CountryName":"Sub-Saharan Africa (excluding high income)","CountryCode":"SSA","GNI":1485},{"CountryName":"Sub-Saharan Africa","CountryCode":"SSF","GNI":1486},{"CountryName":"Small states","CountryCode":"SST","GNI":11099},{"CountryName":"Sao Tome and Principe","CountryCode":"STP","GNI":1770},{"CountryName":"Suriname","CountryCode":"SUR","GNI":5150},{"CountryName":"Slovak Republic","CountryCode":"SVK","GNI":16610},{"CountryName":"Slovenia","CountryCode":"SVN","GNI":22000},{"CountryName":"Sweden","CountryCode":"SWE","GNI":52590},{"CountryName":"Eswatini","CountryCode":"SWZ","GNI":2950},{"CountryName":"Seychelles","CountryCode":"SYC","GNI":14170},{"CountryName":"Chad","CountryCode":"TCD","GNI":640},{"CountryName":"East Asia & Pacific (IDA & IBRD countries)","CountryCode":"TEA","GNI":7061},
        {"CountryName":"Europe & Central Asia (IDA & IBRD countries)","CountryCode":"TEC","GNI":7866},{"CountryName":"Togo","CountryCode":"TGO","GNI":610},{"CountryName":"Thailand","CountryCode":"THA","GNI":5950},{"CountryName":"Tajikistan","CountryCode":"TJK","GNI":990},{"CountryName":"Turkmenistan","CountryCode":"TKM","GNI":6380},{"CountryName":"Latin America & the Caribbean (IDA & IBRD countries)","CountryCode":"TLA","GNI":8179},{"CountryName":"Timor-Leste","CountryCode":"TLS","GNI":1790},{"CountryName":"Middle East & North Africa (IDA & IBRD countries)","CountryCode":"TMN","GNI":3839},{"CountryName":"Tonga","CountryCode":"TON","GNI":4010},{"CountryName":"South Asia (IDA & IBRD)","CountryCode":"TSA","GNI":1729},
        {"CountryName":"Sub-Saharan Africa (IDA & IBRD countries)","CountryCode":"TSS","GNI":1486},{"CountryName":"Trinidad and Tobago","CountryCode":"TTO","GNI":15340},{"CountryName":"Tunisia","CountryCode":"TUN","GNI":3490},{"CountryName":"Turkey","CountryCode":"TUR","GNI":10940},{"CountryName":"Tuvalu","CountryCode":"TUV","GNI":4970},{"CountryName":"Tanzania","CountryCode":"TZA","GNI":910},{"CountryName":"Uganda","CountryCode":"UGA","GNI":600},{"CountryName":"Ukraine","CountryCode":"UKR","GNI":2390},{"CountryName":"Upper middle income","CountryCode":"UMC","GNI":8197},{"CountryName":"Uruguay","CountryCode":"URY","GNI":15250},{"CountryName":"United States","CountryCode":"USA","GNI":58270},{"CountryName":"Uzbekistan","CountryCode":"UZB","GNI":2000},{"CountryName":"St. Vincent and the Grenadines","CountryCode":"VCT","GNI":7390},{"CountryName":"Vietnam","CountryCode":"VNM","GNI":2160},{"CountryName":"Vanuatu","CountryCode":"VUT","GNI":2920},{"CountryName":"World","CountryCode":"WLD","GNI":10371},{"CountryName":"Samoa","CountryCode":"WSM","GNI":4090},{"CountryName":"Kosovo","CountryCode":"XKX","GNI":3900},
        {"CountryName":"South Africa","CountryCode":"ZAF","GNI":5430},{"CountryName":"Zambia","CountryCode":"ZMB","GNI":1290},{"CountryName":"Zimbabwe","CountryCode":"ZWE","GNI":1170},
        {"CountryName":"Zimbabwe","CountryCode":"ZWE","GNI":1171}];

    const sortMethod = sortMethodWithDirectionMultiColumn(
        [
            { column: "GNI", direction: "asc" },
            { column: "CountryCode", direction: "desc" }
        ]
    );
    let sortedData = data.sort(sortMethod);  
    
    
    console.log("sorted by: 1)column:GNI-asc, 2)column:CountryCode-desc") 
    console.table(sortedData);
    console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I need this for a small project I'm working on, so performance is not a priority.

I have two arrays, `main` array I want to be sorted, and array of sorting `rules`. I loop that `rules` array inside sorting callback function, and try to exit that loop as soon as possible.

I use multiplier in order to convert `-1` to `1` depending on weather I'm sorting a property in ascending or descending order.

```js
let array = [
    {fullName: 'Michael Schumacher', sport: 'Formula 1'},
    {fullName: 'Michael Jordan', sport: 'Basketball'},
    {fullName: 'Damon Hill', sport: 'Formula 1'},
    {fullName: 'Kobe Bryant', sport: 'Basketball'},
    {fullName: 'Lebron James', sport: 'Basketball'},
    {fullName: 'Lewis Hamilton', sport: 'Formula 1'},
];

const sortArray = (array, options) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(options)) {
        options = [{ key: options, order: 'asc' }];
    }

    options.forEach(item => {
        item.multiplier = item.order != 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
    });

    return array.sort((firstItem, secondItem) => {
        for (item of options) {
            const { key, multiplier } = item;

            const firstValue = firstItem[key];
            const secondValue = secondItem[key];

            if (firstValue != secondValue) {
                return multiplier * (firstValue < secondValue ? 1 : -1);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });
}

console.log('Original array');
console.log([...array]);

sortArray(array, 'sport');
console.log('Sorted by sport only (ascending, implicit, keeping the same order of athletes)');
console.log([...array]);

sortArray(array, [{key: 'sport'}, {key: 'fullName', order: 'desc'}]);
console.log('Sorted by sport (ascending, implicit), and by fullName (descending)');
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To simplify the understanding**

The sort method compares numbers, if below 0, it sorts it to the let, if above zero it sorts it to the right.

So to add multi level sorting, check if the match === 0, then further sort it.

See example below

```
['a/b/c', 'a long piece of text/b', 'apple/b'].sort((a, b) => {
      const asc = a.split('/').length - b.split('/').length
      return asc
    })
// outputs ['a long piece of text/b', 'apple/b', 'a/b/c']
```

```
['a/b/c', 'a long piece of text/b', 'apple/b'].sort((a, b) => {
   const asc = a.split('/').length - b.split('/').length
   return asc === 0 ? a.length - b.length : asc
 })

// outputs: 'apple/b', 'a long piece of text/b', 'a/b/c'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of complicated solutions, so I'll paste here what I'm using:

```js
assignedIssues.sort((a, b) => {
    let order = sortByText(a.assignee?.username, b.assignee?.username)

    if (order === 0) order = sort(a.labels, b.labels, statusLabels)
    if (order === 0) order = sort(a.labels, b.labels, priorityLabels)
    if (order === 0) order = sortByText(a.web_url, b.web_url)

    return order
})
```

I think that this is much more readable, let you implement any custom sorting function for each level, without calling all unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort by multiple indexes, and assuming that you don't know the type of each field (string, number, or null).
You can create a function to sort with as many indexes as you like.

```
const compareWithType = (a, b) => {
  if (typeof a === 'string') return a.localeCompare(b);
  if (typeof a === 'number') return a - b;
  return (!!a) - (!!b);  // to sort non-string non-number falsy or null values, modify as you like.
}
const compareWithIndexes = (...indexes) => {
  return (a, b) => {
    for (let i in indexes) {
      let diff = 0;
      while (!diff) {
        compareWithType(a[i], b[i]);
      }
      return diff;
    }
  }
}
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]].sort(compareWithIndexes(2, 3, 4)); 
// compares (3 - 3) then (4 - 4) then (5 - 6)
```