# Sorting a JSON object by two fields

Tags: javascript, json

I have the follow json object

```
[
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 1","DISTANCE":20,"TYPE":"1"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 2","DISTANCE":14,"TYPE":"2"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 3","DISTANCE":60,"TYPE":"2"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 4","DISTANCE":37,"TYPE":"1"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 5","DISTANCE":25,"TYPE":"2"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 6","DISTANCE":90,"TYPE":"1"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 7","DISTANCE":49,"TYPE":"1"}
]
```

I'd like to sort it first by type and then by distance so the result would be the following.

```
[
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 1","DISTANCE":20,"TYPE":"1"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 4","DISTANCE":37,"TYPE":"1"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 7","DISTANCE":49,"TYPE":"1"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 6","DISTANCE":90,"TYPE":"1"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 2","DISTANCE":14,"TYPE":"2"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 5","DISTANCE":25,"TYPE":"2"},
{"PARTNERNAME":"Partner 3","DISTANCE":60,"TYPE":"2"}
]
```

I have the following code that sorts it by one field but I can get it to sort by two fields. Is this possible?

```
var sortedData = propertyArray.sort(sortByProperty('DISTANCE'));
function sortByProperty(property) {
            'use strict';
            return function (a, b) {
                var sortStatus = 0;
                if (a[property] < b[property]) {
                    sortStatus = -1;
                } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
                    sortStatus = 1;
                }

                return sortStatus;
            };
        }
```

Comment: A very good anser can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/javascript-how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns

Comment: JSON is text, that is an [*Array initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4), aka Array literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.TYPE === b.TYPE ? a.DISTANCE - b.DISTANCE : a.TYPE - b.TYPE
})
```

Comment: It can actually be: `return a.TYPE - b.TYPE || a.DISTANCE - b.DISTANCE`l If the TYPE isn't equal it will sort on that and if it is equal, the first expression will be 0 and so the difference in distance is returned.

Comment: Excellent, works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

There is very useful function in LoDash:

`console.log(_.sortBy(propertyArray, "TYPE", "DISTANCE"));`

or custom solution:

`function sortBy() {
    var arr = arguments[0];
    var fields = [].slice.call(arguments, 1)
    return arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (a[fields[i]] != b[fields[i]]) {
                return a[fields[i]] > b[fields[i]];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });
}`

using:

`console.log(sortBy(a, "TYPE", "DISTANCE"));`

http://jsfiddle.net/hpzfLq76/

Comment: @RobG, added a custom solution