# Sort a string date array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to sort an array in ascending order. The dates are in string format

```
["09/06/2015", "25/06/2015", "22/06/2015", "25/07/2015", "18/05/2015"]
```

Even need a function to check whether these dates are in continuous form:

```
eg - Valid   - ["09/06/2015", "10/06/2015", "11/06/2015"] 
     Invalid - ["09/06/2015", "25/06/2015", "22/06/2015", "25/07/2015"]
```

Example code:

```
function sequentialDates(dates){
        var temp_date_array = [];

        $.each(dates, function( index, date ) {
            //var date_flag = Date.parse(date);
            temp_date_array.push(date);
        });

        console.log(temp_date_array);

        var last;
        for (var i = 0, l = temp_date_array.length; i < l; i++) {

          var cur = new Date();
          cur.setTime(temp_date_array[i]);
          last = last || cur;
          //console.log(last+' '+cur);

          if (isNewSequence(cur, last)) {
            console.log("Not Sequence");
          }
        }

        //return dates;
    }

     function isNewSequence(a, b) {
          if (a - b > (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
              return true;
          return false;
      }
```

Comment: Do you have some code already?

Comment: Use _ISO 8601_ when storing a _Date_ as a _String_, it'll save you headaches

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### The Simple Solution

There is no need to convert Strings to Dates or use RegExp.

The simple solution is to use the Array.sort() method.  The sort function sets the date format to YYYYMMDD and then compares the string value. Assumes date input is in format DD/MM/YYYY.

```
data.sort(function(a,b) {
  a = a.split('/').reverse().join('');
  b = b.split('/').reverse().join('');
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
  // return a.localeCompare(b);         // <-- alternative 
});
```

**Update:**

A helpful comment suggested using `localeCompare()` to simplify the sort function. This alternative is shown in the above code snippet.

**Run Snippet to Test**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body style="font-family: monospace">
<ol id="stdout"></ol>
<script>
  var data = ["09/06/2015", "25/06/2015", "22/06/2015", "25/07/2015", "18/05/2015"];

data.sort(function(a,b) {
  a = a.split('/').reverse().join('');
  b = b.split('/').reverse().join('');
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
  
  // return a.localeCompare(b);         // <-- alternative 
  
});

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
  stdout.innerHTML += '<li>' + data[i];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RobG - Thanks, that was a good suggestion and I've noted the alternative in the answer.

Comment: @ritesh - If your data contains same dates then you may need to add additional sorting criteria. See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230

Answer (score 9):

You will need to convert your strings to dates, and compare those dates, if you want to sort them. You can make use of the parameter that the `sort` method accepts, in order to achieve this:

```
var dateStrings = ["09/06/2015", "25/06/2015", "22/06/2015", "25/07/2015", "18/05/2015"];
var sortedStrings = dateStrings.sort(function(a,b) {
    var aComps = a.split("/");
    var bComps = b.split("/");
    var aDate = new Date(aComps[2], aComps[1], aComps[0]);
    var bDate = new Date(bComps[2], bComps[1], bComps[0]);
    return aDate.getTime() - bDate.getTime();
});
```

In order to reduce code redundancy, and to handle different date formats, you can add an additional function that will create the comparator needed by the `sort` method:

```
function createSorter(dateParser) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var aDate = dateParser(a);
        var bDate = dateParser(b);
        return aDate.getTime() - bDate.getTime();
    };
}

dateStrings.sort(createSorter(function(dateString) {
    var comps = dateString.split("/");
    return new Date(comps[2], comps[1], comps[0]);
}));
```

You can then use different date formatters by passing different functions to the `createSorter` call.

As for your second question, you can create an (sorted) array of dates from your strings, and perform your logic on that array:

```
function myDateParser(dateString) {
    var comps = dateString.split("/");
    return new Date(comps[2], comps[1], comps[0]);
}

var sortedDates = dateStrings.map(myDateParser).sort();
```

You can walk through the `sortedDates` array and if you find two non-consecutive dates, then you have dates with gaps between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateRE = /^(\d{2})[\/\- ](\d{2})[\/\- ](\d{4})/;
function dmyOrdA(a, b){
a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
if (a>b) return 1;
if (a <b) return -1;
return 0; }
function dmyOrdD(a, b){
a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
if (a>b) return -1;
if (a <b) return 1;
return 0; }
function mdyOrdA(a, b){
a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
if (a>b) return 1;
if (a <b) return -1;
return 0; }
function mdyOrdD(a, b){
a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
if (a>b) return -1;
if (a <b) return 1;
return 0; } 

dateArray = new Array("09/06/2015", "25/06/2015", "22/06/2015", "25/07/2015", "18/05/2015");
var c = dateArray.sort( dmyOrdA );

console.log(c);
```

Comment: it will return ["18/05/2015", "09/06/2015", "22/06/2015", "25/06/2015", "25/07/2015"]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using es6 arrow functions; does the job in 2 lines.

The problem I see with the most voted answer here is that it would fail when the leading zero is missing for days/month which are single digit.

Ex:
`var data = ["9/6/2015", "12/6/2015", "22/6/2015", "25/7/2015", "18/5/2015"];`.

The most reliable way to do this would be to use date sort instead of a string sort. Although in a performance point of view, it might look to be an overhead to cast these strings to Date.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <body style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 16px;">
  <ol id="demo"></ol>

  <script>
    var data = ["09/06/2015", "25/06/2015", "22/06/2015", "25/07/2015", "18/05/2015"];
    const toDate = (el) => new Date(el.split('/').reverse().join('-'));
    data.sort((a, b) => toDate(a) - toDate(b));


    // renders the results in an ordered list
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
      demo.innerHTML += `<li> ${data[i]}`;
  </script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

To sort your date string ascendingly *without alteration to its value*, try this:

```
var T = ["09/06/2015", "25/06/2015", "22/06/2015", "25/07/2015", "18/05/2015"];

var sortedT = T.sort(s1,s2){
    var sdate1 = s1.split('/');
    var sdate2 = s2.split('/');
    var date1 = s1[1]+'/'+s1[0]+'/'+s1[2];
    var date2 = s2[1]+'/'+s2[0]+'/'+s2[2];
    if (Date.parse(date1) > Date.parse(date2)) return 1;
    else if (Date.parse(date1) < Date.parse(date2) return -1;
    else return 0;
}
```

The resultant array `sortedT` should be a sorted array of date string.

**NOTE:**

Your date format is stored in `dd/mm/yyyy` but the standard date format of JavaScript is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Thus, in order to parse this string to Date without using external date format library, the date string is therefore needed to be converted for compatibility during sort.