# How to sort a javascript array by date

Tags: javascript

For example in my array i have this data

```
var mydate = [
"2016,10,01",
"2016,09,13", 
"2016,09,05",
"2016,09,09", 
"2016,10,02"];
```

How to sort this?
I want this output:

```
2016,09,05
2016,09,09
2016,09,13
2016,10,01
2016,10,02
```

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do this, super basic example: remove the commas, turn it into an int and use a generic int sort.

Comment: mydate.sort() is the least you could do

Comment: @DBS or don't remove anything and sort the string

Comment: @mplungjan Fair enough, I didn't think about the string equivalents of numbers working correctly in "alphabetical" order, but that makes sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691066/sort-a-string-date-array

Comment: @Paul In that question they're using dd/mm/yyyy, so the solution is significantly more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to parse date into date object and then sort using `date.getTime()`

```js
var mydate = [
  "2016,10,01",
  "2016,09,13",
  "2016,09,05",
  "2016,09,09",
  "2016,10,02"
];

mydate.sort(function(a,b){
  var da = new Date(a).getTime();
  var db = new Date(b).getTime();
  
  return da < db ? -1 : da > db ? 1 : 0
});
console.log(mydate)
```

Answer (score 8):

A simple `mydate.sort()` could do that.

Comment: w0w nice function I didn't know it exist

Comment: Will `.sort()` not sort based on string values?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes and the string "2016,10,02" sorts higher than "2016,10,01" and will sort correctly. It will fail from year "10000,01,01"

Comment: @mplungjan it will also fail if OP adds time in string. Also I would not suggest sorting based on string values. Its not a reliable solution

Comment: Keep in mind In the year 10K you may be resurrected or cloned or downloaded into something and required to fix this.

Comment: @Tester your sort will fail for "2016, 2, 02" as well. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfk0c23m/)

Comment: yes but the current problem set don't need this. since the format I see is yyyy,mm,dd.. And this is the simplest sorting thing for this format.

Comment: @Rajesh - this will sort perfectly too: "2016,10,13,13:01:23" - if the time is in am/pm then not, but so far we have a sortable date string

Comment: @mplungjan if you add date as `"2016,10,2,13:01:23"`, this will fail.

Comment: Yes I know. So don't

Comment: I answered the question and it was about the format yyyy,mm,dd nothing more nothing less.. It can fail 1000 cases which are not mentioned.. How about HH:mm,yyyy,mm,dd this will also fail for sure.. Think this simplest solution as per the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`Array#sort`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqyvyxm8PPAhUOxGMKHSwtDhIQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort&usg=AFQjCNHhsnTi-QNulIOp5Xp29WT6GRduuw&sig2=prIYm_5fdI9F-GI8-xNh7w)** method with **[`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** constructor.

```js
var mydate = [
  "2016,10,01",
  "2016,09,13",
  "2016,09,05",
  "2016,09,09",
  "2016,10,02"
];

mydate.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(...a.split(',')) - new Date(...b.split(','));
});

console.log(mydate);
```

---

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) not supported by older browser in that case do it like.

```js
var mydate = [
  "2016,10,01",
  "2016,09,13",
  "2016,09,05",
  "2016,09,09",
  "2016,10,02"
];

mydate.sort(function(a, b) {
  var a1 = a.split(','),
    b1 = b.split(',');
  return new Date(a1[0], a1[1], a1[2]) - new Date(b1[0], b1[1], b1[2]);
});

console.log(mydate);
```

Comment: can you explain Date(...a.split(','))

Comment: @sheetal : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: @sheetal :  which helps to treat the array value as it's argument

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mydate = [
  "2016,10,01",
  "2016,09,13",
  "2016,09,05",
  "2016,09,09",
  "2016,10,02"
];

mydate.sort(function(a,b){
  var da = new Date(a).getTime();
  var db = new Date(b).getTime();
  
  return da - db
});
console.log(mydate)
```