# Sort an array of timestamps in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, timestamp, leaflet

I am developing an Angular web service for creating photo journeys and displaying them on a map using Leaflet.
When I upload the pictures, I get their coordinates from their EXIF data and their **DateTimeOriginal** from it which returns string like this:

[image]

and then save them in array for a further connecting with paths on a map.

I have issues with sorting this array by timestamps in order to connect the markers on the map properly:

[image]

How can I sort by time-stamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a string date array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691066/sort-a-string-date-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that the dates are invalid. 
If it would be properly formatted like this ("2012/10/24 16:37:44") you might do this:

```
const a = new Date("2012/10/24 16:37:44").getTime();
```

For example, you would map over items in this array

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

items.map(item => new Date(item.timestamp).getTime()).sort(sortNumber);
```

Comment: What I did is to replace the **:** in the time-stamp string and make it appropriate for parsing to a Date object, and then sorting the array by dates: 

`sortMarkers() {
    this.currentMarkers.map(m => {
      let mTimestamp: string = m.timestamp.substring(0, 10);
      mTimestamp = mTimestamp.replace(/:/g, '-');
      m.timestamp = mTimestamp + m.timestamp.substring(10);
      m.date = new Date(m.timestamp);
    });

    this.currentMarkers = this.currentMarkers.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.date - b.date;
    });
  }`