# Read values in a cypress table and give me the most recent

Tags: html-table, cypress

I want to check in Cypress if the content in all rows of the column Name Document is identical. Let's say

| Name Document | Issue Date |
| --- | --- |
| GOL | 21-06-2023 |
| GOL | 30-05-2023 |

This table does not have a fixed number of rows.

[image]

Bonus question: How can check if the most recent (Issue date column) is on the top?

Comment: Please add the HTML of the table (or an example of it) and any Cypress code you've tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: @agoff I haven't tried anything yet, I want to know how to handle a dynamic table in Cypress

Answer (score 5):

**All of first column has value "GOL"**

To extract column 1 elements only, use `cy.get('tr td:nth-child(1)')`

To map to the text inside, this is a useful recipe [Getting Text from List of Elements](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/recipes/get-text-list.html)

```js
const getTexts = (els) => Cypress._.map(els, 'innerText')
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(1)')
  .then(getTexts)
  .should('deep.equal', ['GOL', 'GOL', 'GOL'])
```

If the rows are dynamic, use `.every()`

```js
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(1)')
  .then(getTexts)
  .should(vals => {
    const allFirstColHasGol = vals.every(val => val === 'GOL')
    assert(allFirstColHasGol, 'All first column has value "GOL"'))
  })
```

---

**First date is the latest**

I recommend the [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format) library to handle dates

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
const customParseFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat')
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)


const getTexts = (els) => Cypress._.map(els, 'innerText')
const toDate = (els) => Cypress._.map(els, el => dayjs(el, 'MM-DD-YYYY').$d) 

cy.get('tr td:nth-child(4)')
  .then(getTexts)
  .then(toDate)
  .should(dates => {
    const firstDateIsLateset = dates.slice(1).every(date => dates[0] > date)
    assert(firstDateIsLateset, 'First date is the largest'))
  })
```

---

**TDD** with the following, and change column values to make it pass/fail

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a>GOL</a></td>
      <td><span>06-02-2023</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a>GOL</a></td>
      <td><span>06-01-2023</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's an elegant way to handle the problem - reusable steps. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab all of the `tr` elements underneath the `tbody`. You can then query for all results that are underneath `tbody`, are `tr`, and have your text (in your example, `GOL`), and compare the size of those two lists. This example assumes there is only one table on the screen.

```js
cy.get('tbody tr').then(($tr) => { // find all `tr` underneath `tbody`
  cy.get('tbody tr:contains("GOL")') // use JQuery :contains() to find elements
    .should('have.length', $tr.length)
});
```

If you did not know the text of the first row, you could grab it from the yielded `$tr` element.

```js
cy.get('tbody tr').then(($tr) => {
  const firstRowText = $tr[0].text();
  cy.get(`tbody tr:contains("${firstRowText}")`).should('have.length', $tr.length);
});
```

And if you need to operate an if/else based on them being equal:

```js
cy.get('tbody tr').then(($tr) => {
  const firstRowText = $tr[0].text();
  cy.get(`tbody tr:contains("${firstRowText}")`).then(($el) => {
    if ($el.length === $tr.length) {
      // code here
    } else {
      // code here
    }
  });
});
```

For your bonus question, you would have to grab all of the dates. [From that list, you could sort them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30691186/11625850) and check if the first item in each list is equal.

```js
cy.get('tbody tr span').then(($dates) => {
  const firstDate = $dates[0].text()
  // For an explanation of what this is doing, look at the linked answer
  const sortedDates = $dates.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = a.text().split('/').reverse().join('');
    b = b.text().split('/').reverse().join('');
    return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;  
  });
  expect(sortedDates[0].text()).to.eql(firstDate);
});
```

Comment: the first solution was having a discrepancy in    '.should('have.length', $tr.length)' it was expecting a number but was returned other. So, I removed this part and it worked, it is comparing the lines. about the bonus answer I am getting ```$dates[0].text is not a function``` . I forgot to mention the dates on my system are on the format mm/dd/yyyy