# Sorting Jquery Table that JSON data appended via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to sort the table to be sorted by following order.  I used JQuery table to display the JSON data. I tried using tablesorter plugin and I failed to configure it. Is there any way to sort this table.

1. Failed
2. Aborted
3. Success

JSON Data

```
{
      "Product":"APIM",
      "Day01":"Success",
      "Day02":"Aborted",
      "Day03":"Failed",
      "Day04":"Failed",
      "Day05":"Failed",
      "Day06":"Failed",
      "Day07":"Success"
   },
   {
      "Product":"AppFactory",
      "Day01":"Aborted",
      "Day02":"Success",
      "Day03":"Success",
      "Day04":"Success",
      "Day05":"Success",
      "Day06":"Success",
      "Day07":"Success"
   },
```

Append Data (dataBind.js)

```
$.post("/portal/controllers/apis/test.jag", {
    action: "getData"
}, function(data) {

    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("----------------------------------start----------------------------");
    var Day = result[result.length - 1].Days;

    $("#tableid").append("<thead><tr><th> Product </th> <th >" + Day[0].substring(5, 11) + "</th> <th>" + Day[1].substring(5, 11) + "</th> <th>" + Day[2].substring(5, 11) + "</th><th>" + Day[3].substring(5, 11) + "</th><th>" + Day[4].substring(5, 11) + "</th><th>" + Day[5].substring(5, 11) + "</th><th> Current </th><th> Failed Components </th><th> Failed Duration </th></tr></thead>");

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $("#tableid").append("<tbody><tr><td>" + result[i].product + "</td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day01 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day02 + ".png' /><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day03 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day04 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day05 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day06 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day07 + ".png' /></td><td>" + result[i].Failed.Component + "</td><td>" + result[i].Failed.Duration + "</td></tr></tbody>");

    }

    console.log("----------------------------------End Table----------------------------");
});
```

HTML

```
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Build Data Table</title>
    
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/dataBind.js"></script>

    </head>
    
    <body style="height: 1100px;">
    <div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <table id = "tableid">
    
    </table>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have 7 days. How are you supposed to sort it by status for 7 days?

Comment: Oh! forgot to mention. I want to sort only the column of Day07 which is the last day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply `Array.prototype.sort` with a custom comparing function:

```
var sortOrder = ['Failed', 'Aborted', 'Success']; // <--- Look here

$.post("/portal/controllers/apis/test.jag", {
    action: "getData"
}, function(data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    var Day = result[result.length - 1].Days;

    /* Look here: */
    result = result.sort(function(a, b) { 
        return sortOrder.indexOf(a.Day07) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.Day07);
    });
    /* ---------- */

    $("#tableid").append("<thead><tr><th> Product </th> <th >" + Day[0].substring(5, 11) + "</th> <th>" + Day[1].substring(5, 11) + "</th> <th>" + Day[2].substring(5, 11) + "</th><th>" + Day[3].substring(5, 11) + "</th><th>" + Day[4].substring(5, 11) + "</th><th>" + Day[5].substring(5, 11) + "</th><th> Current </th><th> Failed Components </th><th> Failed Duration </th></tr></thead>");

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $("#tableid").append("<tbody><tr><td>" + result[i].product + "</td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day01 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day02 + ".png' /><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day03 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day04 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day05 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day06 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day07 + ".png' /></td><td>" + result[i].Failed.Component + "</td><td>" + result[i].Failed.Duration + "</td></tr></tbody>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Yeldar for quick answer it saved my day. I was thinking to go for different table format where I can sort that column. One more thing, how can I sort data order of 1st Day07 column then Day06 column then Day05 likewise..

Comment: @ThilinaAkalanka It would be pretty much harder :) You can refer to this SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/javascript-how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields.

Comment: https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js This helped me to solve it. It's an improved solution of yours. Thanks again for your guidance much appreciated.