# Sort javascript array by multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects something like this

```
var itemArray = [
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "flag": true,
    },
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "flag": false,
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "flag": false,
    },
    {
        "name": "name3",
        "flag": true,
    }        
];
```

I am already sorting this by the name key using the following:

```
var sortedItems = sortByKey(itemArray, "name");

function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key];
        var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
});
```

How do i also sort it by the flag key alphabetically so the false flags appear before the true flags? (I can use a string instead of boolean on the flag property if this makes it simpler)

To clarify, what I am looking for is an array which would be returned like this for example:

```
[
    { name: "name_a", flag: false },
    { name: "name_a", flag: true },
    { name: "name_b", flag: false },
    { name: "name_b", flag: true},
    { name: "name_c", flag: true},
    { name: "name_d", flag: false},
]
```

Comment: The logic is simple: in your comparison function you first make your primary comparison, if this is *not equal*, you return the comparison result, else you do your secondary comparison and return its result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, how do you sort an array on multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/javascript-how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var sortedItems = sortByKey(itemArray, "name");

```
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a[key] == b[key]) {
          return (a['flag'] ? -1 : 1);
        } else {
          var x = a[key];
          var y = b[key];
          return x.localeCompare(y);
        }
});
```

Comment: Yes! That looks like it's working perfectly. Thank you so much for spending your valuable time helping me Eduard, it is genuinely appreciated.

Comment: was my pleasure :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedItems = sortByKey(itemArray, "name");

    function sortByKey(array, key) {
        return array.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(a['flag'] == f['flag']) {
              var x = a[key];
              var y = b[key];
              return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
            } else {
              return (a['flag'] ? -1 : 1);
            }
    });
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this. It does not completely sort by name. Some are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: change ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0)) to x.localeCompare(y)

Comment: Still, this returns a list where all the items with a true flag are in alphabetical order by name, followed by all the items with false flags which are in alphabetical order by name. What I am looking for is a sorted list where the whole list is in alphabetical order by name, and also the flags are sorted alphabetically. e.g. "{ name: "name_a", flag: false }, { name: "name_a", flag: true}, {name: "name_b", flag: false }, {name: "name_b", flag: true}...

Comment: see my another answer. you can edit the ordering function anyway. the first you compare is the main sorting attribute and then follow to the comparation of other attributes

Answer (score 1):

You could use a proper callback, sort first by `flag` and if equal then by `name`.

```js
var itemArray = [{ "name": "name1", "flag": true, }, { "name": "name1", "flag": false, }, { "name": "name2", "flag": false, }, { "name": "name3", "flag": true, }];

itemArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.flag - b.flag;
}),

console.log(itemArray);
```

Comment: This appears to just sort by the flag key

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: Actually, running the snippet only sorts by the flag, when I run it on my code it only sorts by the name, e.g. I now have a sorted array which contains the following data:

    name: "some name" flag: true,
    name: "some name" flag: false,
    name: "some name" flag: true