# Order array of objects by custom field, then alphabetically

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects, each object has 2 values, priority and name.

```
var people = [
        {
            "name" : "Jim",
            "priority" : "Low"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Gary",
            "priority" : "Medium"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Andrew",
            "priority" : "Medium"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Bill",
            "priority" : "High"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Edward",
            "priority" : "Medium"
        }
    ]
```

I would like to sort this array, ordering by priority High to Low, and then within each priority, by name alphabetically.

Ordering alphabetically is easy enough:

```
people = _.orderBy(people, 'name');
```

But how would I sort by priority in the way I want?

Comment: This might help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns

Comment: You can use ``_.orderBy`` to have multiple sorting options. Like example provided on lodash document. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **create a map for specifying the order of priorities** and then can use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like following

```js
let priorityMap = {"High" : 3,"Medium" : 2,"Low" : 1};
let people = [{"name":"Jim","priority":"Low"},{"name":"Gary","priority":"Medium"},{"name":"Andrew","priority":"Medium"},{"name":"Bill","priority":"High"},{"name":"Edward","priority":"Medium"}];
people.sort((a,b) => priorityMap[b.priority] - priorityMap[a.priority] || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
console.log(people);
```

Comment: Ah yes, seems so simple once it's explained, thanks!

Comment: @Daft - Glad to help you!

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal I am glad my answer was very close to yours :)

Comment: @NitishNarang - Glad to see your answer too mate :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved via "sort" as below.

```
var people = [
        {
            "name" : "Jim",
            "priority" : "Low"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Gary",
            "priority" : "Medium"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Andrew",
            "priority" : "Medium"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Bill",
            "priority" : "High"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Edward",
            "priority" : "Medium"
        }
    ]
let priority = {"High": 0, "Medium": 1, "Low": 2}
people.sort((a,b) => priority[a.priority] - priority[b.priority] || a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

Comment: Yes I see now. This happens when we proceed on similar lines of thought :)