# Sorting array by date and time in same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, angular5

I am building shedule app, so  i need to sort items by date and time in same time.  Like you see in example i can only filter hours and minuts and that works, but i need to filter dates too

I am storing date in datebase like YYYY-MM-DD and time by hours and minuts like string for example: hours:"08",minuts:"25".

```
 this.ord3ref.on("child_added", data => {
      this.ord3.push({
        key: data.key,
        data: data.val()
      });
      this.ord3.sort(
        (a, b) => a.data.hours- b.data.hours || a.data.minuts- b.data.minuts
      );
    });
```

[image]
[image: like you see on image it sorts array by hours and minuts, but its need to be sorted by dates first, that with hours and minuts]

like you see on image it sorts array by hours and minuts, but its need to be sorted by dates first, than with hours and minuts...

Comment: can you give one example of the data object? not sure I fully understand how it looks

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. What does `ord3` look like?

Comment: If a.data and b.data are both Date object, you can do a.data > b.data

Comment: maybe t his will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784265/5066625

Comment: Added new images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data contains a key/value for date then you should be able to just substitute your sort function with this:

```
this.ord3.sort(
    (a, b) => {
        var dateA = new Date(a.data.date).valueOf();
        var dateB = new Date(b.data.date).valueOf();
        return a.data.hours - b.data.hours || a.data.minuts - b.data.minuts || dateA - dateB;
    }
);
```

javascript `Date` objects can be created from the date strings in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

The `.valueOf()` method returns the number of milliseconds from UTC time - see [MDN's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf#Return_value) explanation of it.

Comment: Big tnx. Now it sort by date, than i same day it sort by hours and minuts, ty ty!!!