# Sort on multiple field in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to perform sort operation based on multiple fields.
The sort order of the Grid should be descending on DC Due Date/ Not before fields and then on descending on Order Number. This is what I have tried so far but got no success.

```
var data = [{
  "orderNumber": 10040207,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-01-28T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041707,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10001471,
  "dcDueDate": "2018-04-23T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041213,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-03-25T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041747,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041768,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-08-05T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041624,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-10T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041745,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041728,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-02-11T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041625,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-10T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041763,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-04-08T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10039839,
  "dcDueDate": "2018-07-09T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041751,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 96927595,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-02-25T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041654,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-09-23T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041694,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-04-22T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040811,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-02-18T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041700,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-17T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041651,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-09-23T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041621,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041766,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-08-19T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040490,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-29T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041736,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-10T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040609,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041702,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-17T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041729,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041752,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10039411,
  "dcDueDate": "2018-04-03T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041029,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041748,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041622,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041793,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041637,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-11-11T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041744,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040489,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-29T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040610,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-03-25T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 12,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-04-15T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041656,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-08T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041038,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 96927577,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-24T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041708,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041730,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041709,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041796,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10038268,
  "dcDueDate": "2020-03-09T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041710,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041663,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-10-21T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040055,
  "dcDueDate": "2018-07-08T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040549,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-05-13T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 16784298,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2018-12-03T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041636,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-11-11T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041643,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041623,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041770,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-03-18T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040354,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-03-18T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041647,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041650,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-10-07T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041794,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041693,
  "departmentId": "008",
  "departmentName": "",
  "status": {
    "status": "Open",
    "updatedAt": "2019-02-08T01:06:55.893957"
  },
  "supplierId": 426145,
  "portId": null,
  "eventCode": "P10W5F19",
  "locality": "Local",
  "destinationCountry": "NewZealand",
  "internationalCommercialTerms": "IIS/FIW STR/DC(A TO NZ VIA FTC/XDO)",
  "allocationStage": "StoreAllocation",
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "ffDueDate": null,
  "ffBookedDate": null,
  "transportMethod": null,
  "isNewLine": false,
  "createdBy": "BYP",
  "createdAt": "2019-02-08T00:00:00.0000000",
  "advertisedDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-04-22T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notAfterDate": "2019-04-25T00:00:00.0000000",
  "lineItems": []
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041749,
  "departmentId": "008",
  "departmentName": "",
  "status": {
    "status": "Open",
    "updatedAt": "2019-02-15T04:57:43.953292"
  },
  "supplierId": 426145,
  "portId": null,
  "eventCode": "P12W2F19",
  "locality": "Local",
  "destinationCountry": "NewZealand",
  "internationalCommercialTerms": "IIS/FIW STR/DC(A TO NZ VIA FTC/XDO)",
  "allocationStage": "StoreAllocation",
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "ffDueDate": null,
  "ffBookedDate": null,
  "transportMethod": null,
  "isNewLine": false,
  "createdBy": "BYP",
  "createdAt": "2019-02-15T00:00:00.0000000",
  "advertisedDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notAfterDate": "2019-06-06T00:00:00.0000000",
  "lineItems": []
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041762,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-04-08T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041655,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-08T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10039840,
  "dcDueDate": "2018-07-09T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041750,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041773,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-03-18T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040533,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-05-13T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041740,
  "departmentId": "008",
  "dcDueDate": "2019-12-02T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041646,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041645,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-12-02T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040049,
  "dcDueDate": "2018-07-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041732,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041696,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041731,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10040075,
  "dcDueDate": "2018-07-08T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041635,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-04-08T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041627,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-06-17T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041771,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-03-18T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 10041641,
  "dcDueDate": null,
  "notBeforeDate": "2019-12-30T00:00:00.0000000"
}, {
  "orderNumber": 17022057,
  "dcDueDate": "2019-04-15T00:00:00.0000000",
  "notBeforeDate": null
}];

function sortByTime(a,b){
    let atTime = a.dcDueDate || a.notBeforeDate;
    let btTime = b.dcDueDate || b.notBeforeDate;
  let timeDiff = new Date(btTime) - new Date(atTime);
  return timeDiff
  //return new Date(a).getTime()
}

function sortByOrderNumber(a){
        return a.orderNumber      
}

console.log(_.sortBy(data, ['dcDueDate'],['desc']));

console.log('chnda')

/* console.table(data.sort((a,b)=> {
  let atTime = a.dcDueDate || a.notBeforeDate;
  let btTime = b.dcDueDate || b.notBeforeDate;
  let timeDiff = new Date(btTime) - new Date(atTime);
  timeDiff = 0;
  if(timeDiff){
    return timeDiff
  }else{
    return b.orderNumber - a.orderNumber      
  }
})) */
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you sort an array on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the dates and use a string compare ([`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)) and the delta of `orderNumber`.

```js
var data = [{ orderNumber: 10040207, dcDueDate: "2019-01-28T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041707, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10001471, dcDueDate: "2018-04-23T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041213, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-03-25T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041747, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041768, dcDueDate: "2019-08-05T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041624, dcDueDate: "2019-06-10T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041745, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041728, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-02-11T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041625, dcDueDate: "2019-06-10T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041763, dcDueDate: "2019-04-08T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10039839, dcDueDate: "2018-07-09T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041751, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 96927595, dcDueDate: "2019-02-25T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041654, dcDueDate: "2019-09-23T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041694, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-04-22T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10040811, dcDueDate: "2019-02-18T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041700, dcDueDate: "2019-06-17T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041651, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-09-23T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041621, dcDueDate: "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041766, dcDueDate: "2019-08-19T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10040490, dcDueDate: "2019-07-29T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041736, dcDueDate: "2019-06-10T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10040609, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041702, dcDueDate: "2019-06-17T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041729, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041752, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10039411, dcDueDate: "2018-04-03T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041029, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041748, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041622, dcDueDate: "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041793, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041637, dcDueDate: "2019-11-11T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041744, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10040489, dcDueDate: "2019-07-29T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10040610, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-03-25T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 12, dcDueDate: "2019-04-15T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041656, dcDueDate: "2019-07-08T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041038, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 96927577, dcDueDate: "2019-06-24T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041708, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041730, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041709, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041796, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10038268, dcDueDate: "2020-03-09T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041710, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-06T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041663, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-10-21T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10040055, dcDueDate: "2018-07-08T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10040549, dcDueDate: "2019-05-13T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 16784298, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2018-12-03T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041636, dcDueDate: "2019-11-11T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041643, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041623, dcDueDate: "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041770, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-03-18T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10040354, dcDueDate: "2019-03-18T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041647, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041650, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-10-07T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041794, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041693, departmentId: "008", departmentName: "", status: { status: "Open", updatedAt: "2019-02-08T01:06:55.893957" }, supplierId: 426145, portId: null, eventCode: "P10W5F19", locality: "Local", destinationCountry: "NewZealand", internationalCommercialTerms: "IIS/FIW STR/DC(A TO NZ VIA FTC/XDO)", allocationStage: "StoreAllocation", dcDueDate: null, ffDueDate: null, ffBookedDate: null, transportMethod: null, isNewLine: false, createdBy: "BYP", createdAt: "2019-02-08T00:00:00.0000000", advertisedDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-04-22T00:00:00.0000000", notAfterDate: "2019-04-25T00:00:00.0000000", lineItems: [] }, { orderNumber: 10041749, departmentId: "008", departmentName: "", status: { status: "Open", updatedAt: "2019-02-15T04:57:43.953292" }, supplierId: 426145, portId: null, eventCode: "P12W2F19", locality: "Local", destinationCountry: "NewZealand", internationalCommercialTerms: "IIS/FIW STR/DC(A TO NZ VIA FTC/XDO)", allocationStage: "StoreAllocation", dcDueDate: null, ffDueDate: null, ffBookedDate: null, transportMethod: null, isNewLine: false, createdBy: "BYP", createdAt: "2019-02-15T00:00:00.0000000", advertisedDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000", notAfterDate: "2019-06-06T00:00:00.0000000", lineItems: [] }, { orderNumber: 10041762, dcDueDate: "2019-04-08T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041655, dcDueDate: "2019-07-08T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10039840, dcDueDate: "2018-07-09T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041750, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-06-03T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041773, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-03-18T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10040533, dcDueDate: "2019-05-13T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041740, departmentId: "008", dcDueDate: "2019-12-02T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041646, dcDueDate: "2019-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041645, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-12-02T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10040049, dcDueDate: "2018-07-01T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041732, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041696, dcDueDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041731, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10040075, dcDueDate: "2018-07-08T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041635, dcDueDate: "2019-04-08T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041627, dcDueDate: "2019-06-17T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }, { orderNumber: 10041771, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-03-18T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 10041641, dcDueDate: null, notBeforeDate: "2019-12-30T00:00:00.0000000" }, { orderNumber: 17022057, dcDueDate: "2019-04-15T00:00:00.0000000", notBeforeDate: null }];

data.sort((a, b) =>
    (b.dcDueDate || b.notBeforeDate).localeCompare(a.dcDueDate || a.notBeforeDate) ||
    b.orderNumber - a.orderNumber
)

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is delta mean in your answer

Comment: `b.orderNumber - a.orderNumber` is the difference between two numbers.

Comment: okay, but I wanted to know what does delta mean to sort function

Comment: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) needs a numerical value which reflects the order of the elements. if the values are numbers, you could return the difference between the given value and this delta reflects the actual order. for exampe, by given `3` and `7`, the delta is `-4` (for ascending sort) and this means the element `a` is smaller than element `b`, because the delta is smaller than zero. if the delta is zero, the numbers are equal and if greater, then `b < a`. for more information, please have a look to the link.