# How to sort array object by date and time using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have array with different kind of elements and for the sake of simplicity I took 2 kind of objects.

Array:

```
    Data = [{id: 1, TIming: {startDate: "2020-09-19",startTime: "12:00 PM"}, {id: 2, TIming: {startDate: "2020-09-22",startTime: "11:00 AM"}];
```

How can I sort this array by the date and time element in order from the date closest to the current date and time down. (time and date by Ascending order ). Could this be possible with sort function and keep in mind , I am using TypeSCript to do this and need help?#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you sort an array on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Following should do the trick:

```js
const sorted = Data.sort((a, b) => {
  const dt1 = Date.parse(`${a.TIming.startDate} ${a.TIming.startTime}`)
  const dt2 = Date.parse(`${b.TIming.startDate} ${b.TIming.startTime}`)

  return dt2 - dt1

})
```

Comment: thanks alot............... and what if todays date is 16 and time is 12pm but I dont want to display that time because its 4 pm already.