# Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got the following...

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({
  req: "getDocument",
  docu: pagedoc,
  name: 'name'
}, function(response){
  var efjs = response.reply;
});
```

which calls the following..

```
case "getBrowserForDocumentAttribute":
  alert("ZOMG HERE");
  sendResponse({
    reply: getBrowserForDocumentAttribute(request.docu,request.name)
  });
  break;
```

However, my code never reaches "ZOMG HERE" but rather throws the following error while running `chrome.extension.sendRequest`

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
 chromeHidden.JSON.stringify
 chrome.Port.postMessage
 chrome.initExtension.chrome.extension.sendRequest
 suggestQuery
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: You are trying to send an object that has circular references in it. What is `pagedoc`?

Comment: What do I mean with what? 1. What is the value of `pagedoc`? 2. Circular reference: `a = {}; a.b = a;`

Comment: try use node.js : [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)

Comment: i faced this problem and it was made by forgetting await in async function to get values of an function.

Answer (score 675, accepted):

It means that the object you pass in the request (I guess it is `pagedoc`) has a circular reference, something like:

```
var a = {};
a.b = a;
```

`JSON.stringify` cannot convert structures like this.

**N.B.**: This would be the case with DOM nodes, which have circular references, even if they are not attached to the DOM tree. Each node has an *`ownerDocument`* which refers to `document` in most cases. `document` has a reference to the DOM tree at least through `document.body` and `document.body.ownerDocument` refers back to `document` again, which is only *one* of multiple circular references in the DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks! This explains the issue I got. But how does the circular reference present in the DOM objects don't cause any issues? Would JSON stringify a `document` object?

Comment: @asgs: It *does* cause issues, at least in Chrome. Firefox seems to be a bit smarter about it, but I don't know exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Is it possible to "catch" this error and handle it?

Comment: @DougMolineux: Sure, you can use `try...catch` to catch this error.

Comment: @FelixKling Unfortunately I couldn't get that to work (might have been doing something wrong) I ended up using this: https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe

Comment: " DOM nodes"...oops, forgot a .value, thanks for this, I was looking in all the wrong spots

Comment: Magnific explanation ✅

Answer (score 189):

As per [the JSON docs at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#parameters), `JSON.stringify` has a second parameter `replacer` which can be used to filter/ignore children items while parsing the tree. However, perhaps you can avoid the circular references.

In Node.js we cannot. So we can do something like this:

```
function censor(censor) {
  var i = 0;
  
  return function(key, value) {
    if(i !== 0 && typeof(censor) === 'object' && typeof(value) == 'object' && censor == value) 
      return '[Circular]'; 
    
    if(i >= 29) // seems to be a harded maximum of 30 serialized objects?
      return '[Unknown]';
    
    ++i; // so we know we aren't using the original object anymore
    
    return value;  
  }
}

var b = {foo: {bar: null}};

b.foo.bar = b;

console.log("Censoring: ", b);

console.log("Result: ", JSON.stringify(b, censor(b)));
```

The result:

```
Censoring:  { foo: { bar: [Circular] } }
Result: {"foo":{"bar":"[Circular]"}}
```

Unfortunately there seems to be a maximum of 30 iterations before it automatically assumes it's circular. Otherwise, this should work. I even used `areEquivalent` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript), but `JSON.stringify` still throws the exception after 30 iterations. Still, it's good enough to get a decent representation of the object at a top level, if you really need it. Perhaps somebody can improve upon this though? In Node.js for an HTTP request object, I'm getting:

```
{
"limit": null,
"size": 0,
"chunks": [],
"writable": true,
"readable": false,
"_events": {
    "pipe": [null, null],
    "error": [null]
},
"before": [null],
"after": [],
"response": {
    "output": [],
    "outputEncodings": [],
    "writable": true,
    "_last": false,
    "chunkedEncoding": false,
    "shouldKeepAlive": true,
    "useChunkedEncodingByDefault": true,
    "_hasBody": true,
    "_trailer": "",
    "finished": false,
    "socket": {
        "_handle": {
            "writeQueueSize": 0,
            "socket": "[Unknown]",
            "onread": "[Unknown]"
        },
        "_pendingWriteReqs": "[Unknown]",
        "_flags": "[Unknown]",
        "_connectQueueSize": "[Unknown]",
        "destroyed": "[Unknown]",
        "bytesRead": "[Unknown]",
        "bytesWritten": "[Unknown]",
        "allowHalfOpen": "[Unknown]",
        "writable": "[Unknown]",
        "readable": "[Unknown]",
        "server": "[Unknown]",
        "ondrain": "[Unknown]",
        "_idleTimeout": "[Unknown]",
        "_idleNext": "[Unknown]",
        "_idlePrev": "[Unknown]",
        "_idleStart": "[Unknown]",
        "_events": "[Unknown]",
        "ondata": "[Unknown]",
        "onend": "[Unknown]",
        "_httpMessage": "[Unknown]"
    },
    "connection": "[Unknown]",
    "_events": "[Unknown]",
    "_headers": "[Unknown]",
    "_headerNames": "[Unknown]",
    "_pipeCount": "[Unknown]"
},
"headers": "[Unknown]",
"target": "[Unknown]",
"_pipeCount": "[Unknown]",
"method": "[Unknown]",
"url": "[Unknown]",
"query": "[Unknown]",
"ended": "[Unknown]"
}
```

I created a small Node.js module to do this here: https://github.com/ericmuyser/stringy Feel free to improve/contribute!

Comment: It's the first time I see a function being passed which returns a self-executing function which returns a regular function. I believe I understand why this was done, but I don't believe I would have found that solution myself, and I feel I could remember this _technique_ better if I could see other examples where this _setup_ is needed. That being said, could you point to any literature regarding this _setup/technique_ (for lack of a better word) or similar ones?

Comment: +1 to Shawn. Please remove that IEFE, it's absolutely useless and illegible.

Comment: thx for pointing out the censor arg! it allows debugging down circular issues. in my case i had a jquery array where i thougth to have a normal array. they both look similar in debug print mode. About the IEFE, I see them frequently used in places where there is absolutely no need for them and agree with Shawn and Bergi that this is just such case.

Comment: Still no solution to the 30 iteration limit?

Comment: @BrunoLM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this solution does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @BrunoLM: for 30 iterations limit, if you return `'[Unknown:' + typeof(value) + ']'` you will see how to fix the censor to properly treat functions and some other types.

Comment: This solution only seems to work for circular references at the object's *top level*. For anything more deeply nested, not. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731154/3779853) for a more generic version.

Comment: Though if you were actually using `node.js` you would use `util.inspect` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354289/912236

Answer (score 90):

One approach is to strip object and functions from main object. And stringify the simpler form

```
function simpleStringify (object){
    // stringify an object, avoiding circular structures
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/31557814
    var simpleObject = {};
    for (var prop in object ){
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            continue;
        }
        if (typeof(object[prop]) == 'object'){
            continue;
        }
        if (typeof(object[prop]) == 'function'){
            continue;
        }
        simpleObject[prop] = object[prop];
    }
    return JSON.stringify(simpleObject); // returns cleaned up JSON
};
```

if you are using node js use `inspect()`

```
import {inspect} from "util";
console.log(inspect(object));
```

Comment: Perfect answer for me. Maybe 'function' keyword missed?

Comment: Nice, thanks. Though, this leads to strip also unrelated object props available in the main object. If that's the case, the C.M.'s answer is a good alternative.

Comment: thank you mate, you just saved me hours and hours of searching with this. can't express it enough.

Comment: `inspect` works perfect, no more headache, thank you!

Comment: You seem to insist on the spelling `insepect` in your code, which looks like a typo. Do I miss something?

Comment: WARNING: The `util.inspect()` method returns a string representation of `object` that is
intended for debugging. The output of `util.inspect` may change at any time
and should not be depended upon programmatically.

Answer (score 53):

I normally use the circular-json npm package to solve this.

```
// Felix Kling's example
var a = {};
a.b = a;
// load circular-json module
var CircularJSON = require('circular-json');
console.log(CircularJSON.stringify(a));
//result
{"b":"~"}
```

Note: circular-json has been deprecated, I now use flatted (from the creator of CircularJSON):

```
// ESM
import {parse, stringify} from 'flatted/esm';

// CJS
const {parse, stringify} = require('flatted/cjs');

const a = [{}];
a[0].a = a;
a.push(a);

stringify(a); // [["1","0"],{"a":"0"}]
```

from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted

Comment: tnx!. the import syntax little bit changed. see here https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#readme

Comment: This package has been deprecated

Answer (score 30):

Based on zainengineer's answer... Another approach is to make a deep copy of the object and strip circular references and stringify the result.

```js
function cleanStringify(object) {
    if (object && typeof object === 'object') {
        object = copyWithoutCircularReferences([object], object);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(object);

    function copyWithoutCircularReferences(references, object) {
        var cleanObject = {};
        Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
            var value = object[key];
            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                if (references.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                    references.push(value);
                    cleanObject[key] = copyWithoutCircularReferences(references, value);
                    references.pop();
                } else {
                    cleanObject[key] = '###_Circular_###';
                }
            } else if (typeof value !== 'function') {
                cleanObject[key] = value;
            }
        });
        return cleanObject;
    }
}

// Example

var a = {
    name: "a"
};

var b = {
    name: "b"
};

b.a = a;
a.b = b;

console.log(cleanStringify(a));
console.log(cleanStringify(b));
```

Comment: This was the best way to solve it, thx

Comment: I wish this were the accepted answer. This is the one answer that actually allowed me to debug WHY I have a circular reference in a super-complex object structure. TYVM

Answer (score 8):

In my case I simply forgot to use async/await thing while building the route:

```
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find();
    res.send(products );
});
```

Comment: lol was my case too

Answer (score 6):

I resolve this problem on NodeJS like this:

```
var util = require('util');

// Our circular object
var obj = {foo: {bar: null}, a:{a:{a:{a:{a:{a:{a:{hi: 'Yo!'}}}}}}}};
obj.foo.bar = obj;

// Generate almost valid JS object definition code (typeof string)
var str = util.inspect(b, {depth: null});

// Fix code to the valid state (in this example it is not required, but my object was huge and complex, and I needed this for my case)
str = str
    .replace(/<Buffer[ \w\.]+>/ig, '"buffer"')
    .replace(/\[Function]/ig, 'function(){}')
    .replace(/\[Circular]/ig, '"Circular"')
    .replace(/\{ \[Function: ([\w]+)]/ig, '{ $1: function $1 () {},')
    .replace(/\[Function: ([\w]+)]/ig, 'function $1(){}')
    .replace(/(\w+): ([\w :]+GMT\+[\w \(\)]+),/ig, '$1: new Date("$2"),')
    .replace(/(\S+): ,/ig, '$1: null,');

// Create function to eval stringifyed code
var foo = new Function('return ' + str + ';');

// And have fun
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo(), null, 4));
```

Answer (score 5):

For my case I was getting that error when I was using `async` function on my server-side to fetch documents using mongoose. It turned out that the reason was I forgot to put `await` before calling `find({})` method. Adding that part fixed my issue.

Comment: friendly reminder: As of jQuery 1.8 the await/async  is deprecated - so dont use it.

Answer (score 5):

This works and tells you which properties are circular. It also allows for reconstructing the object with the references

```js
  JSON.stringifyWithCircularRefs = (function() {
    const refs = new Map();
    const parents = [];
    const path = ["this"];

    function clear() {
      refs.clear();
      parents.length = 0;
      path.length = 1;
    }

    function updateParents(key, value) {
      var idx = parents.length - 1;
      var prev = parents[idx];
      if (prev[key] === value || idx === 0) {
        path.push(key);
        parents.push(value);
      } else {
        while (idx-- >= 0) {
          prev = parents[idx];
          if (prev[key] === value) {
            idx += 2;
            parents.length = idx;
            path.length = idx;
            --idx;
            parents[idx] = value;
            path[idx] = key;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function checkCircular(key, value) {
      if (value != null) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
          if (key) { updateParents(key, value); }

          let other = refs.get(value);
          if (other) {
            return '[Circular Reference]' + other;
          } else {
            refs.set(value, path.join('.'));
          }
        }
      }
      return value;
    }

    return function stringifyWithCircularRefs(obj, space) {
      try {
        parents.push(obj);
        return JSON.stringify(obj, checkCircular, space);
      } finally {
        clear();
      }
    }
  })();
```

Example with a lot of the noise removed:

```
{
    "requestStartTime": "2020-05-22...",
    "ws": {
        "_events": {},
        "readyState": 2,
        "_closeTimer": {
            "_idleTimeout": 30000,
            "_idlePrev": {
                "_idleNext": "[Circular Reference]this.ws._closeTimer",
                "_idlePrev": "[Circular Reference]this.ws._closeTimer",
                "expiry": 33764,
                "id": -9007199254740987,
                "msecs": 30000,
                "priorityQueuePosition": 2
            },
            "_idleNext": "[Circular Reference]this.ws._closeTimer._idlePrev",
            "_idleStart": 3764,
            "_destroyed": false
        },
        "_closeCode": 1006,
        "_extensions": {},
        "_receiver": {
            "_binaryType": "nodebuffer",
            "_extensions": "[Circular Reference]this.ws._extensions",
        },
        "_sender": {
            "_extensions": "[Circular Reference]this.ws._extensions",
            "_socket": {
                "_tlsOptions": {
                    "pipe": false,
                    "secureContext": {
                        "context": {},
                        "singleUse": true
                    },
                },
                "ssl": {
                    "_parent": {
                        "reading": true
                    },
                    "_secureContext": "[Circular Reference]this.ws._sender._socket._tlsOptions.secureContext",
                    "reading": true
                }
            },
            "_firstFragment": true,
            "_compress": false,
            "_bufferedBytes": 0,
            "_deflating": false,
            "_queue": []
        },
        "_socket": "[Circular Reference]this.ws._sender._socket"
    }
}
```

To reconstruct call JSON.parse() then loop through the properties looking for the `[Circular Reference]` tag.  Then chop that off and... eval... it with `this` set to the root object.

Don't eval anything that can be hacked. Better practice would be to do `string.split('.')` then lookup the properties by name to set the reference.

Comment: Got `VM1226:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ancestorOrigins')` on stringifyin window on the web page I need.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I am using React Native, and tried to debug

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object))
```

and got the error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

It seems that I can get the object logged to the console by using just plain:

```
console.log(object)
```

Comment: this is the same problem im having. any solutions/ideas?

Comment: Try it both ways: console.log(object) and console.log(JSON.stringify(object)) if there is a difference. In my case there was.

Answer (score 3):

I got into a different issue here, I was taking values from html elements into an object array, in one field i was assigning values incorrectly which was causing this exception.
Incorrect expression: `obj.firstname=$("txFirstName")`
Correct expression: `obj.firstname=$("txFirstName").val()`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29957904)

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same error when trying to build the message below with jQuery. The circular reference happens when `reviewerName` was being mistakenly assigned to `msg.detail.reviewerName`. JQuery's .val() fixed the issue, see last line.

```
var reviewerName = $('reviewerName'); // <input type="text" id="taskName" />;
var msg = {"type":"A", "detail":{"managerReview":true} };
msg.detail.reviewerName = reviewerName; // Error
msg.detail.reviewerName = reviewerName.val(); // Fixed
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a **flush()** that was left over in the unit test after some code changes.

Before

```
it('something should be...', () => {
// do tests
flush();
}
```

After

```
it('something should be...', () => {
// do tests
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with jQuery formvaliadator, but when I removed a console.log inside success: function, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might have done something like this

```
<Button onClick={fetchSuggestions}>
```

failing to realize you have passed 'event object' to that function

if you don't wish to pass anything simply send an empty string

```
<Button onClick={() => fetchSuggestions()}>
```

```js
  const fetchSuggestions = async (propsSession) => {
    const {
      error,
      hasNextDoc,
      suggestions: moreSuggestions,
    } = await fetcher(`/admin/fetchSuggestion`, {
      initialRequest: !!propsSession,
      session: propsSession || session,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a jquery or HTML element in the data object as property "target" which contains a circular reference.  The property was not needed for the purposes of the data object being sent as JSON.

Removing it by deleting the property fixed the issue:

```
if(__dataObj.hasOwnProperty('target')){
    // remove target from data to avoid circular structure error
    delete __dataObj.target;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Node.js v10.22.1 (the version running on our GitLab CI server) has, what I consider to be, an erroneous circular reference detector.  The version running locally (v12.8.0) is smart enough to know it's not a true circular reference.

I'm adding this response in case someone else has the same issue and their object isn't actually a circular reference.

This was the original response object:

```
var res = {
    "status":"OK",
    "message":"Success",
    "errCode":":",
    "data":"",
    "appCfg":{
        "acp_age":"2yy",
        "acp_us":"yes",
        "mode":"admin",
        "version":"v1.21.07.1"
    },
    "reqID":59833,
    "email":{
        "status":"OK",
        "message":"Success"
    },
    "emailStatus":"sent"
}
```

It thought that `res.email.status` was the same as `res.status`.  It's just a text element, so not circular, but the name and value apparently tripped up the JSON.stringify parser.

I removed the `res.email` sub-object and everything is fine.  I was trying to collect independent statuses and detailed messages from all of the unique actions performed during the server call. I've switched it to the element `res.emailStatus` which is also included in the example above.

Answer (score -1):

As per MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#issue_with_json.stringify_when_serializing_circular_references

It is a circular json, which cannot be directly converted.

**Solution 1:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted

```
// ESM
import {parse, stringify, toJSON, fromJSON} from 'flatted';

// CJS
const {parse, stringify, toJSON, fromJSON} = require('flatted');

const a = [{}];
a[0].a = a;
a.push(a);

stringify(a); // [["1","0"],{"a":"0"}]
```

**Solution 2: (Also by MDN)**

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js