# Converting circular structure to JSON -- Any way to find what field it is complaining about?

Tags: json, google-chrome, circular-reference

I'm trying to stringify(...) an object in Chrome, and I keep getting a "Converting circular structure to JSON" message, despite the fact that (as far as I know) no such structure exists.

I've been over the code a dozen times and can't find any circular references whatsoever. Is there any way to get Chrome to tell me what it's bitching about beyond this painfully useless error message?

Comment: I posted an answer that may help if you get this error in Node.js where circular references cannot be avoided. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json/9653082#9653082

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Pardon me if this is too obvious.  At the time of writing, I dont know what you have tried.

insert

```
console.log(the object);
```

replacing 'the object' with the object you are passing to `JSON.stringify()`

insert this line before the `JSON.stringify` call

and look in the console log  (shift control J) for the object. In the console log the object will be tagged with a ">" symbol which can be clicked to expand to the fields.

It is complaining about an object that has pointers into itself, like this kind of object:

```
A = [];
A[0] = A; 
JSON.stringify(A); // circular error
```

Comment: I was having this problem and could not figure it out by typing in the console. I put `console.log(all)` right before my `JSON.stringify(all)` and I found that the `all` variable is actually used by Google Chrome! I guess my code would override it, but only after the page has loaded since `all` contains all HTML on the page! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: That sounds odd. I checked all in chrome and it is undef, as expected

Comment: Maybe it was a bug? It was happening consistently for me in Chrome 12.0.742.122 m on Windows XP. I changed my variable from `all` to `allData` and everything works fine now.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Sounds like a mystery on this end.

Comment: great answer, it helped me find the source element that was triggering the event.

Comment: This does not always fully unpack objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dojox.json.ref` to find circular references. This code prints json representation of your `objectWithCircularReferences`:

```
require(["dojox/json/ref"], function(){
    console.log(dojox.json.ref.toJson(objectWithCircularReferences));
});
```

Any occurence of "$ref" substring in its output to console will help you locate circular references. You can alternatively pipe this json output to global variable ZZZ like this if you wish:

```
require(["dojox/json/ref"], function(){
    window.ZZZ = dojox.json.ref.toJson(objectWithCircularReferences);
});
```

And of course you need to include dojo library beforehand. In an html file:

```
<script src="//yandex.st/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

In firebug console:

```
include("//yandex.st/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js")
```

In Chrome console:

```
SCRIPT = document.createElement('script');
SCRIPT.src = '//yandex.st/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js';
document.body.appendChild(SCRIPT);
```

Comment: what is ko.toJS in your code ? i tried dojox.json.ref.toJson( saveObj ) and i still get Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: @max4ever: `ko.toJS` went from [KnockOut.js library](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) that I used in my project. But here it's superfluous. I've cleaned the code. Thank you.