# How to store a DOM-Node?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage, store

i want to store for example a `<table>` (node of my DOM - build up with HTML5) using JS/JQuery. Why?

i like to renew the table but store the old table with the contained values in it. i think it would later be quick to replace an existing table (node) with an stored, than to build it up  again and parse the old data.

(parse data > build table ; rewnew table: parse new data > store old table > replace old by new; later: replace new by old table)

if found for example that problem: [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)
(i tried also to convert my table via JSON save it in given localStorage)

is it recommend to store such a DOM-node in a variable or localstorage?

I'm glad for any advice.

Comment: I don't think storing it in `localStorage` will work. Putting a DOM node in a variable is perfectly fine, though.

Comment: $tableDOM = $("#tableid");
alert($tableDOM);

Comment: i currently try to fiddl it with variables... hope it works. thx for first advice :-) to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your dom in variables.

```
var myTable = $('#content');
```

Local Storage api is not work on older browsers if you want to store your dom tree on the client side you can use cookies but I don't recomend it.

Comment: thx variables will work for me... but why u wont recomend to use cookies? :-)