# io.sockets.clients() gives error "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to pass the contents of io.sockets.clients() through to the client with the following code:

```
var room_users = io.sockets.clients(newroom);
socket.emit('update_room_users', room_users);
```

(newroom is a string var)

But I get the error:

> Converting circular structure to JSON

in the console.

I have no idea why this is happening as this should be the correct code according the the socket.io site?

Comment: But `room_users` is not a string, it's an object ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: Could you link to what code from the socket.io site you're using as a base? Do you simply mean that you're using their `emit` code, or do you mean they produce a result from `io.sockets.clients()` that doesn't have a circular reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert to JSON an object which contain a circular reference.
A circular reference is an object what containt itself.

Example of circular reference:

```
var a = {};
var b = {a:a};
a.b = b;
```

`room_users` certainly contain a circular reference because it contain the socket clients which refer the other clients which refer themselves...

---

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I thought "io.sockets.clients()" was just an object with client data in it? I understand the circular reference, but I cannot see how it apparent here... Stupid brain! But it seems that you cannot pass "io.sockets.clients()" at all through to the client (yes, because of the circular reference) but I just want to know why exactly?!

Comment: What you whant understand exactly ? Why you can't pass a circular reference or why `io.sockets.clients()` contain a circular reference ?

Comment: The later, then because of that, the former :)

Comment: More abstractly, passing the server side client object to a client doesn't make sense. It contain all client-server connection references of itself and other clients. This is not a realy good idea for the security. Why do you whant pass this object ?

Comment: To answer you question. In the Socket.IO API you can't send message to the other clients from a client object with the property `broadcast`. To do this, the client object need to has a reference on its associated server. And the server containt the reference of all clients. Current client too. And each clients containt reference  of the server. This is an infinit loop. ;-)

Comment: I am looking into finding out which other clients are in the same room as the user, so they only see a user list of those in the same room :)

Comment: Ok. I think the full client objet contain a lot of useless information... ^^ You need to construct a `room_users` object server side, with the specific data needed client side, and only transfert this object. It's better for the network. ;-) You can also create this object before, and maintain it on client's `connect` and `disconnect` to not have to build it each time.

Comment: Yea, I slowly figured that out after realising I can't pass this whole object :P Back to the drawing board!