# Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tablednd

I have a tableDnD drag and drop with JSON.stringify :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#Table").tableDnD({
        onDragClass: "danger",
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    'rows' : JSON.stringify(table.tBodies[0].rows)
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(reponse) {
                    if(reponse) {
                        //alert('Success');
                    } else {
                        alert('Erreur');
                    }
                }
            });             
        }
    });
});
```

I have this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

I have the problem only on Chrome.

Comment: You're trying to convert a nodeList / DOM elements to a JSON string

Comment: yes, it works on Firefox, but it gives problem in Chrome

Comment: If it works, it's a fluke, you can't convert nodelists to strings, or at least you shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, can you offer me another solution?

Comment: Why do you have to send the entire element to the server? Usually you'd extract a value or text from the element, not send the whole thing (which isn't really possible)

Comment: ok, I'll test and I want you know, thank you very much.

Comment: I solved the problem, I used the ID instead of nodeList. 
Thank you very much, you can close the ticket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Answer (score 28):

You should not convert a DOM element to JSON directly.

While - like you already experienced - it fails e.g. in Chrome, the results may also be unexpected.

The reason for this is because the data is circular:

A Node has the property `childNode` containing all its children and the property `parentNode` pointing to the parent.

The JSON format does not support references, so it will need to follow the properties until an end is reached, but because a child points to its parent which has a list of its children, this is an endless loop, that’s the reason why you get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Even if this is resolved by the browser you may have other problems.
Because not only `childNodes` exist but also `childElements`.  The same is for `parentNode`/`parentElement`, then you also have `nextSibling`, `prevSibling`, `firstChild`, `lastChild`, ... that would probably also be followed, so you would end up in the terrifying large JSON file containing a butch of duplicate data.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the .innerHtml property of the DOM element instead of converting the entire DOM element.
So you should be looking to have something like:

```
JSON.stringify(table.tBodies[0].innerHTML)
```