# Console log not outputting entire contents of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to pop `n` objects from an array. I'm getting differences between the total objects in the array vs the array `length`. Why is this?

If I console log:

`console.log('Deck length', this.deck, this.deck.length);`

I can see there are 37 Card objects, and the `length` is 18, yet `this.deck.length` outputs `37`.

[image]

This is important when I'm trying to pop all cards in the array:

```
var that = this;
this.deck.forEach(function (cards, index) {
    that.deck.pop();
    console.log('popping ', cards.name, index); 
});
```

I want to pop the entire 37 cards, yet it's only popping 18.

`console.log('Deck length after pop', this.deck, this.deck.length);`

[image]

---

EDIT:

tried with regular for loop and got same results:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.deck.length; i++) {
    var popped_card = this.deck.pop();
}
```

And

`console.log(JSON.stringify(this.deck))` gives error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234436/uncaught-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: What do you see when you run `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.deck))`?

Comment: Don't use the forEach if you are going to pop the items from the array.

Comment: @Will see above edit plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the problem that `this.deck.length` is evaluated in each loop iteration. And as soon as you are half through the array your length will already have been decreased far enough so that the loop condition (i < current length) is no longer true and the loop aborts.

What you can do:

- Store the length before mutation and use that
- Use `.clear()`
- Assign a new array to `deck`

Mutating lists while looping through them is generally error-prone (in most situations only save if you break from the loop after mutation).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ary = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
  ary.push(i);
}

console.log(ary);

for(var i = ary.length - 1; ary.length > 0; i--) {
  console.log(ary[i]);
  ary.pop();
}
```