# how to get Datatable data and check with new data to remove duplicate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on DataTable jquery plugin. i need to remove the duplicate value with check the comming value is alrady in the datatable and update the data dynamically in the datatable.

```
function checkDuplicate(newResource) {
    var resource = $('#list').DataTable();
    var oldResources = resource.rows().data();
    var stringArr = JSON.stringify(oldResources),
        result = newResource.filter(function (obj) {
            var stringObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
            if (stringArr.indexOf(stringObj) != -1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        });
        if(result.length != 0){
            resource.rows.add(result).draw(false);
        }
}
```

But there is a error

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

how to solve this problem.

Comment: What I would say is rather than comparing values one by one you can just reload/refresh the whole data table with new data

Comment: I am appending the data with old data, what are the new data are comming. i will append the data again and again dynamically.

Comment: JSON.stringify(table.tBodies[0].innerHTML);  See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234436/uncaught-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json