# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using request package for node.js

**Code :**

```
 var formData = ({first_name:firstname,last_name:lastname,user_name:username, email:email,password:password});

  request.post({url:'http://localhost:8081/register', JSON: formData}, function(err, connection, body) {

exports.Register = function(req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    console.log("Request data " +JSON.stringify(req));
```

Here I am getting this error :

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Can anybody tell me what is the problem

Comment: Check your data structure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Comment: I am not able to get from here. can u pls tell me what changes i need to made in above code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print a circular structure in a JSON-like format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

JSON doesn't accept circular objects - objects which reference themselves. `JSON.stringify()` will throw an error if it comes across one of these.

The request (`req`) object is circular by nature - Node does that.

In this case, because you just need to log it to the console, you can use the console's native stringifying and avoid using JSON:

```
console.log("Request data:");
console.log(req);
```

Comment: I want to extract a token present in req object, so is there a way to extract this or convert the req object to json without using the external library mentioned in the below answer.

Comment: @Rahulroy you should be able to just access the property you need from the req object

Comment: well i this is the req object that i have https://pastebin.com/i1yyaUaB and i am trying to access access_token field in session.keycloak-token. How can i access that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll need to JSON.parse() it

Comment: tried that, but that also comes up with new problem of its own. given data loss.

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question about your issue

Comment: Thanks, saved my time. Just forgot await while using Mongoose in Node.js

Answer (score 105):

I also ran into this issue. It was because I forgot to await for a promise.

Answer (score 16):

I was able to get the values using this method, found at [careerkarma.com](https://careerkarma.com/blog/converting-circular-structure-to-json/)

Output looks like this.
[image: Preview of the output]

I just run this code in the debugger console. Pass your object to this function.
Copy paste the function also.

```
 const replacerFunc = () => {
    const visited = new WeakSet();
    return (key, value) => {
      if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
        if (visited.has(value)) {
          return;
        }
        visited.add(value);
      }
      return value;
    };
  };
  
  JSON.stringify(circObj, replacerFunc());
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using this npm package. This helped me decoding the res structure from my node while using `passport-azure-ad` for integrating login using Microsoft account

https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-json

You can stringify your circular structure by doing:

```
const str = CircularJSON.stringify(obj);
```

then you can convert it onto JSON using JSON parser

```
JSON.parse(str)
```

Comment: CircularJSON has now been deprecated

Comment: As their page says, I guess we can use https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted flatted from now

Answer (score 7):

I forgotten to use **await** keyword in async function.
with the given systax

```
blogRouter.put('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  const updatedBlog = Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(
    request.params.id,
    request.body,
    { new: true }
  );
  response.status(201).json(updatedBlog);
});
```

Blog.findByIdAndUpdate should be used with the **await** keyword.

Answer (score 6):

use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-safe

```
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');
var circularObj = {};
circularObj.circularRef = circularObj;
circularObj.list = [ circularObj, circularObj ];
console.log(stringify(circularObj, null, 2));


stringify(obj, serializer, indent, decycler)
```

Comment: how do I parse this?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you don't an async response For example:

```
app.get(`${api}/users`, async (req, res) => {
    const users = await User.find()
    res.send(users);
   })
```

Comment: It seems like it is the JSON.stringify call that is the problem and so the console.log line

Comment: Please edit to supply the missing word in your explanatory sentence.

Comment: I was also facing a similar issue, because of not using await before calling response.send()

Answer (score 4):

If you are sending reponse , Just use `await` before response

```js
await res.json({data: req.data});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because **JavaScript structures that include circular references can't be serialized with a"plain" JSON.stringify**.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-json mentioned by @Dinesh is a good solution. But this npm package has been deprecated.

So use https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted npm package directly from the creator of CircularJSON.

Simple usage. In your case, code as follows

import package

```
// ESM
import {parse, stringify} from 'flatted';

// CJS
const {parse, stringify} = require('flatted');
```

and

```
console.log("Request data " + stringify(req));
```

Comment: This gives me a return value totally different from the original object?

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the same error, in my case it was just because of not using `await` with `Users.findById()` which returns promise, so `response.status().send()/response.send()` was getting called before **promise** is **settled** (**fulfilled** or **rejected**)

### Code Snippet

```js
app.get(`${ROUTES.USERS}/:id`, async (request, response) => {
    const _id = request.params.id;
    try {
        // was getting error when not used await
        const user = await User.findById(_id);
        if (!user) {
            response.status(HTTP_STATUS_CODES.NOT_FOUND).send('no user found');
        } else {
            response.send(user);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        response
            .status(HTTP_STATUS_CODES.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .send('Something went wrong, try again after some time.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Same, even I faced this issue.

Comment: Excellent. This was the best answer for me. I was also not using await in the call!

Answer (score 2):

Came across this issue in my Node Api call when I missed to use `await` keyword  in a `async` method in front of call returning Promise. I solved it by adding `await` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when not using async/await on a asynchronous function (api call). Hence adding them / using the promise handlers properly cleared the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error message "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" typically occurs when you try to stringify an object that contains circular references using JSON.stringify().

A circular reference occurs when an object references itself in some way. For example, consider the following code:

```
const obj = { foo: {} };
obj.foo.obj = obj;
```

In this example, obj contains a circular reference because the foo property of obj contains a reference to obj itself.

When you try to stringify an object like this using JSON.stringify(), it will fail with the error message "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".

To solve this issue, you can use a third-party library like flatted or circular-json, which are specifically designed to handle circular references in JavaScript objects. Here's an example using flatted:

```
const flatted = require('flatted');

const obj = { foo: {} };
obj.foo.obj = obj;

const str = flatted.stringify(obj);
console.log(str);
```

In this example, we use flatted.stringify() instead of JSON.stringify(), and it successfully converts the object to a string without throwing an error.

Alternatively, you can modify your object to remove the circular reference before trying to stringify it. For example:

```
const obj = { foo: {} };
obj.foo.bar = 'baz';

// add circular reference
obj.foo.obj = obj;

// remove circular reference
obj.foo.obj = undefined;

const str = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(str);
```

In this example, we add the circular reference and then remove it before trying to stringify the object. This approach works well if you don't need to preserve the circular reference in the stringified object.

Answer (score 0):

```
          AxiosService({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/products',
            data: {
                name: productNumber,
                number: productNumber,
                description: productDescription,
                type: category,
                price: 0,
            },
        })
```

In my case I made mistake in the payload data when making request. By mistake I was setting description as e.target instead of e.target.value when taking input.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

If an object has a different type of property like mentioned in the above image, JSON.stringify() will through an error.

Comment: This question is asked more than 8 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer

Answer (score -2):

Edit May 22, 2023

I think it is an error which need to be fixed not a feature which is needed.
I have faced this issue and tried following things. Hope it helps.

1. The reference does not have resolved value till the time, we are going to use it. In this case, I have awaited the response, by adding **await** keyword and checking whether I am returning proper value from the function.
2. In the second case when I faced this issue I had a json like,

   {
   obj1: "sample1",
   obj2: "sample2",
   obj3: obj3
   }

or,

```
{
 obj1: "sample1",
 obj2: obj1
}
```

in this case, **the value of any of the key in object is again depended on some other key, which was growing the json object recursively**. Here, I fixed this dependency of one key on another to resolve it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31627819)

Answer (score -2):

**For mongodb**

so if you are getting errors while fetching data from MongoDB **then the problem is async**

**previously**
[image]

```
app.get('/users',(req,res,next)=>{
 
 const user=chatUser.find({});
 
 if(!user){
 
 res.status(404).send({message:"there are no users"});
 
 
 }
 
 if(user){
 
 res.json(user);
 
 }
})
```

**After**

```
app.get('/users',async(req,res,next)=>{
 
 const user=await chatUser.find({});
 
 if(!user){
 
 res.status(404).send({message:"there are no users"});
 
 
 }
 
 if(user){
 
 res.json(user);
 
 }
 
})
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this as well

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)));
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` - What the point in this code snippet?!

Comment: I am afraid this might be a plausible workaround.

Answer (score -8):

`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in nodejs:`
This error can be seen on Arangodb when using it with Node.js, because storage is missing in your database. If the archive is created under your database, check in the Aurangobi web interface.