# Call api by axios and show data

Tags: typescript

I try to get json data from *https://api.bitkub.com/api/market/ticker* and show it.
but it look like it have problem when I try to show data.
I'm not sure what is the problem. Please check my code and error below.

index.ts file

```
import myApi from './myApi'

app.get('/myApi', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await myApi()
  res.send(result)
})
```

myApi.ts

```
     import axios from 'axios'

     interface myInterface{
          id: number
          last: number
          lowestAsk: number
          highestBid: number
          percentChange: number
          baseVolume: number
          quoteVolume: number
          isFrozen: number
          high24hr: number
          low24hr: number
          change: number
          prevClose: number
          prevOpen: number
        }
        
        const myApi = async () => {
          const resultAPI = await axios.get<myInterface[]>(
            'https://api.bitkub.com/api/market/ticker'
          )
          return resultAPI
        }

        export default myApi
```

But get error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101240/typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json-in-nodejs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101240/typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
res.send(result)
```

to

```
 res.send(result.data)
```