# What is difference between these two functions

Tags: javascript, json

Anybody Please explain what is difference between two codes. i am trying to print **JSON String**.

**1)**  `console.log("Hello "+str);`

**2)**

```
console.log("Hello");
console.log(str);
```

and this is working

this code is giving error  **console.log("Hello "+str);**   **Converting circular structure to JSON**

Why it is happening.   Can anybody explain me what is difference in both code.

**EDIT:** this is my code

```
firstname="hello"; 
lastname= "hhf";
username= "dffflffl";
email="email@hitemai.com
password= "dddd";

var opts = { 
url: 'localhost:8081/register', 
method: 'POST', 
body: JSON.stringify({first_name:firstname,last_name:lastname, user_name:username,email:email,password:password}), 

};
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your str object?

Comment: circular structure is something like this  --  var a = {}; a.b = a;  --  JSON.stringify won't work in these cases

Answer (score 1):

JSON cannot handle self-referential objects (cyclic object graphs), so such a thing cannot be printed by the console.

```
> var str = { x : 1}; str.x = str;
> JSON.stringify(str);

TypeError: cyclic object value
```

Answer (score 0):

If `str` is supposed to be a JSON string produced by `JSON.stringify`, then you would get that error if the object you're converting to JSON has a reference to itself or child objects with circular references.

See: [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json).