# Scraping table data using cheerio nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, cheerio

i'm new to cheerio and want to scrape all team names in a particular table and return the data as json for instance like

```
{
    name: "Manchester City"
}
```

so far i've created below which is suppose to be an api returning the data, however i cant seem to access any particular elements? i keep getting following response `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

**Code**

```
app.get('/api/standings', function(req, res, next){

    var base = "http://www.skysports.com/football/competitions/premier-league/tables";
    var age = 2015;

    request.get(`${base}`, function(err, response, body) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            //get standings
            var classes = $('standing-table__table tbody tr').each(function()   {

                var d = $(this);
                var td = d.children('td.standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name');
                return td.eq(0).text();
            });

            res.json(classes);

    });

});
```

Comment: Did you look up the error you are getting? This type of issue has been addressed a ton of times on stackoverflow already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: @forgiveson how is that even related.

Comment: The error is telling you that your data has a circular reference. To convert it to JSON, you need to break that circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using the incorrect cheerio function. You need `.map` not `.each`. `Each` just iterates without returning anything useful based on the code in the iterator function, whereas `map` collects everything returned by the iterator function into an array. So switch to `.map` and you should end up with an array of strings (assuming your selectors and HTML parsing is otherwise correct). You'll have `["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"]`.

Then you need to convert that to your desired format which is an array of objects so you need another call to `.map` here.

```
res.json(classes.map(function (name) {return {name: name}}));
```