# Not able to stringify an object, showing "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, cookies, local-storage

There is an object that I want to keep even if user press ctrl+F5. So I am trying it to save in the localstorage of browser.
As localstorage can save only string data so I am strngify it

```
localStorage["objSocket"] = JSON.stringyfy(socket);
```

but this is showing

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.
```

I tried even

```
$cookies.putObject("objSocket",socket);
```

this too is showing the same error.

Is there any other way to save the object even if user press ctrl+f5 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/1398867)