# Saving Express request object to a file

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I'm trying to pipe Express request object to a writable stream. NodeJS creates a file, but it's empty. What am I missing?

```js
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
    app.use(middleWare);
    app.listen(3000);

function middleWare(req, res, next){
    var ws = fs.createWriteStream('./test.txt');
    req.pipe(ws);
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

When I replace **req.pipe(ws)** with **ws.write(req)** I get an error:

```
 TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
```

When I replace **ws.write(req)** with **ws.write(JSON.stringify(req))** I get an error:

```
  TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Comment: This is a very unusual thing to do, `req` object is not generally meant to be written to a file. What are you actually trying to do by this?

Comment: @laggingreflex, I want to have a closer look at the request object structure. I can't do this in console, because the output exceeds the maximum and I can't scroll to the very top.

Comment: [console.dir or util.inspect can show greater depths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-js-console-log-rather-than-object/27534731#27534731) but [node debugger with chrome inspector might be more helpful](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/debugging-nodejs-in-chrome-devtools).

Comment: @laggingreflex, Thank you! I ended up using console.dir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only write a string or buffer to a file.

When you try to convert the object to a string with JSON.stringify(), you get an error because the object contains circular references, which is not allowed, and the reason why you cannot use this function.

You could try to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) the object to JSON, before converting it to a string.

But you could also try to extract only the relevant fields of the request and save them to the file, after converting them to a string.

Comment: Thank you! I've used an NPM module [CircularJSON](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json) for conversion. Everything works just fine!