# Appcelerator - Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, appcelerator, titanium-android

I have a problem with converting a JSON in string. On iOS all works perfect but on Android I have this error:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [2,20592] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

This is my code:

```
var args = $.args

var data = args.data;
var oferta = data.oferta;
var params = data.params;
var parent = args.parent;

//INSERT
var producto = Alloy.createModel('Producto', {
  oferta_id: parseInt(oferta.id),
  data: JSON.stringify(args) //ERROR
});
```

The args passed to the controller are like this:

```
var args = {
   data: 
   { 
      oferta: {id: 5}, 
      params:{id_opcion_precio: 3445}
   },
   parent: {}
}
```

What's wrong?? Why on iOS works fine???

Comment: Why do you need JSON.stringify? Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Comment: Because I want to keep this JSON in a text field on a db table

Comment: I saw the answer above before and is not my case, I think. I can't see a circular structure like in the answer

Comment: The strange thing is that on iOS works perfectly, if args is an circular structure it should be on iOS too.

Comment: Ok, I don't use modules, only database. Try to do a more direct approach when you pass the arguments, instead of create variables to one specific id or value. That code after 'The args passed to the controller are like this:' it's inside the model right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to stringify `args`. Try to use `JSON.stringify(args.data)` when you create the model.

I guess you would have the same problem just stringify'ing `args` in a log statement like: `console.log(JSON.stringify(args))`?

I have run into similar problems when trying to write the entire event (e.g. from ti.map) to the console. Something makes it break - I assume there is added some attributes to the data that you don't see.

Comment: Finally I solved my problem doing this:
´JSON.stringify({data: data, parent: parent})´
This works I don't know why, but works

Comment: Ok, so similar experience to what I have come across with events. Must be something added that we can't see ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem doing this:

```
JSON.stringify({data: data, parent: parent});
```

This works I don't know why, but works