# JS/NodeJS/VSCode - How to step into a console logged object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Novice programmer here.

When I run my Node projects on visual studio code's terminal, it gives me arrays of `[Object object]`, that I can't look into. Whereas in Chrome's console, it lets you step into the object and it's children's children etc.
That is very convenient for prototyping and debugging.

Is there a way I could do that for my NodeJS projects?

Comment: you can JSON.stringify() it

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768567/how-to-print-object-in-node-js