# Select content from class, then send with help of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I write my code using ASP.NET MVC(Razor) and JS. I have a spreadsheet, from which I must get all content from class .

`jtable-column-header`, and then send it to `"/Template/DataGridSave/@ViewBag.TemplateGuid/@Model.Name"` controller with help of ajax.

I try to do this in that way:

```
function createSaveDialog_@(Model.Name)()
          {
            // Creating diallog form
            $( "#dialog_@Model.Name" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                minHeight: 400,
                closeText: "Close",
                modal: true,
                buttons: [{
                    // Button, that must send content of "th.jtable-column-header" 
                    text: 'Save',
                    "class":'btn btn-primary pull-left',
                    click: function() {
                        var abc = $('th.jtable-column-header');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Template/DataGridSave/@ViewBag.TemplateGuid/@Model.Name",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: abc,
                       });

                   }},
                    {
                        text: 'Close',
                        "class":'btn btn-primary pull-right',
                        click: function() {
                            $('#DataGridView_@Model.Name').data({RecordEdit:null});
                            $( this ).dialog( "destroy" );
                        }
                    }]
            });
        }
```

I call this function on form, but works only button "Close". When I press "Save" nothing happens. 
What's wrong?

Comment: consult your console

Comment: When I try to press Save I get that error at console:
'80EBAB437EED4301809B252CC2A4B73C:478 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON'

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4816258/4613398