# console.log(result) prints [object Object]. How do I get result.name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

My script is printing `[object Object]` as a result of `console.log(result)`.

Can someone please explain how to have `console.log` print the `id` and `name` from `result`?

```
$.ajaxSetup({ traditional: true });

var uri = "";

$("#enginesOuputWaiter").show();    
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: uri,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    ContentType:'application/javascript',
    data :{'text' : article},
    error: function(result) {
        $("#enginesOuputWaiter").hide();
        if(result.statusText === 'success') {
            console.log("ok");
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            $("#enginesOuput").text('Invalid query.');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try parsing it? `[object Object]` is just a string representation, not what the object actually looks like.

Comment: That webservice seems to return JSON not JSONP, so you should change your `dataType`. That's probably also why your **`error`** handler is invoked, where you hardly will get a successful `result`.

Comment: You've BOM symbol in Your response: http://joxi.ru/vAWVVbh1k34N2W so fix Your php code, cleanup unnecessary utf8 encoding BOMs

Comment: `result.statusText = 'success'` should be `result.statusText === 'success'`. Otherwise you are assigning 'success' to the result object.

Comment: could You explain the necessarity of this in `get` request: `data :{'text' : article}`  ?

Comment: use console.dir() instead of console.log()

Comment: Try ````console.log("result: ", result);````

Comment: @SuperStormer Why are you fixing the code? OP is trying to test for success in the error callback and the wrong operator is making it seem like the request succeeded.

Comment: @gre_gor because it's irrelevant to the actual question and answers

Comment: I cast a reopen vote because the question is about how to print a JS object, completely unrelated to the dupe target.

Comment: @mtotowamkwe hi, Thank you very much for the answer.
Can you please extend your answer with more explanation about the reason it works?

Comment: @barper Mozilla documentation says if you log objects use console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))); instead of console.log(obj); I believe it works because the console.log() API passes the object you provide to a Formatter function which parses the object keys and object values and prints them to the console. See:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log I think there should be information in the JavaScript spec. If I dig anything up I'll update this comment accordingly. Note the result returned is specified as "implementation-defined".

Comment: This should absolutely be reopened.  The answer may be the same as the one marked duplicate but the question is entirely different.  A user (like the OP) might not be working with an asychronous call at all and still have this very same problem.  I see @SuperStormer has made a similar comment above.

Comment: The answer isn't even the same...

Answer (score 295):

Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` to get the JSON in a string format.

EDIT: If your intention is to get the id and other properties from the result object and you want to see it console to know if its there then you can check with `hasOwnProperty` and access the property if it does exist:

```
var obj = {id : "007", name : "James Bond"};
console.log(obj);                    // Object { id: "007", name: "James Bond" }
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));    //{"id":"007","name":"James Bond"}
if (obj.hasOwnProperty("id")){
    console.log(obj.id);             //007
}
```

Comment: You can also get json style log in this manor 
'console.log('connection : %j', myObject);'

Comment: Hi, I thought Im trying to do the same thing but I kept get getting `ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` . Is this because Im applying this method not on an object?

Comment: @GelSisaed That will happen if any of the property of your variable is a reference to that variable. refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773821/1304575) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816258/1304575)

Comment: Yup stringifying gave me  `"[object Object]"` like it's mocking me.

Comment: You can also use `console.debug(obj)` or console.dir(obj) to get the result in nodejs

Answer (score 70):

Try adding `JSON.stringify(result)` to convert the JS Object into a JSON string.

From your code I can see you are logging the result in `error` which is called if the [AJAX request fails](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), so I'm not sure how you'd go about accessing the id/name/etc. then (you are checking for success inside the error condition!).

Note that if you use Chrome's console you should be able to browse through the object without having to stringify the JSON, which makes it easier to debug.

Comment: Where is the petition to make this standard practice. [object Object] is the most useless log statement

Comment: You can also use `console.debug(obj)` or `console.dir(obj)` to get the result in nodejs

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
console.dir(object)
```

This is the way to see all the properties of a specified JavaScript object in console.

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` accepts a variadic arguments. Upon using the method with multiple arguments the value is printed to its expected readable format.

here's an example of `console.log` accepting multiple arguments:

```
console.log("result:", result);
```

which you can also do:

```
console.log("result:", result, "id:", result.id, "name:", result.name);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log

Comment: result will still be [object object]