# getQueryResult returns '[object Object]' instead of a valid json [hyperledger fabric]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, ecmascript-6

Contract Code:

```
async function queryCar(ctx, query) {

        let queryResult = await.ctx.stub.getQueryResult(query);
        console.log(queryResult.toString());

        return queryResult.toString();
        }
```

How I am invoking the function in my API:

```
 var stringQuery = `{"selector": {"id": "17"}}`
    newQuery = await contract.evaluateTransaction('richQuery',stringQuery);
    console.log(JSON.parse(newQuery));
```

Isn't the value of `stringQuery` a valid query to `CouchDB`?

**Maybe I am using the function wrong because the documentation speaks about the function returning a StateQueryIterator. Can anyone help me out on how to use the `getQueryResult` function in javascript? Thanks!**

Comment: What does result of `console.log(queryResult.toString())`? Guess `queryResult ` is probably an object and `queryResult.toString()` is returning `[object, Object]` . Just try returning `queryResult` from `queryCar` and assign it to `newQuery` without `JSON.parse`

Comment: return JSON.stringify(queryResult); Should do the trick. If you need to work with the object, convert the string back to JSON with JSON.parse(objectString)

Comment: @adiga getting a transaction error : `Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: @Spangle Same error, `Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: Am I using the function right? Or is my query to the db right?

Comment: Think of a circular structure to look something like  a = b  b = a  a = b etc..  Have a read of the accepted answer on the following page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773720/how-to-solve-uncaught-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved now! The issue was with me not knowing how to iterate over the keys it returns properly. Its return type is StateQueryIterator, and I was not using it right. Fixed that, and I got the result.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet that you used to fix the issue? I am encountering the same error and stuck.

Comment: @KarthikSridharan Here's the code snippet I followed to understand a 'StateQueryIterator' return type:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/fabcar/javascript/lib/fabcar.js

the body of the function 'queryAllCars' contains an example of how to iterate it. That's an example of a 'StateQueryIterator'

Answer (score 2):

It's because `queryResult` is an object, and `Object.toString()` returns `[object Object]`. Use `JSON.stringify` to convert the object to a string, then `JSON.parse` it to get the object back:

```
return JSON.stringify(queryResult);
```

And:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(newQuery));
```

Comment: I get a Transaction Error saying :  `Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: That's a problem with the technologies you're using.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this function, and I think that's giving me the issue. Maybe its not fetching any result from the query to the db. I'd appreciate some suggestions on how to use the functions, if you're aware about it. Thanks! @Jack Bashford