# how to display the entire object in console in react native

Tags: javascript, object, react-native

I recently started doing react native and don't understand as how to debug so as to get my results in console .
Here is the result I get in console .

```
Organizations is [object Object]
```

How do i get all the content of organizations .
I did this in my code for console .

```
console.log('Organizations is '+organizations);
```

Comment: did you tried `console.log(organizations);`? or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336663/console-logresult-returns-object-object-how-do-i-get-result-name

Comment: Isn't that same ?

Comment: @satyajeetjha: No it isn't, do have a look at my answer for the explaination

Answer (score 75):

You can [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(organizations));
```

if you want some formatting

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(organizations, null, 2));
```

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer; the pretty-printing (second code block) is exactly what I was looking for when having the same issue. +1

Answer (score 10):

Here are all methods to print an object without going mad. [Print object in JavaScript](https://code-maven.com/logging-javascript-objects)

```
console.log('Organisations is : ' + JSON.stringify(organisations));
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Comment: added essentials info related to answer.

Answer (score 8):

In ***ES6 syntaxe*** you can do something like this :

```js
console.log(`Organisations is : ${JSON.stringify(organisations)}`);
```

Answer (score 7):

Most consoles look at the argument they're passed and show an intelligent rendering of it, so you may want to provide `organizations` directly rather than concatenating it with a string (which will invoke the object's default `toString` behavior, which is `"[object Object]"` if you haven't done something special). Most also support multiple arguments, so you can do

```
console.log("Organizations is", organizations);
```

...to see both your label and the intelligent rendering.

See also [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection) about console rendering, though.

Comment: this is the best answer in that it doesn't require an additional dependency (e.g. `JSON`)

Comment: This is by far the best answer. It's simple to implement and actually auto formats the data and presents it in a logical, sensical way that clearly demonstrates the structure of the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to log with a string the console tries to convert your object to a string definition automatically.

So either you log the string separately:

```
console.log('Organizations is');
console.log(organizations);
```

Or you need to convert your object to a readable format first e.g. JSON:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(organizations));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let organizations = {name: 'McD'}

console.log(organizations)//Without type coercion
console.log('organizations is '+organizations);//Forcefully to convert object to become a string
```

The problem with `console.log('Organizations is '+organizations);` is due to type coercion. You are combining/concatenating a string ('Organizations is ') with an object(organizations) which forcing to convert an object into a string.

Answer (score -4):

use below code to print object in react-native

```
<View> {(()=>{ console.log(object) })()} </View>
```