# How to get certificate/token in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, promise, callback, certificate

My main goal is get and importe certificate on a Chromebook.
I can't get the token for get the certificate, I try to use chrome.enterprise.platformKeys.getTokens the docs :
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_platformKeys#method-getCertificates
Firstly, I would like to get the token I try :

```
function getUserToken(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.enterprise.platformKeys.getTokens(function (token){
            if (token) {
                resolve(token)
            }else{
                reject('Can\'t get token')
            }
        })
    })
}

const userToken = await getUserToken()
console.log('UserToken:', userToken)
```

my log return an empty string '{}'

Comment: Why not [Stringify the JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336663/console-logresult-returns-object-object-how-do-i-get-result-name)?