# How to use promises with data from an external API in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]I'm fetching data from an external api. This data is currency pair e.g EURUSD with real time Ask and Bid Prices respectively e.g 1.17123 , 1.17150. The user of the application is therefore required to input a future price such that if the Ask or the Bid price reaches that price inputted by the user, a message is logged. I have tried using a promise but its outputting the price that the user has put inside the textinput immediately i run the app instead of checking if the price has reached the future price that the user is expecting to be alerted if it is reached.
Below is my code:

```
//hook for the clicked currency pair

const [pricealert, setPricealert]  = useState(0)

function checkAlertCondition (){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(pricealert >= {...data.prices.AskPrice})
    {
      resolve({
        Pair: {...data.prices.instrument},
        message: "Price" + pricealert + "Has been hit"
      });
    } else if (pricealert <= {...data.prices.BidPrice}) {
      resolve({
        Pair:{...data.prices.instrument},
        message: "Price" + pricealert + "has been hit"
      });
    } else {
      reject ("Create Alert")
    }
  });
}

checkAlertCondition()
.then((message) => {
  console.log(message)
  .then((message) => {
    console.log(message)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log(err)
  })
})
      

 <Modal visible={modalopen} animationType={"fade"}>
   <View style={styles.modal}>
     <View>
       <Text style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold"}}>
         {data.prices[clickedindex].instrument}
       </Text>
       <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
         {data.prices.AskPrice}/{data.prices.BidPrice}
       </Text>
       <Card.Divider/>
       <View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
         <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
           <TextInput
             style={styles.textInputStyle}
             value={pricealert}
             onChangeText = {(pricealert) => setPricealert(pricealert)}
             placeholder="Alert Price"
             placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
             numeric
             keyboardType='decimal-pad' 
           />
           </View>
         </View>   
         <TouchableOpacity
           style={styles.button}
           onPress={() => {
             if(pricealert.length < 7) {
               Alert.alert("Error", "Enter a valid price")
               return;
             } else if (pricealert.length > 7) {
               Alert.alert("Error", "Enter a valid price")
               return;
             }
             setModalOpen(false);checkAlertCondition()} }
           >
             <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>OK</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
       </View>
     </Modal>
```

[image: creaecre]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example ? I don't get what you want to achieve

Comment: There's too much code here to review the piece you're actually trying to focus on, and it's also missing a bunch of code apparently. I feel like you want us to focus on this `checkAlertCondition` function, but it's not clear at all where the `pricealert` variable comes from

Comment: provided minimal code

Comment: @user23424 Don't you want to call the `checkAlertCondition.then(....` inside the `onPress` function ?
I don't understand why it is outside

Comment: I have tried it. it logs `[object Object]undefined`

Comment: That means it probably works (I mean the promise is either resolved or rejected), the `undefined` stuff is because of the chained `.then`, i don't think you need it. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336663/console-logresult-returns-object-object-how-do-i-get-result-name#answer-41336822), try to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(message));`

Comment: Its now correctly showing the message. The remaining task is to ensure the `pricealert` meets both of the conditions in the if statement for the message to be logged. It was actually my main issue

Comment: @user23424 - This is out of the scope of this question, you can post an other one for a different topic :)

Comment: Ok. Let me do that

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to consume the promise inside the `onPress` function, like this:

```
       <TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.button}
         onPress={
           () => {
             if(pricealert.length < 7) {
               Alert.alert("Error", "Enter a valid price")
               return;
             } else if (pricealert.length > 7) {
               Alert.alert("Error", "Enter a valid price")
               return;
             }
             setModalOpen(false);
             checkAlertCondition().then((message) => {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
             })
             .catch(() => {
               console.log(err)
             });
           }
         }
       >
```