# I can't get number of followers of the followers of a specific user using Twitter API V2

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, twitter

I'm having a hard time getting the number of followers of the followers of a specific user ID.

What I've seen from the docs, the only way you can get it is that you use the "user.fields" parameter and then access "public_metrics.followers_count".

But I'm struggling to access the "public_metrics" object, it just returns [Object] like this. I couldn't figure out how to access "followers_count" from the "public_metrics" object.

These are from the docs:

[image]

[image]

This is what returns in terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is standard JavaScript behaviour.

Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` or `console.debug(result)`

See also this answer for the general question.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336663/console-logresult-returns-object-object-how-do-i-get-result-name)