# TypeError converting circular structure to json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ngStorage']);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope','$localStorage', function($scope, $localStorage){
 var comment = [
  { name : '',
   rating : ''
  }
 ]
 $scope.saveData = function (review) {
  comment.push(comment);
  localStorage.setItem("review", JSON.stringify(comment));
  console.log("dkfjhdjhgjh",review); 
 };
 
}])
```

When I am Inserting through Input Box I am getting TypeError.

Comment: Where is the input box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the comment in... the comment!

```
comment.push(comment);
```

This creates a circular reference.
Maybe you want to do:
`comments.push(comment)` ?