# Convert CSV-stream to UTF-8 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, utf-8, ftp

In advance I have to say I'm new to **node.js** and may did not understand it fully yet.

I'm stuck at the moment with a rather obvious problem that I can't solve. I am importing a CSV file from a FTP server via the node module "[ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp)"
then I'm receiving the file as a stream which I then convert to a JSON with the node module "[csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson)".

So far that works wonderfully. But now I noticed that I stumbled over some **Umlaut** chars from the German language which keep crashing my solution. I found out that I have to convert the file stream to UTF8, but I have no idea how.

I tried it already with the `toString()` method and several other node modules but that also didn't work.

My code looks like this:

```
getCsvFromFtp: function (profile) {
    init(profile);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.on('ready', function () {
            client.get(file, function (err, stream) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                stream.once('close', () => {
                    client.end();
                });
                csv({
                    trim: true,
                    delimiter: delimiter,
                }).fromStream(stream, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(csvFormatterService.groupAndFormatOrders(result));
                });
            });
        });
        client.connect(ftpCredentials);
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found out that the problem was not my code, but the encoding of the file. the file was Western (ISO 8859-1) encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [utf8 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) from npm to encode/decode the string.

One more solution you could use is :

```
convertString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(convertString));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried it once with the second one you suggested. But I get this error:
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
Now I try the module. I keep you updated. Thank you so far :)

Comment: You can look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json for that problem, since the structure of your object is circular, or just stick with the utf8 module.

Comment: So I tried it now with the module. then I get as a result: 
kï¿½chen
Without it I get:
k�chen
And what I want to get is:
küchen
I'm not sure anymore if I'm on the right way with utf8 :S.

Comment: German characters usually work with UTF-8, since they use ISO/IEC 8859-15, you could try using UTF-16 or even UTF-32.

Comment: Alright. I solved it. after looking to all the files again (I almost got crazy) I realised that some of the files from another customer work. Reason:
The files who dont work are ISO 8859-1 encoded ... so Im going to tell that one customer to encode his files in UTF-8 :P thank you