# Write global object to file from node application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write the global object to file from a node application.

As a starting point I know that writing `Function('return this')` in the console outputs the global object with all members.

So I am trying the following:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFile("/Users/myuser/Desktop/log.txt", Function('return this')());
```

But it just writes `[object global]` to the file

- Why is the output in the file different than the output in the console?
- How can I output the entire global object to file?

Comment: JSON.stringify(Function('return this'))

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I get "Uncaught exception: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify(<anonymous>)..."

Comment: If you're trying to JSON.stringify circular object, try this function https://stackoverflow.com/a/31557814/1951115

Answer (score 2):

You must pass a string to the body of the file you write to. Use

```
JSON.stringify(myObj)
```

Assuming `Function` return an object, you can do this:

```
var body = JSON.stringify( Function('return this')() );

fs.writeFile("/Users/myuser/Desktop/log.txt", body);
```

You should put a failsafe check also.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I get "Uncaught exception: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify(<anonymous>)..."

Comment: @user1283776, could you please put the full snippet? The output `Function` as well if short to include in the question.