# Getting undefined values from jquery post json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm using jquery to post results:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){            

          $("#submit").click(function(){                                      
                   $.post("/addGrade", 
              {"name": "test"},
              function(data, status)
              {     
                console.log("OK");
                $("#rc").val("OK");                                           
                      });

    }); // fnction

 }); // ready
```

but I'm getting undefined results:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())



app.post('/addGrade', function(req, res) {
  console.log("[/addGrade] Got New Grade: " + req.body.name);
  res.send("OK");
});
```

In Node.js log I can see: `"[/addGrade] Got New Grade: undefined"`

What am I missing ?

Comment: Why don't you log your response to see what properties it has `console.log(res)`

Comment: I have tried, but I got " [object Object]" which doesn't help much

Comment: Did you try `res.body` then

Comment: yes, same results

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(res))`

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816258/5038073

Comment: I read it, and don't understand why there is circular ? I'm sending {"name": "test"}.

Comment: Might be something with your body-parser