# pushing object to array javascript error stringify

Tags: javascript, angularjs

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify ()

```
var userInfo = currentUser.children;
      if(currentUser.type ==1){
        userInfo.push(currentUser);
        //console.log(typeof userInfo);
      }
```

It produce me error Converting circular structure to JSON. How can i come over this please guide.

Comment: can you please post your values ? that you are pushing

Comment: A circular structure in a JSON means you have strored a Selfreferencing variable inside the Object or just a Selfexecuting functions like a timeout or interval

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: {user_id: 1, social_id: null, type: 1,  name: "xys", …},
{user_id: 2, social_id: null, type: 1, name: "xyz", …} ..so ..on

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to something like this:

```js
var oscar = {
  name: 'oscar'
}

var john = {
  name: 'john',
  friend: oscar
};

oscar.friend = john;

console.log(JSON.stringify(oscar));
```

`JSON.stringify` navigates the tree defined by the object until it finishes. The problem here is that `oscar` has a property that references `john`, and then `john` references `oscar`, so the function would enter an infinite loop:

```
{"name": "oscar", "friend": {"name": "john", "friend": {"name": "oscar", ...
```

And so on. Always avoid circular references when converting to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can't push "currentUser" to "userInfo", because userInfo itself is a property of current user, you are trying to reference an object to itself. Just push the data you want to push into an array.

```
var userInfo = [];
if(currentUser.type ==1){
  userInfo.push(currentUser);
  //console.log(typeof userInfo);
}
```