# Localstorage of a circular object (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to store and retrieve a socket.io session but react is throwing an error saying that it can't save a circular object.

I've tried to stringify the object but no luck. Any work around without going into Redux?

Store:

`localStorage.setItem('socket', JSON.stringify(socket));`

Retrieve:

`const socket = localStorage.getItem("socket");`

Attempting to stringify the object returns:

`Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:7`

Comment: Can you please post `console.log(socket)` output?

Comment: I can't actually copy the output as I can't stringify the object. If I try it just returns 'Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:7'

Comment: @dporechny that just returns `"[object Object]"` as a string

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) is something that can help you.

Comment: const JSON = require('circular-json'); use this for stringify it

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/x3xzxrvxv4 I have console it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: You can check reply at [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) by Eric Muyser.

Comment: Thanks @DhavalPatel that works for setting into storage. But it errors when trying to retrieve and JSON.parse. `SyntaxError: JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:1`

Comment: nop is it so because in link I am storing it and retrieving it, please check again

Comment: @StephanieParker: make sure while parse you use the same const JSON = require("circular-json");

Comment: Thank you all sorted :)!

Comment: What is socket? Sounds like a bad idea that you're trying to stringify and store that

Comment: Does not make sense on what you are trying to store in the first place.

Comment: @StephanieParker after retriving socket from localstorage.
can you use socket's build in methods like `socket.emit?` If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inspect method 
you can import it immediately since it's from node with

```
const util = require('util')
```

And then inspect the object and log that