# Ionic 3 in-app-browser executeScript error

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using an in-app-browser to open my web portal in my Ionic app and I need to execute jquery data in browser using executeScript.

Here is my code:

```
const runFirst = `$("[data-menu=logout]").attr('data-menu','logout_custom');$("[data-menu=logout_custom]").click(()=>{});`;

let target = "_blank";
const browser = this.iab.create(url,target,this.options);
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
  browser.executeScript({
    code: runFirst
  });
});
```

When I pass that jquery data using executeScript I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Comment: This could be useful I guess, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816258/6509848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put script code direct inside executeScript

```
let target = "_blank";
const browser = this.iab.create(url,target,this.options);
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
  browser.executeScript({
    code: `$("[data-menu=logout]").attr('data-menu','logout_custom');$("[data-menu=logout_custom]").click(()=>{});`
  });
});
```