# angular js error when accessing session storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass object, controller to another controller using '$sessionStorage'

My first controller, I set the object to the session.

```
   $scope.expandChart = function(obj){
        $sessionStorage.chartObject =  obj;
        $state.go('app.chart-full-view');
       
    }
```

after i am trying to access this object in another controller. please check below code
Second controller (this is 'chart-full-view' controller)

```
  $scope.test =   $sessionStorage.chartObject;
      console($scope.test);
```

when I console my object,  console log printed correctly with error. What is this error? I need to correctly access this.
as a solution i tried below way. but did not working

```
  $scope.test =   JSON.stringify($sessionStorage.chartObject);
```

Error is **"angular.js:15697 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON "**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `stringify` when saving the object in `sessionStorage` and then use `parse` when getting it

`sessionStorage.setItem("chartObject", JSON.stringify(obj));`

As you cannot save objects in sessionstorage only strings.

And then
`$scope.test = = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('chartObject'))`;