# Get Exact Inner Text of Javascript Result

Tags: javascript

I run this script on a website:

```
document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[2]
```

it's output is:

```
<input _ngcontent-aui-c140="" pinputtext="" type="password" formcontrolname="password" autocomplete="current-password" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid p-inputtext p-component">
```

It is what I exactly need (or something comma separated). when I try to convert it into a string uaing `JSON.stringify`, it gives a `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` error. No problem, I can also convert the circular structure into a string with the help of this: [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

But it will return so many extra unknown strings! I just only need that inner HTML in a comma-separated format (JSON). what should I do?

Comment: *"when I try to convert it into a string"* How did you do that?

Comment: Please share the html and expected output

Comment: *"I just only need that inner HTML in a comma-separated format (JSON). what should I do?"* What you've shown has just one item, without commas. What do you want the other entries to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to get the HTML for the element and its descendants:

```js
const input = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[2];

console.log(input.outerHTML);
```

```html
<form>
<input>
<input>
<input _ngcontent-aui-c140="" pinputtext="" type="password" formcontrolname="password" autocomplete="current-password" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid p-inputtext p-component">
</form>
```

> I just only need that inner HTML in a comma-separated format (JSON). what should I do?

If you mean you want the above for **all** of the `input`s in the form, you can loop through the result from `getElementsByTagName` and get the `outerHTML` of each of them, and join the strings together with `join(",")`. (Though I probably wouldn't use CSV for this.)

```js
const inputs = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input');
const strings = Array.prototype.map.call(
    inputs,
    input => input.outerHTML
);
console.log("Joined with a comma:");
console.log(strings.join(","));
console.log("As JSON:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(strings));
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" class="example">
<input type="date" class="blah">
<input _ngcontent-aui-c140="" pinputtext="" type="password" formcontrolname="password" autocomplete="current-password" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid p-inputtext p-component">
</form>
```