# Fetch HTML Page with Js-Dom JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

Im trying to fetch the HTML from [this url](https://rarible.com/collection/0x60e4d786628fea6478f785a6d7e704777c86a7c6) which works by using [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) with:

```
JSDOM.fromURL("https://rarible.com/collection/" + collection, { runScripts: "dangerously" },{ pretendToBeVisual: true },{resources: "usable"}).then(dom => {
      console.log(dom.serialize()); //turn the page back into HTML
      var rendered= dom.serialize();
      res.status(200).json([{ rendered}]);
});
```

The thing is that the response i get seems to be unrendered content, meaning there's practically no html, mostly script([see the reponse in the pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ArEN0zaf))

How can i get elements of this page after all the scripts are rendered?

Comment: You can't scrape such content with just one single HTP request - you need a _headless browser_, that will actually fetch all those scripts & execute them.

Comment: @CBroe — They aren't making a single HTTP request (well, they wouldn't be if they hadn't made the mistake described in my answer). JSDOM is **designed** to fetch dependant resources (hence `resources: "usable"`)  in a similar way to a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

JSDOM takes a **single** *options* argument. You're putting each option in a separate object and passing each as a separate argument.

`{resources: "usable"}` is ignored because it is in the wrong place so it doesn't trigger the download of external scripts.

You need to combine them, like so:

```
JSDOM.fromURL("https://rarible.com/collection/" + collection, {
     runScripts: "dangerously",
     pretendToBeVisual: true,
     resources: "usable"
}).then(...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still getting the same result, it doesnt seem to be rendering thhe page...

Comment: @Ted'sProjects — When I run it it throws an error "Uncaught [TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function]" because it uses a feature not implemented by JSDOM that you'd need to polyfill.

Comment: Oh yeah i see that on my side too... You got any fix for that brother?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. You'd need to write a polyfill. (Or find an existing one). https://duckduckgo.com/?va=j&t=hc&q=jsdom+polyfill+matchmedia&ia=web

Comment: Here's what i ended up finishing with: `const {window} = new JSDOM(JSON.stringify(dom));
      matchMediaPolyfill(window);
      window.matchMedia('(min-width: 920px)');
      window.matchMedia('(min-width: 920px)') // Create MediaQueryList instance
`
But im still getting an error: 
`error - unhandledRejection: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json