# Unable to get "request" object in the express server. It throws "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a Node JS novice. I have setup an express server as shown below...

```
const expressJS = require("express");

const server = expressJS();

server.listen("3333", () => console.log("Server started on Port 3333"));

server.get("/", (request, response) => {
    const req = request;
    response.send(req)
});
```

When I tried to access `http://localhost:3333/`, the server is returning me the below error.

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (f:\NodeJS\REST_API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1150:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (f:\NodeJS\REST_API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:271:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (f:\NodeJS\REST_API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:162:21)
    at f:\NodeJS\REST_API\server.js:11:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (f:\NodeJS\REST_API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (f:\NodeJS\REST_API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (f:\NodeJS\REST_API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (f:\NodeJS\REST_API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at f:\NodeJS\REST_API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
```

May I know

1. the root cause for this error and
2. the fix for this issue?

(Any best practices or suggestions appreciated.)

Comment: Why do you want to send the entire request back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can solve your problem, instead of sending whole data, you can send whatever you want by destruction the request

```js
const util = require("util");

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  const r = util.inspect(request, { depth: null });
  response.send(r);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error throws when you call `res.send(req)`, the `express` try to call `JSON.stringify(req)` underly and the `req.socket` has a circular reference, see [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/8368dc178af16b91b576c4c1d135f701a0007e5d/lib/response.js#L1150)

From the error message:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
```

We can find the circular reference, debug log:

```
value.socket.parser.socket === value.socket
// true
```

We can use the below example to demonstrate this error

```js
class HTTPParser {}

const value = {
  socket: {
    parser: new HTTPParser()
  }
}

value.socket.parser.socket = value.socket

JSON.stringify(value)
```

That's why you got the error. The `res.send(req)` doesn't make sense. The fix for this issue is don't use it like that.

Further reading: [Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)