# After run `npm run storybook build` occurred error

Tags: build, storybook, webpack-5

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON!

for above error after research in web just give up below solution:
[Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816258/12158366)

```
var a = {};
a.b = a;
```

But i was not able to find in my stories like above structure for any object!

[Build Results ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AReKp.jpg)

package.json

I was installed below devDependencies

```
devDependencies:
"@storybook/addon-a11y": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-controls": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-jest": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-toolbars": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-viewport": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/addons": "^6.5.16",
"@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.20",
"@storybook/cli": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/jest": "^0.1.0",
"@storybook/react": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/source-loader": "^7.2.1",
"@storybook/test-runner": "^0.10.0",
"@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
"@storybook/testing-react": "^2.0.1",
```

when I do run `npm run storybook dev -p 6008` is OK!
but running `npm run storybook build` error occurred!

.storybook/main.js Config:

```
const config = {
        stories: [...myPatterns],
    addons: [
        '@storybook/react',
        '@storybook/addon-a11y',
        'storybook-source-link',
        '@storybook/addon-jest',
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-actions',
        '@storybook/addon-toolbars',
        '@storybook/addon-viewport',
        '@storybook/addon-controls',
        '@storybook/addon-essentials',
        '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    ],
    framework: {
        name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
        options: {},
    },
    docs: {
        autodocs: 'tag',
    },
    async webpackFinal(config, { configType }) {
        if (configType === 'DEVELOPMENT') {
            // Modify config for development
            config.module.rules.push(
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /\.lazy\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'style-loader',
                            options: { injectType: 'styleTag' },
                        },
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader',
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.lazy\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'style-loader',
                            options: { injectType: 'lazyStyleTag' },
                        },
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader',
                    ],
                }
            );
        }
        if (configType === 'PRODUCTION') {
            // Modify config for production
        }
        return config;
    },
};
export default config;
```

node version: 18.13.0
npm version: 8.19.3
storybook version: 7.2.1