# How to access an element's prototype with jQuery's .data() funciton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I am trying to access an html element's prototype through jQuery's `.data()` function. So far I am very confused.

This is my code:

```
// start prototype definition for myWidget
var myWidget = function() { 
    console.log('my widget is alive.');
    return this; 
};

myWidget.prototype.chosenSelect = [];

myWidget.prototype.init = function() {
    this.chosenSelect = $('#chooseMe');

    // test 1
    console.log(this.chosenSelect.data());

    // test 2
    console.log(this.chosenSelect.data('chosen'));

    // test3
    console.log(this.chosenSelect.data('Chosen'));

    // test4
    var chosenObject = this.chosenSelect.data();
    console.log(chosenObject.chosen);
};
```

Test 1 from above returns an object that I was able to look through using Chrome devtools. The object looks like this:

```
Object
    chosen: Chosen
        changeCallbacks: Array[0]
        etc
        etc
        etc
```

I want to access the `chosen` object in that data object. but tests 2 through 4 all return `undefined`. What could I be doing wrong?

### Edit

The prototype is being added to the element from another library. This is an excerpt where the assignment occurs:

```
Chosen.prototype.init = function(select, zidx, isIE7) {
this.select = select;
this.select.data('chosen', this);
```

Comment: What is `#chooseMe`?  Does it have data attached to it?

Comment: Yes it should. Another library is operating on a select html element giving it the chosen prototype. See in `// test 1` it returns a data object with `chosen: Chosen` in it.

Comment: Where do you run `$('#chooseMe').data('chosen', ...)`?

Comment: @Blender: I assign `$('#chooseMe')` to `this.chosenSelect`. Then I run `this.chosenSelect.data('chosen');` in `// test 2`.

Comment: @Blender: I understand what you mean, please see edit.

Comment: @quakkels: And when do you create that `Chosen`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [console.log object at current state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state)

Comment: DOM elements are host objects, and host objects don't have to implement any kind of inheritance, much less prototype inheritance. There are browsers in use that don't. You can access an object's internal `[[Prototype]]` property (if it has one) in some browsers using the Mozilla proprietary [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property or perhaps using `object.constructor.prototype`, but that may not be the correct object.

Comment: @RobG: `// test 1` from my post shows that the data object has `chosen` in it. My question is really how to access that `chosen object`. `// test 2` through `// test 4` all show undefined.

Comment: What happens if you access it like "this.chosenSelect.data().chosen"?

Comment: See `// test 4`. It returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data object as follows. Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qJJkL/1/).

```
// Set some data on the widget.
jQuery.data($('#chooseMe')[0], "Chosen", {chosen: "Hello!"});

var myWidget = function() {
    console.log('my widget is alive.');
    return this;
};

myWidget.prototype.chosenSelect = [];

myWidget.prototype.init = function() {
    this.chosenSelect = $('#chooseMe')[0];

    // test 1
    console.log(jQuery.data(this.chosenSelect));

    // test 2
    console.log(jQuery.data(this.chosenSelect, "Chosen"));

    // test3
    console.log(jQuery.data(this.chosenSelect, "Chosen").chosen);

    // test4
    var chosenObject = jQuery.data(this.chosenSelect, "Chosen");
    console.log(chosenObject.chosen);
};


myWidget.prototype.init();
```