# Javascript: how to access an object in an object

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, javascript-objects

I am working with a language file that stores the traductions for the jquery datepicker
URL: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js?ver=3.4.2

The jQuery.datepicker.regional object is returned and I would like to access the it (italian) property of this object.
My problem is that when I do something like

```
console.log(jQuery.datepicker.regional['it'])
```

or

```
console.log(jQuery.datepicker.regional.it)
```

the console says the object is undefined.

But when I do something like:

```
    console.log(jQuery.datepicker.regional);
```

The console returns something like this:

```
[Object]
    : Object
    af: Object
    ar: Object
    ...
    it: Object
```

What am I doing wrong? The "it" object is there isn't it?
How can I access the "it" object of the jQuery.datepicker.regional object?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jQuery.datepicker.regional` is updated with each translation object when the DOM is ready:

```
JQuery(function($){ 
    $.datepicker.regional['it'] = {
        // …
    }
})
```

Try accessing it similarly:

```
$(function() {
    console.log(jQuery.datepicker.regional.it)
})
```

#### Aside regarding `console.log`

`console.log`ging just the regional object shows all the localization objects because `console.log` (and sometimes `console.dir`) [prints a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state) to the object, whose properties may have changed by the time you actually look at them in the console. There are definitely some browser idiosyncrasies.

For example, in Chrome 25.0.1337.0:

```
var foo = {};
console.dir(foo) // Object: { baz: "bip" }

console.log(foo) // Object: {}
console.log(foo.baz); // undefined

foo.baz = "bip";


var bar = {};
console.dir(bar) // Object: { baz : { foo: 10 }}

bar.prototype = new Array;
console.log(bar) // Object: { baz : { foo: 10 }}
console.log(bar.baz); // undefined

bar.baz = { foo: 10 };
```

While in Firefox 17.0 + Firebug 1.9.2:

```
var foo = {};
console.dir(foo) // Object: { }

console.log(foo) // Object: { baz: "bip" }
console.log(foo.baz); // undefined

foo.baz = "bip";


var bar = {};
console.dir(bar) // Object: {}

bar.prototype = new Array;
console.log(bar) // Object: { baz : { foo: 10 }}
console.log(bar.baz); // undefined

bar.baz = { foo: 10 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var regional = jQuery.datepicker.regional;
console.log(regional.it); 
console.log(regional['it']);
```

Comment: It still returns undefined in both cases